# MathJax not rendered in questions list

Tags: bug, question-lists, mathjax

When I was wandering around [physics.stackexchange.com](http://physics.stackexchange.com), I suddenly saw this weird text:

> [image]

At first I thought the post was like that, but after checking there is no strange thing in the second image that previously appeared in the first image:

> [image: Image Two]

The square inside the first picture that contain text "\text{closed quantum system" is not done by me; I already found it like that.

Comment: now i confused this is mathjax or latex error because @Shadow Wizard say it is mathjax error , well i don't want to bother with it tho .

Comment: Sorry, was confused myself between MathJax and LaTeX

Comment: [MathJax](https://www.mathjax.org/) is the Javascript library used to render LaTeX (and also MathML and ASCIImath) as "beautiful mathematics". I would hazard that most of the [tag:latex] tagged questions should be tagged [tag:mathjax], as the issue/question is with the renderer, and not the typesetting program or its syntax.

Comment: @ifajra oh, it's really confusing. Well, feel free to start a discussion here about it, see what others think.