# New post summary designs on site home pages and greatest hits now; everywhere else eventually

Tags: discussion, design, announcements, greatest-hits

## Update 3 - 2022-02-01

We've rolled out another small set of changes + bugfixes. The largest change was that we removed the yellow from watched tags entirely, leaving just the new "watched" icon.

We've also added [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/375808/395497) where we lay out our next steps.

[image]

## Update 2 - 2022-01-27

We've pushed some layout changes live. When reviewing the given feedback as a whole, we've identified a few major themes:

- Stats are too hard to pick apart, "votes" in particular
- New watched/ignored states are not bright enough/too bright (respectively) and cause too much trailing whitespace

We've made the following changes to alleviate these issues:

- Bumped up the size of stats
- Gave more visible weight to "votes"
- Gave less visible weight to "supernova" view counts by removing the :fire: icon
- Removed "watched" state label, restored the yellow background and adding highlighting/icon to the individual tags that are causing the watched status
- Removed "ignored" state label, added icon to the individual tags that are causing the ignored state

This latest set of changes also includes a number of bug fixes. We're still discussing how to better improve this component. There is still some extra whitespace at the end when there is no body excerpt and a bounty exists on the post (though, this is generally still less trailing whitespace than the current design on [/questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions), which *has* a body excerpt). Thank you for your continued feedback.

[image]
[image]
[image]

## Update 1 - 2022-01-25

Most of the reported bugs have been squashed. We're currently gathering together all the [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) and [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) feedback items to decide how we want to alter the design. Thank you everyone for your feedback.

---

## Original Post

### tl;dr

We’re starting a rollout of the new [post summary design](https://stackoverflow.design/product/components/post-summary/) to many existing screens, starting with [greatest hits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/greatest-hits). This will be a slow rollout, with only one set of related screens changing at a time.

### What we’re shipping now

We’ve built a new component to replace the existing post summary implementation. We aimed for ~100% data compatibility with this implementation so that users are not losing any statistics or features. That being said, our desire to leave the existing data intact as much as possible has led to sub-optimal layouts in a few uncommon scenarios, particularly for the display of community wiki posts. Work on these experiences is ongoing and will improve over time.

For the initial announcement, we’ve migrated [/questions/greatest-hits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/greatest-hits) to use the new implementation. This way, users can have a tangible example they can use today, before we roll out the design to more and more screens. Why did we choose greatest hits to start with? It was an ideal screen for many reasons:

- Entirely standalone - no dependencies on other screens/processes and not depended on
- Low user impact - low traffic, infrequently referenced and not terribly well known (even among employees!)
- Uses the exact same component code and layout as [/questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions) - users can see this as a very close preview for what will be shipping there later on
- In disrepair - the screen was already showing some signs of neglect and really needed some love <3

**Before**

[image: post summary before]

**After**

[image: post summary after]

### What we’re shipping later

In addition to greatest hits, we’re aiming to roll this new design out site-wide. The areas we’re concentrating on first are the main areas of the site that still have mobile-only layouts. As we [remove our final mobile views](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/367609/deprecating-our-mobile-views), we need to ensure that the remaining responsive views actually look good on smaller screens. More specifically, the following high traffic views are next on our list:

- [/](https://meta.stackexchange.com/) (home / recent questions) - our “QuestionMini” layout
  [image: questionmini layout]
- [/questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions)/* (question list, list by tag, search, etc) - our “QuestionSummary” layout
  [image: questionsummary layout]

Work on these screens has progressed fairly far already due to most of the necessary work being in the creation and implementation of the underlying component. However, we’ve decided to hold off on the rollout until after the community has had an opportunity for processing the design changes and to offer us feedback.

Eventually, everything will be the new post-summary design, but it may be some time before the changes reach the long tail of our many different views.

### Where we are currently using this design

Despite my claims above that this is a “new” design, we’ve been using it in a number of places across the site for quite some time. A (non-inclusive) list of places that are *already* using the post-summary design:

- Many various places in [Teams](https://stackoverflow.com/teams/tour#content-health) and [Collectives](https://stackoverflow.com/collectives-on-stack-overflow/tour)
- Review queue [tasks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/review/close/)
- New user activity screens, such as [bookmarks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=bookmarks) and [questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=questions)

### Why we’re making these changes

Our current designs have withstood the test of time, but they fall short in many areas:

1. We generally assume 3 items of metadata: score, answers, and views. If we want to add new entries for e.g. bookmarks or revisions, it can be difficult to create a consistent layout in a list of questions.
2. Inconsistencies in implementation have led to several different layouts across the site. When gathering requirements for a unified post summary component, we found at least *5 (five!) different layouts*.
3. Scaling the design is tricky, both in window size and adding features and functionality. We need to support all sorts of metadata on all sorts of devices.
4. Our post summaries were only designed to support questions (and answers, kinda). We need to be able to display various content types in single lists. For example, in a list of notifications, we may want to present an article next to a question.
5. We have no unified place to put an action menu.

Our new post-summary design solves these problems while supporting future features we’re exploring. Some features we’re looking forward to are:

1. An arbitrary, scalable number of stats
2. Multiple different content types
3. A consistent location for post actions
4. Scalable excerpts
5. Responsive layouts
6. A single consistent layout regardless of what data is included

### How this component was designed

An early version of this component first appeared in Stack Overflow for Teams in a feature called For You. For You is a rich list of notifications that include questions, answers, and articles.

The existing designs were desirable for familiarity, but just weren’t well suited for the task. After the initial proposal and some iterations with our team of designers, the new post summary design was ready for user testing.

User testing was run with ~170 recently active users against 5 different versions of the post summary design (two of those being existing designs). The chosen design performed better than the existing designs in some metrics (including readability) and never worse on the remaining metrics (including familiarity, data absorption).

After this new design tested well, the design systems team gathered further requirements from across the organization and built it out as an official [Stacks](https://stackoverflow.design/) component. If you’re technically inclined, you can see some of the iterations in [various](https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks/pull/498) [open](https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks/pull/547) [source](https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks/pull/787) [pull requests](https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks/pull/794).

If you’re familiar with the design tool Figma, feel free to check out [some explorations](https://www.figma.com/community/file/1062438578792353822/Post-summary) prior to us moving into code.

### FAQ

Q: What if I find a bug/regression?
A: Report it as an answer to this post - one bug per answer please. If you’re feeling charitable, add a `[tag:bug]` tag to the top of your post so we can more easily find it.

Q: What if I have constructive feedback, but it isn’t a bug?
A: We’d like to hear it! Add it as an answer on this post. As above, you can add a `[tag:discussion]` tag to the top of the post as well.

Q: When will `FAVORITE_SCREEN` be migrated to use this new design?
A: [6-8 weeks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19514/395497)

Comment: Shouldn't https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/greatest-hits be added to https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/ (under the "More" tab)? This announcement doesn't make it clear which webpage we would be on, and where we would click, to access https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/greatest-hits (without using the URL in this announcement); I've been here a while, fairly certain I've not see the *tabless* "Greatest Hits" page before.

Comment: @Rob Honestly, no clue. I only found this page while I was looking for areas that needed migration to the new layout. Most of the people I showed this page to didn't even know it existed. I'll follow up internally about if we want to make additional changes to better surface this screen.

Comment: @Rob it's an [unlinked page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/76569/1017231)

Comment: @bobble  Announced 10 years ago: [How can we utilize the "Greatest hits" list for our sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/103650/282094) and asked where to link to it from several years ago: [What should we do about Greatest Hits?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/243010/282094) - apparently it is used to populate the Newsletter: [Are the "greatest hits" in the Stack Overflow newsletter appropriate?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/102786/282094)

Comment: I wish more work went into improving the UX instead of the UI.

Comment: I'm on my phone so writing a full answer would be awkward, but I'd like to see the "answers" label right aligned with the "votes" and "views" text, rather than it being aligned based on the "answers" box's right border

Comment: Cool!  Think you could mark [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/360523/greatest-hits-definition-text-should-be-more-visible-on-all-sites-where-dark-mod) report as [tag:status-completed] then?

Comment: Under "Where we are currently using this design" -- the user activity bookmarks and questions views look much different (and worse) than the screenshots in this post. Am I missing something?

Comment: @LShaver Those screens are using the same component, but using the ["minimal" view](https://stackoverflow.design/product/components/post-summary/#minimal) (which is basically the mobile/responsive view on desktop). The underlying implementation is different, but those screens are using the same CSS classes / markup.

Comment: @BenKelly Is the removal of gold/silver/bronze badge count for non-CW posts an unintentional or intentional change in the new layout? I consider it a regression, personally, as it is a loss in somewhat interesting/useful data.

Comment: I think it's interesting that you refer to "score" (*We generally assume 3 items of metadata: score, answers, and views.*) when it's still labelled "votes". I'm going to be annoying and link the feature request about that so we don't forget about it :) [Use "score" instead of "votes" in the list of questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/153515/273494).

Comment: `5 Users 48% Gnome` made me laugh - but what does the 48% even refer to? The number of characters changed?

Comment: @TylerH Yes, that was by design. If that's something you feel strongly about, add a new [tag:discussion] answer. I'd prefer it as an answer so any extended discussion happens off the main post's comment chain.

Comment: @simonalexander2005 Yeah, that wording is not great. I think that percentage is measuring how much of the post is attributed to the top editor of that post. I hint at it in a comment on one of the answers below, but we plan on rewording that text more naturally, making it much clearer in the process.

Comment: I think the means your favourite page 

Comment: No no. Literally a page on the site you like, and if you want it updated to responsive stuff, It'll happen when it happens ._..

Comment: @charlietfl it is meant to be a placeholder, an *left to the imagination of the reader*, a *catch all*  for all the pages / dialogs / "components" that are yet to get their redesign. By using that phrase It tries to pre-emptively shortcut inquiries about the pet-peeve pages / screens /dialogs of readers of this question. Even with that in place I'm sure someone brings up that one feature request from 2011 that is still not fixed and will argue it should have gotten priority over *post summary designs*. That FR points out *their* `FAVORITE_SCREEN` ...

Comment: @charlietfl in place of FAVORITE_SCREEN you choose one of the site's URLs. Definition: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/fill_in_the_blank https://help.blackboard.com/Learn/Instructor/Ultra/Tests_Pools_Surveys/Question_Types/Fill_in_the_Blank_Questions

Comment: Probably you meant that the list is non-exhaustive rather than non-inclusive ….

Comment: Did this just go out for Meta's homepage?

Comment: @bobble it appears it went to *all* homepages (it's there on rpg.se at least)

Comment: @illustro there was definitely some time where it was only meta, but it's definitely everywhere now.

Comment: I sure don't like it; much harder to see the metadata on the home page.

Comment: This layout makes the desktop experience on the homepage worse, due to a lower information density displayed at once on the screen (# questions per screen), more difficult to parse and smaller statistics, too much padding between list items, misaligned tag and user bars with the bottom of the question block

Comment: What does "screens" mean? Is it a term-of-art in design?

Comment: @AndrewMorton It refers to the different pages or “views” or _places_ where you see question lists, e.g. the [`/` screen](/) or the [`/questions` screen](/questions) or the [`/questions/greatest-hits` screen](/questions/greatest-hits).

Comment: I don't understand what "~100% data compatibility with this implementation" means.  Do you mean that the same information is shown to viewers, with both the old format and the new format?  Or are you referring to something about internal implementation details (e.g., database formats, etc.) that are not directly visible to Stack Exchange?  If the latter, why should we care?

Comment: I should also point out, my use of the word "screen" in my previous comment refers to the amount of information displayed on my computer monitor (or screen) at once, as opposed to the "view" based meaning ascribed in the Question

Comment: @D.W. They mean the former. Both versions show the same stats; nothing is lost. This was (or _is_) a problem in the Profile page and Activity page redesign.

Comment: To the author of this post, I would suggest rewording that part of the post.  I find super confusing to talk about "implementation" and "data compatibility" when what you mean is "we continue to display the same data, but in a different format".

Comment: Is it just me or does anyone hates these changes to the feed and profile? I say "hate", because they're ruining the desktop experience.

Comment: @BernardoDuarte the rapidly declining score on this post says _"yes"_. As we've seen before though, [score on announcements means nothing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/372049)

Comment: I honestly don't see how this can be considered an improvement. It's harder to find information from a glance and it looks incredibly unbalanced.

Comment: It's horrible in nearly every way. Not a single improvement to my experience and several things which are worse.

Comment: Are 5 (*five!*) different layouts too much for a network of 178 sites? I would expect a bit of customization for such a large network.

Comment: This has gone live on the main /Questions pages; are there any other locations that should be edited in as having the new style now?

Comment: Why do UX changes always make things harder to read and digest *sigh*

Comment: @DanIsFiddlingByFirelight Where do you see this having gone live on [`/questions`](/questions) pages? On MSE, MSO, and SO they’re still in the old version. Is this an A/B test?

Comment: I’m not a fan of this strategy: adding huge changes to a the site and editing the meta post two weeks later after the score is artificially inflated.

Comment: @SebastianSimon I rechecked, not questions but the question feed on the main .com at stack overflow and workplace.SE.

Comment: @cocomac too bad I don't have enough reputation on meta to add another bounty and join the cause.

Comment: The change to *add* ***ignored*** tags with a black background, just to make questions you want to *ignore* stand out *even more* is ridiculous and bad UX design

Comment: It might help if examples/mockups were provided that demonstrate how the new design will provide advantages in the future.  The current set of before-and-after screenshots don't look any better and instead demonstrate how the old design was easier to scan.

Comment: While it was great that you released this on the Greatest Hits page first for us to poke around with, there's a fundamental problem with that, and it's why so many people are upset now: *no one uses the Greatest Hits page*. It's not part of anyone's regular workflow, so it's harder for us to see how the new design will break our workflows. People aren't used to using it, so if information is a little awkward to acquire, or certain use-cases aren't served, it's difficult for us to see it. I don't have a solution, just wanted to point out why the pre-release didn't end up being that useful.

Comment: While I appreciate the effort that's gone into this, it's really disappointing how consistently any UI changes to the site actually make the experience worse. It seems like every change is a net regression. Do the staff just think our consistent complaining is because people hate change? Because it's much more than that. Almost every change is a significant step backwards in some respects. This change seems to have a number of objective flaws. I feel like all the effort that's spent twiddling with a layout that's always been *fine* could be put to better use.

Comment: I've created a [userscript](https://stackapps.com/questions/9293/legacy-questions-bringing-back-the-old-questions-design) that brings back the old design.

Comment: I love the before and after pictures... how on earth is that an improvement?! How are you meant to read anything, without zooming into the page..?

Comment: I will join in with the chorus of disgruntled users for once... because you had them review [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AfZEd.png), and instead we get [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KggVH.png) (note the lack of color, for example). Why were the users here given 1 thing to review, and then surprised with a completely different change?

Comment: @Tinkeringbell [This](//i.stack.imgur.com/pCPUy.png) was the old state, not the planned new state. It was clear to me that [this](//i.stack.imgur.com/KggVH.png) is how all views are going to look like, but reading the announcement again, I can see how this may not be clear. Feel free to edit and clarify.

Comment: @SebastianSimon we still got something different anyway, especially with the watched / ignored badges and the extra vertical space that comes with them. Those changes don't appear anywhere in the OP

Comment: @SebastianSimon fair point, I may have misunderstood. I'm not going to touch the edit button on this post though. Instead I have updated the image in my comment to point to the screenshot used for /greatest-hits and /home now. There's still a pretty big difference between the two (use of color, for one), so the original question still stands :)

Comment: Who started this design change? Who decided this was a good idea? And why the hell wasn't this released as an opt in for testing before forcing it down our throats? Or even showing us mockups and announcing it before releasing? Classic Stack Overflow, ignore the users and break stuff.

Comment: @Tschallacka It was released on [the greatest hits page](/questions/greatest-hits) 12 days ago, screenshots exist, and the [Stacks design page](//stackoverflow.design/product/components/post-summary) has been linked as well, so there _definitely was_ an opportunity to test this.

Comment: @SebastianSimon To my feelings about it is [to reference this](https://www.planetclaire.tv/quotes/hitchhikers/the-hitchhikers-guide-to-the-galaxy/#:~:text=%E2%80%9CYes%2C%E2%80%9D%20said%20Arthur%2C,Beware%20of%20the%20Leopard'.%E2%80%9D)

Such a all encompassing design change should have been in my opinion been featured side wide.

Comment: In the name of everything that you hold sacred, **please revert this!**. My brain hurts trying to process this layout. There's way too much empty space and a tiny vote count is purely awful!

Comment: In the same user experience fail category as Windows 8 removing the "Start" menu for tiles. Why? Because you broke what I have learned to find with a quick glance. Sizable vote numbers and unintrusive highlighting of watched tags.

Comment: @AlanDev See also: **"new" reddit** (not compact, slow, unfortunate single-page-application which reduces effectiveness of browser tabs) vs **old.reddit.com** (compact, very readable, much faster and responsive, browser tabs work, maybe needs some modern reskinning and CSS tweaks, but the user experience is terrific).

Comment: If you flip the labels on the before/after screenshots, they make a very good case study for how to improve readability by making the most important pieces of information easy to find for your eyes.

Comment: As a Stack Overflow old-time developer. Don't come to the community with solutions. Come to the community with a problem statement and an idea and iterate. This way you'll get a better solution than this and you won't get massive downvotes. Remember: most people here are (a) better stack overflow experts than you or me and (b) better _developers_ too. Give them a chance.

Comment: "While it was great that you released this on the Greatest Hits page first for us to poke around with, there's a fundamental problem with that, and it's why so many people are upset now: no one uses the Greatest Hits page." I have been around for over 11 years, and this meta.SE question is *literally the first time I have ever heard about a "greatest hits" page*. Staring at the current Stack Overflow interface, I have **absolutely no clue** how one is intended to navigate there, other than by manually entering the URL. So... *no wonder* nobody uses it.

Comment: @bobble Also, I think this was a featured meta post, everyone should be able to see it. There was some early feedback... but they aren't that negative. (in fact, if I recalled correctly the question initially get something like +50?)

Comment: There is a *reason* why sites on the internet contemplating sweeping changes to their *primary view* offer users several months (or years in some cases) to transition between the two and gather feedback, and they do this by using a modal box on the page *informing* users that a change is going to happen, and would they like to preview it. This was buried in a post, that doesn't have an especially informative title, nor is it clear that it was referring to such a sweeping change (I missed it and I'm active on the SE network daily).

Comment: Finally, it was tested on a page a fraction of the userbase even uses. You got feedback on the design from 170 users, for changes on a site that has millions of page views per day?

Comment: I genuinely can't actually face browsing and answering questions on SO with the interface like this.

Comment: @illustro that could be a post in itself, and you would have my full-throated support on that point.

Comment: @EricDuminil It's genereally counter-productive to blame individual employees for changes, we usually don't know who actually made which decision and it creates an unnecessarily hostile atmosphere in the discussions. SE, the company is to blame here, not the people implementing changes. There is almost certainly some process for this kind of change, and this process failed thoroughly here.

Comment: give us an option to use the old design, the new one is not better, you can't find the info fast :(

Comment: @KarlKnechtel https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/375549/388810 open to suggestions for better wording etc

Comment: This is a nightmare. Please revert ASAP. The "watched" bag is a useless attention-stealing distraction, it occupies space that should rather be occupied by larger digits for number of answers and votes, instead there is an unnecessarily large amount of margin everywhere and it just makes it a mess and hard to read. If the "watched" thing should be visible, a default-colored eye icon somewhere in a corner would have sufficed. Really not a fan. :(

Comment: Even Microsoft is [giving up](https://blogs.embarcadero.com/native-windows-is-back-to-center-stage/?utm_source=Eloqua&utm_medium=email&utm_content=Article-211112-Multicontent) on "one interface for every screen size".

Comment: @MadScientist: Fair enough, and that's why I asked about the logic behind it. The logic might be : "My boss told me to", or "This group of long-time users/mods decided it's a good idea because X, Y, and Z." As presented, the whole thing is just baffling.

Comment: Terrible! Another step closer destroying this community. The home page is barely usable anymore. Without the previews and/or clear vote counts, it is practically impossible to distinguish the good questions from the bad ones. Bye bye (closing) votes, bye bye finding good questions. Bye bye Stackoverflow.

Comment: At least bring back the blurbs on the main page.

Comment: @FreeMan UWP is architecture, not design; it was never about "one interface for every screen size"; a responsive design from a UWP would work just fine in a traditional program. Responsive design is _certainly_ not going anywhere.

Comment: We all know change is hard and people nearly universally hate new designs (ok that's anecdotal, but still). My vote though - dear lord I can't scan the content or easily read the numbers now. I'm a desktop user. I'm sure I'll get used to it, but I really don't see how this is an improvement on anything from a user perspective. Perhaps from a back end one, sure, but you just made it harder for me to read, not easier. Thumbs down.

Comment: I actually double checked my browser plugins this morning as I thought one of them had broken the site by being a little overaggressive. The large white space/small text combo is hurting my eyes.

Comment: This is hardly believable, SO's homepage is just way harder to digest now. I'll wait for the revert before getting back at answering. I can't really explain how these changes reached production as is...

Comment: I really think this must be (again) a mistake or a joke. Finally the mobile version looks *actually* like a SO website. But what happened to the designer/UX-specialist looking at the desktop version? But mostly to the person saying: *"That's it! Ship to production!"*? Why all those whitespace, I can barely fit 7 questions on the home page, the cognitive load (as already mentioned) is huge. Instead of vertically swiping trough the columns (score/answers/views) now I have to intermittently jump my already tired eyeballs to query some 12px font size numbers... and scroll like crazy. *"Votes"*?

Comment: @BenKelly You said "User testing was run with ~170 recently active users". What's the total user pool size and why was such a miniscule pool selected? Why weren't there more users selected, specifically those that use the sites the most? Was there an invitation sent out for testing, or were these ~170 users randomly chosen? Why does it seem like the desktop version of the site is being neglected/ignored?

Comment: To be constructive now, the *Watching* "design" was even before the update (with the roseyellorange-ish background-"hard to call highlight") also an ugly mistake. Now instead of a background we have a *"pill?"* taking up 50+px of vertical space. Instead of just adding a 5 or 4px left orange border for the Watching Tag *Cards*. Also, add the same 5px left border to the menu for selecting the watch tags and you have a reference/UI/hint. and that's it. And return the (S/A/V) as columns. And Bam. Win/Win

Comment: Again, you showed us something and pushed something different that a lot of people really don't like.  Again, the score of the post changed from +100-whatsit to something that looks like a negative phone number.

Comment: Quick note - there's been about a dozen or so requests via comments to revert to the old view - rather than flooding this main post with comments upvote an answer such as  [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/375584/135565)  instead

Comment: @0stone0 What “previews” are you talking about? If you mean post excerpts under the titles, they were _never_ there on the home page ([`/`](/)). Excerpts were always there on [`/questions`](/questions). This has been [mentioned before](/a/375475/289905).

Comment: @tomdemuyt What “blurbs” are you talking about? If you mean post excerpts under the titles, they were _never_ there on the home page ([`/`](/)). Excerpts were always there on [`/questions`](/questions). This has been [mentioned before](/a/375475/289905).

Comment: @JourneymanGeek, what would you think about re-opening https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/375481/please-revert-the-new-question-list-style-change as a place for discussing this?

Comment: Its not closed. And tbh, I'd rather have everything in the same place. - here If members of the community close it, I don't have a strong reason to disagree either, but I can't reopen a post that's not closed no matter how hard I try. I'd *love* for these design changes to be more responsive to *our* needs, and that means encouraging people to keep calm, and put *reasoned* detailed constructive critiques of what is wrong where we know staff will read it - and that's most likely here.

Comment: From the update: "We're currently gathering together all the discussion and feature-request feedback items to decide how we want to alter the design." That's good but I would have additionally halted the rollout until the feedback is properly processed and alterations to the design have been made. As it is, there might be grave problems that were already reported early on, but you nevertheless pushed the product out. Why? To stay on some schedule? That only resulted in lots of downvotes. Taking time, processing feedback and then coming back would have been much better, I think.

Comment: @SebastianSimon They were there on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @j08691 The way I read it they were self selected users - they had everyone who was using For You in Stack Overflow for Teams - and of course they have now run into the problem with that kind of selection process, they chose the pool as a subset of users that fell into one category (people who use SOfT) and that introduces a very skewed bias into the the responses.

Comment: Thank you for removing the watched tag and going back to highlighting, much more acceptable now, but still the score needs to be much more prominent in desktop. If score does not help out in quickly triaging out low quality questions and give visibility to interesting questions... what's the point? I cannot simply see the score quickly enough as it is right now.

Comment: Does the 90% downvote rating of this question tell SE anything about this decision?

Comment: Full marks for technical implementation. Very smooth. Low marks for content delivery. It probably got worse. That probably means you need more content people. You use the product yourself, right? The shortcomings could maybe have caught the attention of people earlier. Maybe a limited beta would have been the best.

Comment: I'm sure everyone at Stack Overflow is thinking 'we know better than all our users on this, they're wrong and we're right, just give it time and they'll see."  As I recall, one of your two founders (I can't remember if it was Spoelsky or Atwood) had an entire blog post on that kind of thinking ...

Comment: Curious to know whether this UI change had an impact on the rate of answers throughout Stack Overflow in any way, do we have such metrics available?

Comment: @sp00mn "do we have such metrics available?" Yes, see the [data explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/). However, there might be a bit of delay. I think it updates once per week.

Comment: Update 2 reintroduces some of the fixes mentioned below, eg, content jumping has increased significant.

Comment: "New watched/ignored states are not bright enough/too bright (respectively) and cause too much trailing whitespace" - You've missed the thurst here I think. The whole new design causes too much whitespace on the page, and in particular vertical whitespace on desktop. The Watched/Ignored tags were just the *most egregious* examples of it

Comment: Removing things from the stats list on the left certainly helps with the height problem, but doesn't it still leave you in the same situation where if later you added things to it, which you suggested is literally the reason it's designed that way, we'd just be right back in the same boat?

Comment: @illustro keep reading - "*There is still some extra whitespace at the end when there is no body excerpt and a bounty exists on the post (though, this is generally still less trailing whitespace than the current design on /questions, which has a body excerpt).*"

Comment: Put another way I feel the design was built with the intent of using the left list to present more info, but because it's not being used in that way due to that causing too much vertical space... what benefit are we gaining from it being that way? If the left list version was removed leaving just the top list, we'd then have space to go back to the full user card and position it to the right of the title since the title now has the space freed up from the left to compensate.

Comment: Looks *a bit* better now. IMO, the eye icon grabs too much attention compared to the tag name, especially when the name is short (e.g. `c`). I'd either make it translucent or remove it completely.

Comment: About update #2: the new yellow tags that pop out of the screen in dark mode are no better than the old watch label popping out of the screen. Try dark mode and see for yourself. Why not just give them the eye icon or a slightly different tint? Solid yellow is MEH. -- Also *"Gave more visible weight to "votes""* - changing color from light grey to white doesn't give it any more visibility to be honest, it's still microscopic and not as prominent as it should be.

Comment: @Catija My point was in identifying the *major themes* in the first two bullet points, the focus was on the Watched/Ignored tags. There should (imo) have been a third bullet point in that list, where the design *generally* has too much vertical whitespace (when the post excerpt is not there). Essentially the update is not highlighting that one of the major themes of feedback was whitespace in general, in addition to specific issues with *additional* whitespace caused by the Watched/Ignored tags.

Comment: I really dislike a lot the way that the watched tags looks now (related [1](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/375639/289691), [2](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/375638/289691))

Comment: Doing updates 1, 2 that are about so big changes like is done in this post doesn't look to be a good practice... **Please**, please, please don't sacrifice readability and clarity for post economy. Please also have in mind that so far there are 72 answers some of them being with status tags that might become "irrelevant" to the current "update"

Comment: Re `2022-01-27` changes: The high contrast nature of the new watched tags is too stark and unreasonably distracting (especially in dark mode). More specifically: it significantly reduces SNR during normal eye tracking: unique information amongst items (e.g. title) is more important information and should receive a uniquely higher priority in regard to its visual contrast. (The current title text to item background contrast is only `4.46`, compared to the tag background to item background contrast, which is `6.04`!) The ️ is thoughtful for accessibility.

Comment: If watched tag posts now have the background color back to what it was, why do the tags also have ugly eyeball icons? I really don't care that much about it. You're over notifying us about something that's very minor. Belt and suspenders. Ditch the eyeballs

Comment: The eye for watched is a bit too much. Maybe the visual hints can be overall a bit more subtle.

Comment: It is now slightly more tolerable, but honestly I cannot understand why you are not rolling back to what people didn't *fervently hate* and taking the time to process the plethora of feedback users have carefully collected, and instead trying to fix the busted tires of a moving car.

Comment: Stop making tweaks to this like all you did was break a little thing and the fixes will make it better.  **Make it all STOP!**  The interface is actively giving me a headache and it makes it unbearable to use the site.

Comment: @sp00m Agreed. The site is so off-putting now, I have no desire to answer any more questions and provide SE any more free labor until they start listening to their user base.

Comment: StackOverflow lost its soul with these UI changes..

Comment: There should be a rule that if a network change gets net -500 votes that it's automatically rolled back

Comment: Deleted my previous comment as the layout has improved dramatically. Biggest issue for me right now is just how bright the watched tags are. A less-intense watched tag colour would be ideal (pulling the colour from site themes would be even better, so it doesn't stand out as much).

Comment: Was anyone complaining about the "watched" banner not being bright enough? Even the old one hurt my eyes on dark theme, and the new one is no better. Aside from that, the point countless folks have made about scanning the columns for vote/answer counts stands proud, event after the 1/27 update. And I'm still left asking: What does this improve? It infuriates half the regular users of the site and... does what for everyone else? Impresses the shareholders with a new UI because "new is good"? If the goal really is the bottom line, then what does this do to benefit that?

Comment: Tags have always had a stronger outline and a softer fill. We had this discussion for the [“Staff” and “Mod” labels](/a/367912/289905) already. Why not do the same here: stronger golden outline, softer golden fill? Why not keep the solid fill for anything on Stack Exchange which is _supposed_ to grab our attention, while keeping the outline approach for anything that _isn’t_?

Comment: On second thought, tags aren’t always blue, and on a second look, they don’t always have the outline. Case in point: [TeX & LaTeX Stack Exchange](//tex.stackexchange.com) has an “ecru white” tag color. Compare, from the old design, [normal post summaries](//i.stack.imgur.com/KtODz.png) to [highlighted (“watched”) ones](//i.stack.imgur.com/W7iBI.png), and from the new design, [normal](//i.stack.imgur.com/RaTTl.png) vs. [watched](//i.stack.imgur.com/PX0XY.png). It’s important to note that, _if_ watched tags get a color at all, that it doesn’t conflict with the rest of the site design.

Comment: I agree with commenters who think the most recent update (2) is positive. I do think the watched tag color is too bright still. I do like there being emphasis, but the yellow ochre is pretty harsh.

Comment: For a few days the yellow "watched" tag was gone. Now it's back and while the new position is less  interfering with the vote count, it's still bright distracting clutter that shows up on 90% of the questions if you watch a tag like "python". Maybe I should start unwatching popular tags, but how would SO then know that I am interested in those tags? IHMO a watch-tag should not have a different colour. Placing an eye icon next to it is more than enough. BTW, the yellow clutter is annoying me enough to consider fixing this client side or (more likely) to quit browsing questions for relaxtion...

Comment: If you watch a tag, the tag watches you too.

Comment: @BenKelly: Why are you ignoring the overwhelming public demand to back out this change? We didn't ask for contract tweaks and such.

Comment: @einpoklum In BenKelly's defense, the push for the changes likely came from far, far above him and therefore any revert to the old needs high-level approval. SE is not a little startup any more...

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact: 1. By "you" I meant SE Inc., not Ben Kelly personally. 2. If BenKelly does not personally support the decisions from "far above", and does not want to take collective responsibility for it, he is welcome to clarify that he is merely relaying a message (and better yet, tell those people up above to post here themselves rather than hide behind his back).

Comment: I don't think there's much in this new UI that is salvageable.  I don't understand why it's still here.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact Ben may not be welcome to clarify. Ben may, as representing SE as a whole, be required to toe the party line and not publicly express any disagreement with the choices from on high.

Comment: @Andrew Agreed. As in "don't kill the messenger".

Comment: @einpoklum "Why are you ignoring the overwhelming public demand to back out this change?" Isn't it obvious? They think they know better. And it's not formally ignored. They even thank us for continuously giving feedback. They just don't seem to (fully) agree with it. With they I mean the company as a whole, in particular those with decision making power in it.

Comment: there's also the fact that a whole bunch of time and money was just invested in this new UI.

Comment: @Trilarion: 1. It's not obvious. 2. If the reason was that they think they know better, they could say "you are wrong because XYZ"; but they're not saying that.

Comment: @billynoah: But that money was invested in order to improve the question list pages, it was invested for having a "general post summary design". You can still have that design for other pages.

Comment: *a whole bunch of time and money was just invested in this new UI.* See [Fallacy of sunk costs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sunk_cost)

Comment: @einpoklum "they could say..." They could but they don't have to. They aren't really accountable to us - we are not their bosses. They can also simply disagree and know better and thank us for the feedback (and the downvotes) and then be done with it.

Comment: @Trilarion: They do have to. 1. Because it's their responsibility to the users and 2. Because [Teresa Dietrich said so](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/343890/196834), in almost so many words. See also [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/375677/teresa-dietrich-what-about-the-commitment-to-rebuild-relationship-with-our-com) I just asked.

Comment: @einpoklum If you think that they do not engage enough with the community and fall short of their own standards, then of course they should better do. Nevertheless... in my experience it's better to simply let go at some point and move on (for example to other Q&A platforms and try your luck there maybe). The question you just asked is wasted if you ask me. They are aware of the problem, the score here says it all. If they have something more to say about it, they will. Additional poking will not have any impact.

Comment: This is now the fourth **LOWEST** post of all time on MSE

Comment: @BenKelly Can I add an answer  to [feature-request] [use of scores instead of votes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/153515/use-score-instead-of-votes-in-the-list-of-questions) ?

Comment: I appreciate that you are trying to improve the thing you've done, but it's going to take more than bumping up a font size or refining white space.  These are minor adjustments that can help but there is a huge overall design problem here and the user response has been so overwhelmingly negative in this case that's it's hard to believe. People that use the site every day have a workflow - if there is going to be a major design change, it needs to be considerate of this.

Comment: After what feels like an eternity of starring into glaring yellow watched tag and subsequent yellow tags I am happy that now at least I can open Stack Overflow without getting a seizure.

Comment: Never heard of greatest hits and couldn't find it if I tried! **Hate** the new layout!

Comment: Why do people complain that they didn’t see the new design because they couldn’t find the _greates hits_ page? It is literally mentioned and linked in this post, and it was featured almost since the beginning! Alternatively, simply visit Meta more regularly.

Comment: @SebastianSimon That is not the main issue here at all. Whether people knew about it or not the actual implementation has been abysmal

Comment: @charlietfl No, I’m referring to the people specifically saying that they never heard about the _greates hits_ page. Like the comment right above mine: _“Never heard of greatest hits and couldn't find it if I tried! Hate the new layout!”_ — Why is never hearing of the _greates hits_ page relevant to the negative feedback?

Comment: @SebastianSimon The company presented the new design first on the greatest hit page approximately two weeks before it applied that new design also to the "top questions" page. However, because nobody actually visits the greatest hits page, nobody could comment on the design change back then in early January and had to do it now. That should explain the comments.

Comment: I keep following this post and the main sites, hoping day by day that I won't have to fight nausea to use them. When will this be reverted please?

Comment: All this post really needs is just an edit at the top saying: "#Update 3: \r\n We've rolled this back for now while we consider all the feedback we've received."

Comment: Votes are still very difficult to see compared to the other stats. That seemed to be the biggest complaint and the best we got in response was "we made it like 1% darker than the other text".

Comment: It seems that nobody in the organization understands that no one as users wants this. I'm wondering, how often software developers search for questions on their phones? Have you ever been a coder? I don't see myself compiling apps with my phone.

Comment: I 100% approve of using the same code for all five list pages and making it responsive.   I question where re-creating the old look on desktop is really that hard while still meeting those tech debt removal goals.   Using CSS grids allows you to re-order content without changing the order of the HTML code.  You could mimic the old desktop look using only CSS while still being completely responsive.

Comment: Please revert this. I don't know who thought that this looks better, but whoever did is incredibly wrong. Please, revert this. Do the right thing for the first time in years...

Comment: This seems to have unfortunately gone live to `/questions` as well, without even being announced‽

Comment: Yet another CSS patch should be prepared for `/questions`...

Comment: @aepot [my userstyles](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/375511/158281) seems to work fine on `/questions`

Comment: All I see now is *votes answers views, votes answers views ...* when browsing new questions. The old design priveleged the meaningful data (the numbers associated with the above labels). Now the eye has to repeatedly zigzag down the page to pick out meaningul information. Yet another 'design' choice with no basis in user experience.

Comment: I have to wonder about those 170 users you mentioned... no offense intended, but judging by the overwhelmingly negative feedback it seems suspicious.

Comment: This is now the [third most unpopular meta post of all time](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions?tab=votes&page=6417), just beating out the fake apology to Monica. Will Stack Exchange actually listen to user feedback and reverse course?

Comment: I think SE needs a new model for posts like this. This is not a question but an announcement, just as the 'accepted answer' is not an answer but a defense of the announcement (no matter how 'carefully written'). Posting it as if it were open to discussion is as disingenuous as the design changes are disfunctional.

Comment: @SurpriseDog I lost hope in that; It's clear that someone is too proud to admit that what they did is just plain terrible.

Comment: @SurpriseDog StackOverflow is the EA of Q&A websites. They got so big that they think they can do anything and we will eat it quiet and nothing will happen. Looking at Battlefield 2042 and StackOverflow, you can see similarities on how they handle user feedback. They say they listen but they don't, they throw together a tone-death "explanation" on why they did what they did and keep going without a care in the world. But, Battlefield 2042 is suffering it's consequences. Maybe we will see some consequences for StackOverflow as well?

Comment: When i sit in public transport i usually do not answer in StackOverflow, I also do not answer while sitting in a Tesla. If anything then i do crawling and reading mobile. But changing the design to focus mobile first? When we print the news in bigger letters on bigger piece of paper the news do not change, the perception changes. In design agencies we call this distractive design. Since the changes i barely answer on SO anymore, i just cant see the forest with that big trees in front.

Comment: I’ve been using this design on `/questions` for two weeks on desktop now. It works for me. It doesn’t disturb my workflow, I can read things clearly, find and access questions that interest me efficiently. Obviously, that doesn’t mean that the design and the rollout process are free from issues. A large part of the (mostly negative) feedback is valid and still relevant. In particular, the score count is still cumbersome to visually parse.

Comment: @Zombo please inform yourself. These changes were announced before they rolled out network wide, as they were tested on the greatest hits page.

Comment: So, how's about fixing the broken design then? We're waiting and waiting.

Answer (score -184, accepted):

After exploring a number of alternatives and discussing with multiple members of the CM team, we’ve decided that it would not be in the long-term interests of the network to roll these changes back. This includes both rolling back the code entirely and a "visual rollback" where we keep the new code, but shoehorn the old layout onto it.

### Why?

One of [Stacks's](https://stackoverflow.design/product/guidelines/using-stacks/#goals) goals is to burn down technical debt in the complex Stack Overflow Codebase because the way it constructs pages for viewers can be excessively difficult to manage and change. Over the years, many highly-desired feature requests have gone unanswered specifically because the work burden associated with UI and UX changes is high, and it is difficult to budget in even apparently small changes.

Our evaluation alongside the CM team is that the changes Stacks introduces into the inner workings of the network are necessary at some point or another for the sake of the longevity of the community. We recognize the community is a bit burnt out from the feeling that this feedback isn’t going heard or addressed, and may consider the Stacks team's approach a step backwards in UI/UX. Keep these feature requests coming - they will soon be much more actionable.

Here are a few of the things we gain by keeping the new layout that aren't possible to cleanly do if we rolled back the design:

- Responsiveness - this was the primary catalyst for the change. The old layout was unusable on mobile and could not be feasibly scaled to work.
- Unified feature set - we had 5+ different layout implementations (plus the "QuestionMini" layout replaced here). That number has *grown* since writing the original post. Only some screens support some features<sup>1</sup>, but not others and other screens exhibit bugs that have been fixed in visually related areas<sup>2</sup>.
- Multiple types - we need a way to showcase multiple types of content in one list. The home page shows questions and [apps](https://stackapps.com/) (but not articles<sup>3</sup>). The question list shows questions and articles (but not apps<sup>4</sup>). Search results return questions, answers<sup>5</sup> and articles. For You in Teams (an in box of rich notifications) shows questions, answers, articles, collections and a few other types of content. The existing design does not scale all of these scenarios. The Stacks post summary does.
- Extensibility - we want to be able to add new features to post summaries. In fact, many of these "new" features already exist in specific areas and can be (visually) supported everywhere if we are able to implement the backend processes. Existing features include: Collective post/user endorsements, Article types and read time in Teams / Collectives, Bookmark support in Activity, answers nested under questions in Activity (and Enterprise search results).

### What have we done to address the community's concerns?

I've gone through nearly 100% of the feedback in the answers (as of 2022-01-27) and distilled it down to the major themes. Here are the top 5 themes, with the list roughly ordered by number of times the individual theme was mentioned<sup>6</sup>. The amount of trailing whitespace was the most mentioned issue, while the layout of the "stats" area was the largest combined category of related issues.

**LEGEND**

- ✅ Resolved
- ⚠️ Partially resolved
- ❌ Unresolved

---

- ⚠️ Too much trailing whitespace

  - Category: Whitespace
  - Improvements made: Removed watched/ignored labels<sup>7</sup>
  - Further work: Fix the bounty indicator increasing space on the left side, explore adding body excerpt to home page<sup>8</sup>, explore improving wrapping of title/tags/user card
- ⚠️ Increase votes visibility / emphasize votes

  - Category: Stats
  - Improvements made: Moved votes to the topmost (leftmost on mobile) stat, increased visual contrast of votes stat, increased size of stats as a whole, removed visually distracting "supernova" icon from views
  - Further work: Needs discovery / additional user research to identify further specific pain points
- ✅ Don’t like the watched/ignored labels (adds height, too visually distracting)

  - Category: Whitespace, Stats
  - Improvements made: Removed labels entirely, reverted back to highlighting summary background, added icon to watched/ignored tags
  - Further work: Improve UX to better explain why the summary is highlighted/dimmed<sup>9</sup>, improve visuals in dark/high contrast mode<sup>10</sup>
- ❌ Quickly scan by votes (stats horizontally lined up)

  - Category: Stats
  - Improvements made: See above regarding votes visibility
  - Further work: Explore setting home layout to ["minimal"](https://stackoverflow.design/product/components/post-summary/#minimal) always<sup>11</sup>, Do discovery / additional user research on other layouts that provide similar benefits, but still allow for forward progress
- ✅ Stats text too small

  - Category: Stats
  - Improvements made: Stat sizes bumped across the board<sup>12</sup>
  - Further work: Needs discovery / further user research to identify further specific pain points

### So, where do we go from here and what are our next steps?

We're committed to continual improvements on the design. This includes all of the explorations and commitments I've outlined in the previous section.

We're going to continue to roll out this design to the screens it already most resembles. This includes [/questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions), [tagged questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/announcements) and [search results](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bannouncement%5D+user%3A395497). The largest unresolved issue (see above) does not apply to these screens, as they have always had their stats laid out vertically like in the new design.

Additionally, we're going to continue to roll this specific implementation out to the different areas that already use the new design, so they can benefit from the bug fixes and added features.

We will continue monitoring this post for incoming, future bug reports / feature requests.

I know this message will not be well received by a number of users, but we sincerely thank you for your continued feedback.

#### Footnotes

<sup>1</sup> [Here's a recent comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/1250706) from a prolific user about the long standing search results page not implementing functionality seen everywhere else across the site

<sup>2</sup> This user [edited their post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/375474/395497) to reflect that a bug fixed in this set of layout changes isn't working everywhere you'd expect, despite the layout being 100% visually the same

<sup>3</sup> This is due to these items not being able to be made to fit the existing layout, which requires exactly three statistics, no more and no less.

<sup>4</sup> These are shown, but using the question layout with the rest of the posts. Because of this, apps can not be quickly identified in any appreciable way.

<sup>5</sup> The existing search results literally only differentiate answers by showing an `A:` in front of the title. Articles are implemented as an entirely different partial on questions.

<sup>6</sup> I didn't order my list based on upvotes, as many highly upvoted posts included 2 or more different themes. I did notice that there is a pretty strong correlation between "combined number of upvotes" and "number of times mentioned".

<sup>7</sup> Watched/ignored labels along with bounty indicators are the cause for additional trailing whitespace 95% of the time.

<sup>8</sup> The home/recent question pages have never had a body excerpt, while almost every other post summary *does* (see "QuestionSummary" screenshot in the original question taken from [/questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions)). Adding a body excerpt will further unify the implementations visually, potentially at the expense of list "scannability".

<sup>9</sup> This was the primary reason for the inclusion of the labels. User research showed that non-power users often weren't sure why posts were suddenly bright yellow / dimmed.

<sup>10</sup> Using color *only* to indicate state ranges from "not useful" to "actively harmful" for accessibility reasons (e.g. high contrast, color blind).

<sup>11</sup> Basically, force the mobile layout for desktop. Stats are horizontally aligned like before, but are placed above the title. This improves "scannability" at the expense of vertical height.

<sup>12</sup> Stat sizes are not quite as large as they were previously (~25% size reduction). Further increasing the size is at the expense of vertical whitespace, which was the largest single criticism.

---

This update has been carefully written by [Ben Kelly](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/395497/ben-kelly) and reviewed by the CM Team. I'm posting it so we can pin the accepted answer.

Comment: For those who want to see votes in big, easy to see font - use this [userscript](https://stackapps.com/questions/9293/legacyquestions-bringing-back-the-old-questions-design) created by [Spectric](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/863015/spectric), because it looks like SE is not interested in making vote count bigger.

Comment: Once rolled out to /questions, will the question previews stay? While I'm mostly indifferent to these changes, losing the question previews would be a massive loss in my opinion

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing The questions list will display all the same data it does currently. We rolled out to greatest hits first because the implementation there was identical to the one on /questions.

Comment: "I know this message will not be well received by a number of users" My answer is at +501/-3. Your message will be ill-received by all but three users. At least be honest here. "A number of users" should actually read "essentially everyone".

Comment: Why is the tag watch icon added post-render? The content jump is mildly annoying and it seems a waste of processing given you should be able to do everything server-side

Comment: Q: When is an accepted answer not accepted?

Comment: I'm burnt to a crisp.  It's not like we don't understand that you're trying to pay down technical debt, but this pattern of making a change and telling us that it'll be better for us down the road is a tune I've heard from Stack Overflow so many times over the years that the sentiment no longer holds any value.  Don't be surprised that we're dissatisfied with how you're doing this - again, it's not that most of us don't get what tech debt is, but you don't just make changes and tell the customer to accept it.  That's not how a healthy relationship with your customers work.

Comment: SE is breaking the most important pages on all sites here, just to support features for Teams and Collectives. All other goals could be achieved by rewrites that keep most of the old designs. I had some reservations about the new focus for SE, but this is far, far worse than I ever imagined.

Comment: It is quite shameful how you are ignoring your user base and creating a false narrative around the way you are responding to the feedback. Pretending you are addressing feedback when you are just fixing egregious design flaws in the new UI/UX which you sold as solving a problem no one had, along with  "may consider the Stacks team's approach a step backwards in UI/UX" and "this message will not be well received by a number of users" is dangerously close to plainly gaslighting your user base. I have used the SE forums for 10 years, and this seems like what may make me want to stop. Sad.

Comment: "Responsiveness - This was the primary catalyst for the change. The old layout was unusable on mobile and could not be feasibly scaled to work." Perhaps, but I suspect quite a lot of the critique is from people using this site on the *desktop*. And SE *is* the second (or first!) screen for a lot of people.

Comment: "increased visual contrast of votes stat," is not enough.. answers are still more present... "increased size of stats as a whole"well.. is still not enough.... they are still little

Comment: As far as "mobile first" strategies. I deal with that myself, and it makes sense for a *lot* of web sites. But consider who the primary users of the main SE sites are: programmers. I think everyone understands that the other stuff (DIY, History, Physics, etc.) is secondary in usage and in $ value to investors. **How many programmers are looking up answers to serious coding questions on their phones?**

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact nothing specifically wrong with _"mobile first"_, it just doesn't have to be _"mobile everywhere"_. There's absolutely no reason that they can't have different layouts per device. I've written a userstyle that uses the current markup and provides the old column layout that could just as easily be applied via media queries.

Comment: Votes visibility is marked as resolved and you have a second unresolved point for "lining up" vote scores... what? Vote visibility will be resolved once the score is the most prominent thing about the listing (maybe after the title), and then you can drop the lining-up part. You write you need "discovery / additional user research" - how about simply using what worked for a decade and *add the votes as a big number in its own column*? Feel free to drop the view count if you need more horizontal space. Given that you've cleaned up the tech debt, such a change should be simple, right?

Comment: I would say that "_too much whitespace_" has been a recurrent problem since the [infamous line-height change](/q/353525/401803), and it has been consistently repeated over and over in all design changes: so much, excessive, useless space everywhere. Information density has been decreasing more and more, every design change makes me see less information at once.

Comment: Excuses...excuses...excuses. This whole process has been completely broken from start to finish. It started with the profile activity lists and instead of cleaning issues up there it snowballed instead

Comment: The way this new design has been forced upon everyone, while refusing to accept that the community doesn't want this, is quite frankly disgusting and disrespectful towards SE's users. For the first time in years this made be wish that there was an alternative to SE.

Comment: "_One of Stacks's goals is to burn down technical debt_" That is Stack's problem. Don't ruin the UI for all users so your developers aren't behind.

Comment: This whole thing reminds me a bit of when the iPhone came out, and it didn't do email, and there were a lot of naysayers who didn't think it would ever catch on. You first have to build the scaffolding, then you can build cool stuff on top of it. I do believe you mean it when you say this is necessary to implement better features, faster, in the future, but you've got to show us the vision.

Comment: @LShaver the fact that the new design heavily de-emphasizes question score has nothing to do with technical debt or "building scaffolding", but is a deliberate (and awful) design decision. They could very easily change the style and/or layout to make the score as prominent as it was previously, as is evident by the various user-styles that do just that in about 50 lines of css. The issue is that SO either does not want to do so, or thinks it's not important enough, against the wishes of many expert users.

Comment: The really funny thing is that deemphasizing the number of votes on questions goes *against* two of the previously added "features" (which are still in effect): *10 points for question upvotes instead of 5* and *reminders when you vote on answers that "you haven't voted on questions in a while"* So which is it? Votes on questions are really important (so let's encourage them by reminding people and by giving more rep) or votes on questions are really not important, so let's minimize visibility of the vote counts.

Comment: @l4mpi - yeah that was my thought exactly.  I really don't get what the big deal is here.  If a stackscript can accomplish this so easily on top of the new UI, why is it such a fight to feature question scores in the way that everyone knows and loves?

Comment: @BenKelly - I think if your team was willing to make *that one concession* it would really go a long way here! After reading your post above, I think most of us grasp the big picture and vision you have, but I find it problematic that your team is being so inflexible about a UI change that nearly everyone in the community is displeased with.

Comment: A partly "visual rollback" where you keep the new code, but shoehorn parts of the old layout onto it, might be the best compromise. Having less code is nice, but ask yourself: is it visually an improvement or rather a regression? Probably it can still be improved a lot and partly is a regression. Instead of living with it for now until maybe it gets fixed, I wonder if it maybe could have worked better right from the beginning. How did you test it before? Is measurement of white spaces or color contrast and visibility of stats part of tests?

Comment: 1. Some of your V marks should actually be X'es. Don't try to rewrite reality. 2. I can relate to not wanting to keep older code for technical debt and uniformity reason. **however** if that is a key consideration, you should simply have had the new mechanism support the old layout (in the visual sense) as one of the visual styling options. That way you could have achieved all of the goals you mentioned. Regardless - you should have _first_ rolled back the changes, and _then_ gone through a proper process of discussing them with the community of users.

Comment: It seems that nobody in the organization understands that no one as users wants this. I'm wondering, how often software developers search for questions on their phones? Have you ever been a coder? I don't see myself compiling apps with my phone.

Comment: @BenKelly *"we’ve decided that it would not be in the long-term interests of the network to roll these changes back. This includes ... a "visual rollback"* - can you explain this a bit more please?  I read the entire **"Why?"** section of the post above and still don't understand why a visual rollback presents an issue. Is it very difficult with your new underlying codebase?

Comment: Footnote #11 is a bit misleading: the biggest consumer of vertical whitespace on wide screens right now ***is** the metadata sidebar!* So forcing the mobile layout actually fits *more* questions on the homepage a good bit of the time. Obviously including a summary will alter this balance a bit, but… Possibly not as much as it would seem, given there's a good chance the new design would push the existing summary to >= 3 lines in many cases due to the 980px constraint on content width. I'd recommend examining popular email UIs for inspiration here: this is a problem with many existing solutions.

Comment: (Er, 728px. Whatever. Point is, the overall layout constraints make desktop rendering on large screens a lot closer to mobile aspect than one might expect, meaning there isn't the wealth of horizontal space to play with that "desktop" might otherwise imply.)

Comment: It looks really good in my opinion. Thank you for keeping such detailed feedback, it's clear that even though you're not giving the most hardcore users what they want that you're listening to how you can improve. An anecdotal survey of my friends and colleagues is that this redesign is much easier to parse and read!

Comment: @dylan-myers... _"you're listening to how you can improve"_. Listening, perhaps. Acting on overwhelming feedback, not so much. Also, _hardcore users_ are what keep StackExchange sites going. Why they feel the need to alienate and dismiss those users is absolutely beyond me

Comment: Ok, now that you understandably burnt down some of the technical debt, change the layout to match what everyone was used to. Don't tell me it can't be done. Everything is possible in software.

Comment: "✅ Increase votes visibility / emphasize votes" - no, it's not resolved so far. It's still very small and uncomfortable to use at all.

Comment: @dylan-myers They're _pretending_ they're listening, and then ignoring and going on with whatever they have planned before. And just to reinforce what was said above, **hardcore users are the ones responsible for creating the true value of SE sites**: the high quality content that built this network (specially Stack Overflow, but also all the [other sites](https://stackexchange.com/sites)) and made it so relevant was created and curated mostly by hardcore users. Their opinions should't be ignored like this

Comment: 1), I'd be interested in knowing:  Why are you setting so much store by the mobile views if they're being deprecated?  Because really, a much higher percentage of your users are looking at desktop views.  2), don't push this to [/questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions).  I personally use that area a *lot* when browsing Stack Exchange and that would be very annoying.  Finally, are you sure you have a good picture of the best interests of the network and its users?

Comment: @Ollie None of this is being shipped to the (old) mobile views. These redesigns are part of the (unified) responsive views.

Comment: @dylan-myers Where’s the user group that supports this change?

Comment: I'm still brooding over this, and I know I shouldn't since it won't accomplish much.  I'm just legitimately disgusted that the company is choosing to ignore the negative feedback that they're getting and deciding to press forward.  It's not the feedback you want to hear - I get that.  I've seen that in spades over the years and I can at least somewhat sympathize with not wanting to be the bearer of bad news on Meta.  But to say that what the community has been asking for is really not a choice at all - wow.  It's not a wedge you've driven; it's a whole chasm.

Comment: I can't say that there's any good pattern from here on out to work with y'all on these things.  I just can't see it. If we don't like something, and we tell you, and you say "But you are going to get it anyway", we just have to roll over and accept it.  That's not an impression that lives long and strong for good reasons in my world.

Comment: @Makoto its their own fault, I dont feel one bit bad for them. **They** are the ones that decided to just drop this, without checking with the community first. Focus grouping with 10 users is not checking with the community. Also you have designers doing this that dont even use Stack Exchange. They have only themselves to blame.

Comment: This UI is horrible to use on mobile. If the intent was to make things better for mobile, it didn't really work out.

Comment: *"✅ Increase votes visibility / emphasize votes"*, *"✅ Stats text too small"* - you guys are **joking**, right? Because this sure is what all of this feels like... a joke. Either that or you are just in denial. Does [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u5VRD.png) look visible or adequately sized to you? At this rate you will have to decrease downvote penalties from -2 to -1 if you want staff members who post on MSE to keep their rep > 1.

Comment: "for the sake of [traffic]" not *community*, whom is obviously giving you the finger about this. SE is (was) about signal to noise. Now you're just trying to keep the traffic up on a 12yo site and justify your jobs. Or sell this Teams crap or Dark Mode (FFS?). As far as the end users of the community are concerned, no changes are necessary. But we're a captive audience so I guess do w/e you want.

Comment: I made a suggested edit on this post to change **"✅ Increase votes visibility / emphasize votes"** to **"⚠️ Partially resolved"** which I feel is fair because we can see some small amount of effort was made to address users' concerns.  However, since it's clearly not "resolved" I don't understand why it's being labelled as such in the accepted post here? **It's not resolved.** @BenKelly - please approve my edit.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to post this. Your argument about needing to make the changes in order to facilitate making other changes the community has requested makes sense. My only minor complaint here is that it might be presumptuous to say that an issue is "resolved" based on your own assessment. Oh, and a general ongoing gripe about the seeming prioritisation of mobile, which does not seem right for SO.

Comment: @SteveBennett *"Your argument about needing to make the changes in order to facilitate making other changes the community has requested makes sense."* - except at this point I wouldn't expect that to be anything but a silly excuse, if not simply a lie.

Comment: I'm sadly giving up on this website. If 600 downvotes and hundreds of negative comments don't make you realize that what you are doing is not appreciated by the community, I'm not sure what will.

Comment: And the post is no longer "Featured on Meta". If that isn't a clear indication that SO inc sees this as resolved, I don't know what is.

Comment: @BenKelly Do you have any intention at all to reply to the comments here? What about Vanny? Do you have any intention at all to listen to the community? Once again, SE is hurting the community, ignoring their input when they give it, and silently trying to weasel out of it with some corporate speak.

Comment: @pilchard Accepted answers on meta are commonly used to "pin" official responses.

Comment: "*The old layout [...] could not be feasibly scaled to work.*" This is simply objectively false. In two words: media queries. The design was greatly improved for mobile, yes, but then the work to treat larger screens/viewports with the respect and care they deserve seems to have been either phoned in or abandoned altogether, and media queries, which I'm sure the SE design/UI devs are familiar with using, would solve this **very easily**.

Comment: I put a screenshot in the revision explanation of my edit, but here is an example of the persisting pain points of the new vote/score section compared to the old one: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XptxX.png @BenKelly - Fix this for desktop-sized viewports (1366px and wider) and I guarantee >90% of the complaints about that will go away.

Comment: "Over the years, many highly-desired feature requests have gone unanswered specifically because the work burden associated with UI and UX changes is high" Because of this you're going to ignore even more highly requested changes to go back to what this ruined, because the burden in fixing what you messed up is too high, and requires you actually admit to being wrong? That's the way I read this, and I am sure most others do to. This is the second worst move SE has made after the Monica issue, with the whole community agreeing you're wrong.

Comment: I know this was already posted, but better safe than sorry: please, **increase vote size on questions**.

Comment: White space is *partially resolved*. [Are you sure?](https://imgur.com/Xu2rTao)

Comment: Hamburger, SE Hamburger, magnifying glass, in box, vote thing, question mark, another hamburger, Log In, and Sig [sic].  - Oh boy, where do I *sig* up?

Comment: @Zombo they "focus group" checked with 170 users (that's 0.02% of the SE rep league for reference) using a biased self selection method (SOfT users) which introduced some pretty HEAVY bias into their responses that is clearly counter to the opinion of just about everyone else who uses SE. They did every single step of this process 100% wrong, and want to force us to live with it, not to mention the lies about how they can't follow through with what we want, proven lies because user CSS has done just that within a day.

Comment: You can't decide what's in the long-term interest of the network, you can only adopt an assumption. Anyway, it's high time to revisit this "decision".

Answer (score 581):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)

#### I cared about question scores, but now my head hurts.

On the previous layout, I could quickly survey the question scores by reading down the votes column:

[image]

Now, I simply cannot quickly survey the front page for question scores, as those scores are quite small and buried between other information:

[image]

To me, this is *a complete loss of functionality of scores on the front page*. Trying to read the scores on the page, quite literally, makes my eyes and head hurt.

So I guess I can word this as a [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request): **please change it back.**

Comment: If "don't fix what isn't broken" fits your theme it would be a nice BLUF.  Up to you...

Comment: Same, but on mobile it's sandwiched in the middle horizontally, which is much worse: "1 answer 5 votes 109 views". It's often the least prominent number color-wise too.

Comment: Also: [view count now more prominent than score](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/375180/183280). I fear this is by design, and popularity is deemed more important than quality…

Comment: Given views and answers, on top and bottom, both change colors based on status, and score doesn't, by default deemphasizes the score (also... it's score... not votes... feel like we've had this discussion)

Comment: So who is going to be the first to create a greasemonkey script to fix this atrocious redesign?

Comment: The vertical alignment of those statistic boxes makes no sense either

Comment: It makes sense from a lets have one design for everything perspective. Even bounties show up in the left statistic area now. One design for everything doesn't often produce the best design for each individual usecase.

Comment: @SurpriseDog Glorfindel! Hear our prayers!

Comment: Agreed completely, previous layout made **much more sense**.  If there's a problem with mobile, then change it on mobile.  Leave us desktop folks alone.

Comment: To elaborate your argument for the previous layout, I would put it this way. Previously the score, view count, answers are tabulated and treated as primary information side by side with "content data" such as the title and tags. Now they are presented in a nested list, which groups them and subsumes this list to the stuff about the content of the post, creating a two-level structure of information.

Comment: However this is not how these numerical data are used. They have been playing a much more primary role in a user's decision to view a question or not, and have an importance closer to the title than the tags or the most recent activity. Thus they deserve the more prominent position in the older design.

Comment: What is the point of SE at all if you can't actually see the votes?  Might as well be quora.

Comment: @NoahSnyder: You *can* see the votes. They aren't hidden. They're just not the most prominent thing anymore.

Comment: I'm really missing the [free-hand red circles](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19775/183280) in this answer

Comment: @Bergi might put some mobile screenshots in, if i do, they will feature red circles.

Comment: @NicolBolas note everyone can see all colours equally on all backgrounds.... (particularly with smaller text sizes)

Comment: This answer was unfairly labeled "feature request". It is not.

Comment: @einpoklum the answerer added the feature request tag at the bottom of their answer. The staff member just put it at the top. I don't think there was anything unfair about it.

Comment: I'm personally fine with making votes small and unobtrusive; I don't think a post's score is anywhere near as important as a question's title, *or even tags.* But I'm with @Elliot as to the core problem: by losing the ability to "read down" within a single type of data (score / answers / views) the work involved in extracting information is greatly increased - for each line, I have to *read* vs. scan to determine the meaning of the number my eyes land on. Could probably relegate the text (answers / votes / views) to column headers and achieve a similar savings in real estate...

Comment: (Also probably worth noting that this only really matters for the home page; question pages haven't been great in this regard for a long time, although the smaller text makes it hurt more; profiles were apparently already trashed when it came to tabular scanning a few months ago. We ... can at least be thankful that the question pages won't be as bad as question/answer lists in the new profile. I hadn't seen that until now; having done so, I suddenly like this design *better*. Good lord, what a flaming trainwreck.)

Comment: The scores are also incorrectly labelled as "votes" in the summary. *”Purveyors of fine cheese!”* doesn't have 49 votes; it has 56 (+52/-3). Its _score_ is 49.

Comment: @doppelgreener This has been mentioned here: [“the wording votes is wrong, it should be score”](/a/375181/289905).

Comment: I've attempted to rectify this via [user styles](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/375511/158281). It's not exactly the same as it used to be but at least it's back to a grid format

Comment: @Shog9 I think the score is pretty important... if there's a negative score in an area I know about, I like to go in and try to fix it, or at least leave constructive comments for the person who asked the question.  (Because, few else seem to care to do this, and I'd rather help people than just obliterate their posts outright.)  If there's a zero-score or low-score, it's probably a new question or a question that hasn't received any attention, and I like to look at it to see if I can answer, or close as duplicate as necessary.

Comment: @ThomasMarkov and you even did not mention the new "Watched" yellow blob that shows at over 90% of my "top" questions and makes it impossible to quickly scan that page if there's something worth answering. Also, the new design makes the number of votes / answers too hard to read, because there's no whitespace around it and the position is not as fixed. For me the change means I'll take a break from answering questions on stack overflow for fun because finding questions worth answering just got a lot harder.

Comment: @576i The peepee colored watched tag was added after I posted this answer.

Comment: @ThomasMarkov thanks for pointing this out. The new design hit me this morning and my first reaction is that browsing/answering questions on SO for fun is over until this is fixed.

Comment: The *order* of the information changed, too, not just the orientation. It went from votes, answers, views to answers, votes, views. *Of course* votes are the most important of these for a community web site; they're the *community driven* sorting mechanism.

Comment: In a way, I am grateful for this change. It may actually improve my productivity! It's so hideous I'll probably quit procrastinating by scrolling through SE so often! >:D  (jk)

Comment: Another reason for the feature request: It is now very difficult to see if a question has a negative score, especially when it is a small number like -11 rather than a big negative score like -349. This is especially difficult in the mobile view.

Comment: I'm sure SE is mostly just dismissing feedback because "nobody likes change" but this is a great example of how it actually makes it way harder to parse the data. Reading down a single column vs. having to find text that's sandwiched in between other text

Comment: @BenKelly can't you see how much negative comments this UI/UX change received? Please revert it back. My eyes bleed from that question list, it's nearly unusable that way, I can't participate anymore actually because I find it very difficult to pick questions to answer with this design.

Comment: I'm not versed enough to offer specific criticism, but I generally check SE on my phone, and I **hate** the new UI with a passion! Almost impossible to read, compared to previous layout! Please stop it!

Comment: I really despise the whole 'meta' side of stackexchange, but I joined this community just to share my support of this post. This change is horrendously bad for usability.

Comment: The grey value is bad. There is no visual handrail. It's harder to distinct what's the important value. Cannot be done at a glance. AND green is far brighter and less important to the viewer than black font on white backgrounds. Please think of visually impaired people, too. You design guys clutter the UX and disimprove already perfect designs. Thanks for asking.

Answer (score 564):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)

## Revert this

As critical feedback goes this is probably the sharpest I've delivered, but this change is neither needed nor warranted.  It doesn't make me enjoy using the site on desktop, which is what I do during the course of my day.

It strains my eyes a bit to have to read the smaller text of the title, compared with the even smaller text of the other information I'm not sure I need to know in the moment.

Revert this, and revisit this.  This UX is **not** good.

---

In response to the third update - they're not going to revert this.  So I'm burnt to a whole crisp on this.  This is yet another case in which the company has decided to introduce an intrusive change that they insist is for the benefit of the community, but those benefits won't be realized for a long while.  Like, I get it - it's innocent in and of itself, and paying tech debt is something I make a living out of these days - but this whole sentiment of "we'll fix it later, promise" is so played out that I can't take the company seriously anymore.

I should just stop giving feedback.  You're going to do whatever you please and we're powerless to do anything about it.  Just make the changes and post them to your blog and that'd be a better experience than having the modicum of hope that is you posting something on Meta about this.

Don't give me the "incremental changes" as something to indicate that you're listening to our feedback.  **We *use* this site every day.**  We *liked* the way it looked.  You thrust this change on the entire damn network after talking with a *handful* of people about some obscure page that I think I've seen maybe twice in the ten years I've used the site, and decided to pick ***that*** as the standard for all posts.

Why did I even bother...

Comment: It doesn't look good on mobile either. I really don't see what the improvement was.

Comment: @Dharman:  Yeah, I took a peek on my phone and I'm really not seeing a delta there either.

Comment: @Makoto Congratulations, after a few days of this question being bountied, I plan to award my bounty to you, as I want this change **GONE** and the previous design back. I completely agree that it should be reverted, so you will probably get the bounty.

Comment: I only entered to meta to verify that I was not the only one who found the new design absolutely terrible, now I am calmer

Comment: I miss the summaries or excerpts that were added beneath the title, the front page now just looks ... cheap.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen There never was summary text on the home page. This has been [mentioned before](/a/375475/289905).

Comment: @SebastianSimon But I *have* seen summaries on Stack Overflow, and now they're gone. I can't see them anywhere. I guess my bookmark was not to the main home page.

Comment: This is all that needs to be said. And while you're at it, SE, bring back the old profile view. Stop making this website worse and worse with every change.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen As also mentioned in the linked comment thread, excerpts have always been on [`/questions`](/questions), never on [`/`](/).

Comment: Old design was functional and easier on eyes. Both homepage and profile page seem less informative to me now.

Comment: @SebastianSimon /questions was the default homepage for people when logged in, IIRC.

Comment: Amazing that they can implement all these changes that make it harder to identify relevant questions but I still have to [manually remove deleted questions from my Followed list](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/374697/374623).

Comment: I was surprised to see the original post having a high score when I initially saw it. For a second, I almost thought I was just being difficult to changes. Thanks, you made me feel like my distaste of the new design wasn't just me being a hard head.

Comment: @Zombo in fairness to Ben, I know for a fact that plenty of SE employees maintain multiple accounts--we don't know that the human behind "Ben" doesn't use SE, we just know this account doesn't use SE. That said, I do not dispute the notion that SE, *generally*, needs to understand its own product better. I've said as much here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/346437/311001.

Comment: This change *still* hasn't been reverted. A bigger bounty coming your way @Makoto (I'll award it within the next week, just to get some more attention on this post)

Comment: This is the only reasonable thing to do. To revert and to forget about this

Comment: If they don't want to revert it, at least make it an option in the account settings. Same thing as the bar on the left that I hid since it appeared.

Comment: @Dharman for the user there was no improvement - this makes the lives of SE staff easier (and harder for users) as part of their retiring the mobile views, and somewhat standardising the layouts. Less for them to maintain, but less useful to users with different priorities who made use of those different options.

Comment: @Clockwork I think what happened is the original post only had any attention from their test users, those who approved of the design, and thus suffered from a selection bias from being users recruited from on specific subgroup (SOfT users) which aren't representative of most of the site's userbase, and it shows by most of us disagreeing strongly with their rushed and undertested change.

Comment: For what it's worth, I just used µBlock to hide away the "view" count on ALL questions. With only vote count and answer count, the lines aren't nearly as clunky and overloaded, and it feels almost as user friendly as before.

Comment: "Why did I even bother" - yeah, that's something I asked myself quite a few times in the past, until I stopped bothering entirely and accepted that SO is going down the drain unless some drastic organizational change happens. On the plus side, remember two weeks ago when you complained on meta.SO about the bad log4j blog post - doesn't seem very important anymore now does it? You might re-read my answer to that question from your newfound perspective of not taking the company seriously anymore.

Comment: @l4mpi:  Oh, no I still think the company should fix their tacky and out-of-place blog post about the Log4Shell.  Everything's burning, and something else that's burning doesn't mean that this other thing that's on fire isn't somehow still important or not burning.

Comment: @Makoto fire analogies - how about this one: if your food is burning on the stove _while the whole house is ablaze_ then you probably wouldn't ask for someone to go and turn off the stove. But that's orthogonal to my point, which is that if the company doesn't offer a meaningful response to issues like this after all the community outrage, we have literally zero chance of any meaningful change on the blog. Of course you're free to continue fighting against windmills, but I for one would be extremely surprised if you even get an official response, nevermind one that results in a useful change.

Comment: If you go to https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions you will have a nice layout (https://i.imgur.com/WYW1ozs.png) but going to https://meta.stackexchange.com/ will ruin your day (https://i.imgur.com/0XeU5AR.png), and shows how the company will implement anything, no matter how horrible it is. I really wish they would listen to you, but, I lost hope in 2019...

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel if you go to [meta.stackexchange.com](https://meta.stackexchange.com) *on mobile* ([screenshot](https://imgur.com/a/Ffv8yNg)) you might as well just pretend you are blind and use the text to speech accessibility feature to let the phone read the page for you. My head hurts just looking at this complete mess of mixed, unaligned, scrambled content for more than 10 seconds.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli That feels like someone is sticking needles into my eyes. Thanks, my whole year is ruined. Yuck! That is, indeed, disgustingly unusable, specially for something that was supposed to be BETTER for mobile...

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel yeah, the most ridicolous part of all this is that I have *no idea* how they can say that they want they wanted a mobile-friendly design. The current /questions design on mobile is perfect as is.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli This is the definition of "Changes for the sake of changing", not for improvement. Anyone can see that this is not an improvement.

Answer (score 289):

[discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion)

Ridiculous amounts of vertical white space on watched and/or bountied questions.

[image: red boxes showing all the extra white space]

The old design had no problem fitting all of that information in the same vertical space as the title and tags, so this feels like a huge step backwards in that regard.

This could at least be partly mitigated by simply reverting to how questions with watched tags used to work (i.e. the colored background).

Comment: Totally agree the amount of unnecessary padding and vertical white space reduces the amount of questions I can see at once and diminishes my site experience

Comment: ugh, I agree. One of the justifications for deploying this design was to support an increasing number of stats for each question. But this answer is the reason why we should not have more than 3 at most.

Comment: The first one (Bounty + watched) would look even worse if the question was a single line, which it easily could be. It would be like 2/3rds wasted.

Comment: This empty space could be filled by the summary text that they removed but apparently that's not coming back!

Comment: The watched tag background not being highlighted anymore is really annoying

Comment: @phuzi There never was summary text on the home page. This has been [mentioned before](/a/375475/289905).

Comment: And [watched] is yellow. Someone needs to read Edward Tufte.

Comment: "Hey, you probably haven't noticed the list of watched tags to your right, so LOOK AT ME I AM YELLOW!" All this makes me want to do is remove my entire list of watched tags.

Comment: @Michael [Here's an example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pyLdT.png) of how that looks like.

Comment: At what point those blank spaces improve something? Even If there are some improvement of the new design that I have not seen yet, the importance of those new blank spaces is evident

Comment: And if we are going to have a [watched] tag are we going to have [followed]?  What about [favorite]?  Any others?  I hate it

Comment: @ChrisRogers The idea of the change was "support an indefinite number of labels". I guess no one stopped to think "what if an indefinite number of labels looks completely stupid?"

Comment: Agree, amount of blank space is huge. Why should we look at blank space?

Comment: The number of stats themselves is not the problem. They could just be placed horizontally over the title and we would still save space.

Comment: The bounty indicator could be perhaps inlined into the title. (The “Watched” and “Ignored” labels are gone, good riddance.)

Comment: **Update 2** [makes this even worse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OndRP.png). At least, it looks worse. Wish I could upvote this again to gain more attention to useless vertical white space.

Comment: @0stone0 : Maybe after [finding out about all the "white" people visiting SO using the race-enthusiastic survey](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/415648/1593077), SE inc. has decided we need more space for whiteness on the site :-P

Comment: @demonplus: When you hit 100,000 reputation you unlock the feature of collapsing the useless white space to see more questions.

Comment: @einpoklum from a 100k+ user... _"You raised my hopes and dashed them quite expertly, sir. Bravo!"_

Comment: Seems like the current version has *too little* whitespace; it feels cluttered now.  Maybe that's just because the info I want to look at is smaller so surrounding clutter makes it worse.  (Especially last modification: asked/answered/modified, and the username and rep of the user making that change.  The tags I follow are low-enough traffic for me to basically moderate / police them, so I want to see what's happening to questions.)

Answer (score 232):

[discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion)

### tl;dr: Please don't do this to question lists; the motivation is invalid.

> We’re starting a rollout of the new post summary design

Please stop the rollout - on question list pages anyway; the new design for question lists is [worse than the existing one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/375481/196834).

> Our current designs ... fall short ... :
>
> - We generally assume 3 items of metadata: score, answers, and views. If we want to add new entries for e.g. bookmarks or revisions, it can be difficult to create a consistent layout in a list of questions.

And difficult it should be. It is tempting to "stuff" more meta-data into the question list, but there are diminishing returns. It would make more sense to have an alternative question list view with more meta-data, used when someone indicates that they want that meta-data.

> - Inconsistencies in implementation have led to several different layouts across the SE network. When gathering requirements for a unified post summary component, we found at least 5 (five!) different layouts.

That's orthogonal to changing the basic design of question lists, which is mostly (or fully?) uniform across the site. If that design needs to be changed, explain why, then change it; if it doesn't - address whatever inconsistencies you find.

> - Scaling the design is tricky, both in window size and adding features and functionality. We need to support all sorts of metadata on all sorts of devices.

I don't see what's tricky; and that challenge has already been met for many years. Also, you should not aim for a question list packed with a bunch more data and features.

> - Our post summaries were only designed to support questions (and answers, kinda).

I don't know what post summaries are, I'm referring to the question list design. If you mean question titles, then - yes, StackExchange is a network of Q&A sites. Are you saying you intend to change this? For existing sites even? I hope not...

> - We need to be able to display various content types in single lists.

No you don't. Or rather, not in the question list. The question list needs to display questions and a bit of meta-data about them, and it has done so reasonably well.

> - For example, in a list of notifications, we may want to present an article next to a question.

Please don't force the design of a list of notifications on the list of questions.

> - Our new post-summary design solves these problems while supporting future features we’re exploring.

As I've explained above, you have not presented problems with the question list design. So, the new design solves problems which *may* exist for *other lists/pages*, not the question list. That's a poor reason for changing the question list design.

> Some features we’re looking forward to are:

It's nice that you're working on some generic item-summary-list design, but don't work on it at the expense of the acceptable/good design for question lists we have had so far.

Comment: Every single point in this is spot on.

Comment: The weirdest part about this to me is that they talk about the changes as if they were intended to improve *visual consistency* ("We need different kinds of lists to have the same underlying design! For some reason!"), but that aspect of things just got *noticeably worse*.

Comment: And, incremental changes are apparently a lost art. There's no reason this needs to be some giant sweeping redesign. Want to [get rid of the "modified" notation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/375467/87234)? Then do _just that_ and see what people think. Likewise for any of the number of other changes. Heck, maybe in isolation one of them is actually good...

Answer (score 191):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

#### It is very hard to ignore my ignored questions.

Could you come up with something more subtle than an ostentatious black box leading the way, such as the post highlighting/greying we used before that worked perfectly fine?

[image]

If I have my ignored tags set up to still be visible on the page, ignoring should make the post *less* imposing (like the old greying out did), not more imposing by adding an eyesore of a black box.

That said, after some experimentation I prefer the black ignored tag to the gross yellow watched tag for watching tags, so I’ve ignored my watched tags for now.

Comment: It's also worth pointing out that on desktop, the new ignored/watched tags make the questions take up *more* vertical space. So if you ignore a tag, questions with that tags now take up *more* screen space, with a coloured tag *highlighting* the now larger question...making it *extra* visible.

Comment: I came here to post this exact same thing. The "ignored" bar is the single most attention-grabbing thing on the page. In fact I'm missing the posts I actually _want_ to see _between_ the ignored posts. It's successfully made _all the other_ questions subdued by comparison. I didn't have this trouble with the previous layout—ignored posts were just faded out and that was that!

Comment: If you click on the “edit” button in the “Ignored Tags” sidebar section on the home page, there’s a radio button setting of “Hide questions in your ignored tags” vs. “Gray out questions in your ignored tags”. Isn’t it an option for you to simply hide these posts?

Comment: @SebastianSimon That's somewhat missing the point - if the option to "gray out" is still there, its effect should not be to make the questions *more* prominent.

Comment: @SebastianSimon Also, while I might want to ignore the tags *most of the time*, occasionally there might be a title I find interesting enough to look into, or a situation where a new user might need some help with their question (new user plus downvoted score can indicate this)

Comment: We have partially reverted the label approach, but kept all of the other changes for ignored entries. Additionally, the titles themselves were intended to be muted as well, but weren't. We've addressed this in the latest round of changes.

Answer (score 148):

[discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) [status-deferred](/questions/tagged/status-deferred)

It's [an old bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/229608/votes-vs-score-in-review-queue), but might be worth revisiting: the wording **votes** is wrong, it should be **score**.

The number that is displayed is not the number of votes on a post, but rather the *score* derived from number of upvotes and number of downvotes. Controversial posts can have a huge number of votes but still a score around 0.

If some countable noun is desired, maybe "*net votes*"?

Comment: Also recently mentioned in [New responsive Activity page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/372652).

Comment: I agree that it should probably be called _score_. However, I'm currently considering that beyond the scope of this change since the new layout is maintaining the status quo in regards to data shown / wording. My recommendation for passers by would be to support the linked meta post. In the meanwhile, I'll raise this suggestion internally to talk about our options. This may seem like a super easy change, but that's deceptive. We have to ensure the wording is consistent everywhere cross-site, which will in turn invalidate a lot of translations for our non-English Stack Overflows.

Comment: This is already on our backlog and I think it's being looked at right now.

Comment: The problem with this, is that when you read a number and after that a word, you take in your mind that is a whole.. if you read a number, and under it a word, you take the word as a title for the number... this is in fact, everywhere.. so is not a wording problem... is a showing problem....

Comment: If we would remove downvotes instead, we could also leave the wording as it is... Otherwise we should really change the wording rather sooner than later. Did really nobody realize the mistake internally before the change going public?

Comment: @Trilarion: The use of the wording "votes" isn't a change - that wording was already used throughout much of the site. Bergi's just proposing that this wording be changed to "score".

Comment: @V2Blast You're right. It seems to be an old mistake, which kind of makes it even more strange that nobody really thought about how meaningful "-X votes" is and did something about it. I now stumble over it more because before votes was written very small and the score really big, my brain was able to filter votes away. Now it cannot do it anymore and it somehow looks wrong. Let's see what the solution will be.

Comment: There is another MSE post about it with the [status-review] tag already on it, so it's already something we're looking at: [Use "score" instead of "votes" in the list of questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/153515/335251)

Comment: @V2Blast "it's already something we're looking at" Almost 10 years old issue. I really need to adjust my expectations. I'm far too impatient for this world.

Comment: @Trilarion Don't get into local town planning. I asked about making a street safer for pedestrians, and they told me they "had a plan for that." This plan was made 40 years ago. Still no sidewalk.

Answer (score 128):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign)

Wow, no text summaries for the questions anymore?

Frankly, this is the most awful change I've ever seen on Stack Overflow.  There's no other way to put it.  It makes it very difficult to browse now.

This has to be a bug, right?

**Update:** See comments below from Ben and Catija.  You can get the old view by using the "Questions" link on the left nav.

[image: Bad Question Display]

Comment: dunno if it's the *most* awful, but,

Comment: @KevinB Can you think of something worse?

Comment: I hope its a bug. it really is hard to read since everything is almost the same size.

Comment: If it's not an outright bug, it feels like some dark pattern stuff.  "Let's increase the number of click-throughs to questions.  How do we hit some [arbitrary metric] before [arbitrary time]?  I know..."

Comment: @Brad it's all subjective, but i found sticky header, sticky navbar, to both be a far bigger annoyance than this one.

Comment: @KevinB Oh yeah!!  I forgot about that one.  That was pretty jarring.

Comment: So, the home/recent questions page this post is referring to has _never_ had text summaries. See the screenshots in the original post, specifically [QuestionMini](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Og2Z.png). We did actually considering adding body excerpts on that page, but decided to punt on it to maintain the status quo. See the `questions/greatest-hits` page for an example of what it looks like _with_ excerpts.

Comment: @BenKelly Does the StackOverflow link in the corner go somewhere else now?  I always remember seeing the question summaries.  Maybe the way I navigate the site is now taking me somewhere else?

Comment: Can't please everyone, huh? :) [related](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/375232/786798)

Comment: @Brad the "Questions" link in the side nav goes to [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions) which does have summaries.

Comment: Nah, the home page doesn't have descriptions - that's one of the reasons I like it so much - it's compact, focused on titles only. The /questions view is the one that's always had summaries.

Comment: @Catija Weird... I don't think I've ever used the "questions" page or left nav... so whatever link I was following before (which I thought was the logo) must not go to it anymore.  Anyway, that solves it for me, thanks.

Comment: @Brad Nothing changed here. The “Questions” items in the left navigation always went to [`/questions`](/questions) and never to [`/`](/). On Stack Overflow, the logo always went to `/`. Here, the “Meta” logo at the top always went to [`/`](/).

Comment: I have my left navigation hidden, but now I need it to see summaries :-(

Comment: @BenKelly I have to say that I could not believe this page never had snippets in the first place, so I went to check the web archive, and indeed, it never had snippets, which I still cannot believe. The old design just looked... I don't know, complete? And the new design just looks... as if it has been stripped of something important, which I guess translates to the feeling that the snippets are missing even though they aren't. It must be a massive blunder in design if the *same amount of information* used to look complete, and now doesn't.

Comment: @GSerg I made the exact same mistake and probably for the same reason. It just *looks* like something must be missing.

Comment: For anyone who wants a reminder about what the homepage looked like, there's a screenshot of it from November 2021 [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d2L1I.png)

Comment: @BryanKrause And something is [indeed missing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/375479/147640) - the yellowish background for the watched tags and the grayed out ignored tags. It looks as a continuous white sheet without that, with nothing for the eye to catch on. Hopefully it is indeed status-planned and will be brought back, the current Watched label is [absolutely hideous](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/415540/11683) and does not serve the purpose of visually splitting the page into areas of interest.

Comment: I don't understand why `/` and `/questions` even have a separate existence in the first place. As far as I can tell, right now they are the **same content**, presented two different ways.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel they're not the same and haven't been for a long time. The homepage has filters that remove some content from visibility, such as low-scoring questions and some locked questions. This is subtle and most people aren't aware of these filters but they do exist.

Comment: Why can't I instead, like, configure it so that `/` shows me my preferred filter? Why aren't those features you describe, that "remove some content from visibility", explicit options offered to me when I create my own filter? Why shouldn't I be able to specify or update filters on every page that shows me a question list? *What good are* "subtle" features attached to a page presenting the same sort of data with totally separate layout rules and interface? I thought **consistency** was an expressly stated goal here?

Comment: @BenKelly Your comments about excerpts don't square with my experience. I have always used `/` as a path. I changed nothing. But excerpts are gone now. Either you are wrong about `/`, or there was some additional state (cookies?) that modified the view of `/`. This matters, because the page loses almost all of its utility without excerpts. (Why *any* view would eliminate excerpts and attempt to rely on the VLQ titles typical of SO baffles me, but that's a different issue.)

Comment: There were excerpts on my home page. I feel like I'm being gaslit with everyone insisting there weren't. There were, there absolutely were. It must be some user setting. I **know** I had excerpts at `https://stackoverflow.com`, not any sub-page, because my SOP for 10 years has been to click on any post starting with "Hi", "Hello", or "So..." and edit that stuff out.

Comment: @Ben and others doubting their own sanity as to question excerpts on the homepage: they *did* exist - until sometime in early march 2017. Just not in the way that other views have them! For years, the homepage showed the excerpt as hovertext / "title text" - hover over a question on [this archive link](https://web.archive.org/web/20170307092740/https://meta.stackoverflow.com/) and see for yourself...

Comment: @Shog9 Apparently, you were able to toggle excerpts at some point: [Improving our navigation, the next iteration](/q/261307/289905). Was this toggle button actually available on the affected homepage?

Comment: Oh yeah, @SebastianSimon - if you opted into that UX (and thousands did), you could have the homepage (and other views) tailored to your precise needs and wants. It was ... Very nice.

Comment: @JohnKugelman Thank you for commenting... glad to know I'm not going crazy!  Or maybe we all are together somehow...

Comment: @JohnKugelman Totally agree, not sure what's going on. All I know is, when I went to "stackoverflow.com" the resulting page was beautiful and useful and had excerpts. That is no longer the case, **hard stop**. I don't want arguments about how other people didn't notice or literally didn't have them. *I did* and now it's broken.

Answer (score 125):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

This design just hit live for the main page of Meta SE ([this page, for clarity](https://meta.stackexchange.com/)) and I've noticed that we've lost a pretty useful bit - The most recent activity notation next to the question listing.

When a post receives a modification (an edit, reopening, etc.) it "bumps" that post on the front page, and will display a "modified" notation along with the user (or Community if it was a deleted user/bumped by Community) who modified the post. That "modified" notation is clickable, and will take you to the post (answer or question) within that entry that was modified.

Here's what that looked like:

[image: Image of old design with a modified link]

That link was *profoundly* useful when navigating to an answer that was modified on a question with many answers (multiple pages of answers), and it feels like an oversight that it's no longer available. It allowed a user to at-a-glance see *who* changed the post, and be able to quickly click the link to see *what* was changed.

For an example, I've just bumped *this* question with *this* answer, and the home page only indicates the date that this question was asked:

[image: Current design, with the "asked on (date)" notation only]

Which leaves the question of why this post was bumped unclear.

Could we restore that functionality?

Comment: That was added in 2014 in response to [this feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/145039/can-we-add-asked-answered-edited-text-to-each-question-featured-on-the-f).

Comment: Nice catch, I'd definitely consider this a regression. We do have support for this functionality written into the new component, it just isn't getting triggered for this instance. I took another look at the old view and found where the logic differs. I'll get a fix out for this today.

Comment: Note that this isn't JUST "bumped" posts on the home page - the normal question views also support this, including tag views (although irritatingly, search results do not).

Comment: @Shog9 Yup, I'm aware of all those and they'll have this enabled when their migration goes live. I'm using the same feature here - it's literally a boolean to turn on. The migrated logic for this particular implementation was incorrect, so it wasn't triggering. Regarding search results, I'm working on the migration for those now - I'll check to see if it makes sense to turn on support there as well ;).

Comment: This has been fixed and rolled out cross network

Comment: @BenKelly this is still broken when loading newly active questions on-the-spot (clicking on "X questions with recent activity")

Comment: "Which leaves the question of why this post was bumped unclear." I want to see **both**. I hate when I am browsing by newest, see something with recent activity, start reading the question, want to ask OP for a clarification... and then notice that the question is years old and OP is presumably not coming back.

Comment: Never mind the link, just showing the "modified" time enabled me to see what had new activity since my last visit. Thank God *that* got fixed quick!

Answer (score 123):

[discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign)

It appears that the view count is now more important than the vote count. Previously, score and answer count were larger numbers, with a font size equivalent to that of the question title.

Maybe this impression is just caused from [greatest hits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/greatest-hits) being, well, greatest hits by view count and thereby all questions in that list having the  "supernova" icon, but the orange highlight makes it stand out too much. Should a similar emphasis be put on questions with >10, >100 or >1000 votes?

Comment: Yes please to increasing the font sizes on score and answer values to be more like current. Especially in search result lists. Context of the list matters.

Comment: This is a good point. In most of the preexisting post summary layouts, view count was deemphasized. The greatest hits page does somewhat exacerbate the problem, but (imo) it looks much better in normal circumstances. I'll bring this up internally, but for now I'm going to mark this as "by design".

Comment: @BenKelly I would respectfully disagree that it looks better in "normal" circumstances, particularly on the main Questions page.

Comment: Why does view count need to be highlighted at all? I want high quality content which is indicated by the post score, not how many times it has been viewed.

Comment: Bergi, assuming you like many of us don’t like it any better on non-“greatest hits” pages, you should either remove status-bydesign or ask Ben to do so, because I, for one, definitely feel this needs revisiting.

Comment: @BenKelly any results from bringing it up internally? If this really is "by design", then the design is garbage and should be redone. It has been discussed time and time again that popularity is a very bad indicator of quality, and that the post score is by far the most important metric we have on the SE network.

Comment: @BenKelly there's been a lot of "Defect by design" changes rolling out, particularly in this case where the test platform was something I didn't even know existed, and most users probably never used - there was some pretty heavy selection bias in designing for the rare user who knows about, and prefers, that greatest hit page.

Answer (score 98):

[discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion)

> ### Why we’re making these changes
>
> Our current designs have withstood the test of time, but they fall short in many areas:

May I humbly propose that the reasons for these changes are not actually good reasons in the first place?

> 1. We generally assume 3 items of metadata: score, answers, and views. If we want to add new entries for e.g. bookmarks or revisions, **it can be difficult** to create a consistent layout in a list of questions.

I've highlighted this part to point out that the difficulty you're talking about is a difficulty for *you*, the UI designer. The goal of UI design is surely to make things easier for the user; making things easier for the designer is important insofar as it makes it easier to make things easier for the user, it normally should not come at the cost of making things *harder* for the user.

> 2. Inconsistencies in implementation have led to several different layouts across the site. When gathering requirements for a unified post summary component, we found at least 5 (five!) different layouts.

Lists of questions can appear differently on different pages because those pages have different purposes. You found 5 different layouts because they were designed for 5 different use-cases. It is a deoptimisation to attempt to unify them.

If I'm browsing a list of recent questions then the most important information to me is the question score (particularly whether it's positive or negative) and the tags; if I'm browsing search results for a problem I have, the most important information to me is an excerpt of the post's content. But in the list of recent questions, an excerpt is not information I am going to use to decide whether to click on a post, and in a list of search results, the tags are secondary because they don't tell me whether a post is specifically about exactly the same problem as I have.

> 3. Scaling the design is tricky, both in window size and adding features and functionality. We need to support all sorts of metadata on all sorts of devices.

It doesn't really matter to me as an end-user if the page I'm looking at would look nice in a different sized window or on a different sized screen than the one I'm reading it on. Different layouts might be optimal for different devices, so again it is a deoptimisation to attempt to completely unify the design across devices.

> 4. Our post summaries were only designed to support questions (and answers, kinda). We need to be able to display various content types in single lists. For example, in a list of notifications, we may want to present an article next to a question.

See #2. If you're showing a list of questions on the home page then it is irrelevant whether an article could be shown uniformly alongside those questions, because articles don't appear on that page anyway.

> 5. We have no unified place to put an action menu.

See #2. What's missing from this list of five reasons is any real *problem* users had with the old UI, or any *use case* that a user might have such that a redesign would serve that user better. These five reasons are all focused on things which matter to the designer, not to the user.

As a user, I do respect the fact that making things easier for the people who develop and design the products I use is ultimately something which serves me, and asking a designer to choose a design which is better for me but harder for them to maintain means I am asking them to put effort in on my behalf.

But I still think it is worth highlighting that the interests of actual users apparently didn't form part of the rationale for the change, because I doubt you *wanted* to ignore the interests of actual users, I think it's more likely that you didn't realise you were doing so.

Comment: Well formulated.

Comment: In my ponion, this type of changes is better to introduce them slowly and consensually ,   there are many changes for something that is used daily

Answer (score 95):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

The questions on the main page are missing the highlight if they have a watched tag on them. Previously this allowed me to quickly scan whether the question comes from one of my favourite tags, now they're all just bland white.

Comment: Thank you for the report. I'll take a look into this

Comment: This is exactly what I came to report as well. I scan for highlighted questions on the main page based on my highlighted tags. Without those highlighted, I'm bouncing from the home page because I don't want to spend time scanning for tags I care about.

Comment: @RossAllen I wonder whether the front page update has measurable effects on the answering behaviour :-)

Comment: @BenKelly This has been fixed quickly! I have to say that I preferred the inconspicuous yellowish background over the bold "Watched" badge though

Comment: @Bergi I'm guessing the highlight made styling sites and dark mode complicated, but I agree there should be a better way to implement this, like a tag, a bounding box, something on the right-hand side, etc.

Comment: I also **much** preferred the background as opposed to a new marker on the left. The former is ingested simultaneously, the latter must be ingested linearly. The former is instant... the latter is not.

Comment: @BenKelly that _"watched"_ badge is hideous. Did that actually get approved by a designer? On dark mode it's absolutely glaring. I'd rather nothing at all in place of that

Comment: Not only is the `watched` tag way too prominent, especially with the dark theme, but when you add the number of answers, votes, views, AND bounty, the wasted space is just unwelcoming. IMO it looks bad, feels bad, reads bad. It's just making the user experience worse in every ways.

Comment: I thought I had accidentally turned on a colour-blind accessibility option. I can see why a subtle background colour is not enough for people with vision issues. But I can no longer scan questions by anything but reading every title. I am flabbergasted at how horrible this is. Was this not user-tested?

Comment: To get a quick fix with custom styles `.s-post-summary--stats-item.is-watched {display:none !important;} .s-post-summary__watched {background-color: var(--yellow-100);}`

Comment: The new "watched" marker has proven itself both garish and *unclear in meaning*. I greatly prefer the old style of subtly shading the background for that question div. However, I think I would like it even better to have *the individual tags which the user is watching* highlighted, perhaps in addition to the cell.

Comment: Assuming that the tag-style box is here to stay - I think it would be nicer if the `watched` tag was grouped with the tag buttons, and had the different styling for emphasis. It makes it harder to see the other metrics on the LHS when it shows up, and it definitely breaks up my flow when skimming the page. Or even just style the tag buttons differently if they're one of my watched tags.

Comment: The watched tag makes the location of the other metadata unpredictable and makes it even harder to quickly glance at votes because you don’t know where to look.  The watched tag is bad, but at a minimum it should go last rather than first.

Comment: @BenKelly Thanks for fixing this! Looks much warmer and familiar again :-)

Comment: I concur, the highlight looks neat and is immediately familiar to those who are used to the old design - thanks!

Comment: Yes! Thank you @BenKelly - much better. Although my custom `rgba(245, 235, 150, 0.2);` was a bit better `:)`

Answer (score 93):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

#### Please restore background highlight on watched questions

The questions with your watched tags used to have a yellow background.

Now they instead have a yellow plaque on the left:

[image: pic]

Which, at least for me, makes it much harder to visually scan for watched questions. Please consider restoring the background highlight we had before (with or without this new plaque).

Comment: Also mentioned by [John Montgomery](/a/375501/289905).

Comment: I would argue that the absence of the backgrounds for questions with watched or ignored tags is the main reason why the new home page leaves distinct feeling that it has been [stripped of important information](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/375081/new-post-summary-designs-on-greatest-hits-now-everywhere-else-eventually/375475?noredirect=1#comment1250822_375475). The "Watched" sticker do not serve the purpose of visually splitting the page into the areas of interest like it was before. It is important to fix that.

Comment: This tag might be useful if you have one or two watched tags; it's pure and utter visual clutter when you have enough watched tags that *Every. Single. Question.* has it.

Comment: Add custom css `.s-post-summary--stats-item.is-watched {display:none !important;} .s-post-summary__watched {background-color: var(--yellow-100);}`

Comment: We have partially reverted the label approach back to using a colored background. We lose info that way, but it gives us an opportunity to revisit how the watched styles are being added to the page.

Comment: @BenKelly Thank you. Negatively received design changes were very rarely reverted before, if at all, so it feels like a step in the right direction. I'm not a fan of the rest of the changes too (sorry), but at least it's a bit better now.

Comment: @BenKelly *"we lose info that way"* - not really. It's one bit of information (watched / not watched), either way the information is there, it's about how to present it. I think you mean you lose explanatory power, because a yellow background doesn't explain itself; but users don't actually need to know this. The goal is to draw attention to content that is more relevant; that's done better by literally highlighting the content, not a bright rectangle which draws attention to *itself*. It matters less whether users know *why* their attention is drawn there, if it's drawn to the wrong place.

Answer (score 78):

[discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) [duplicate](/questions/tagged/duplicate)

This `Watched` label.

1. The color is like it belongs somewhere else, not to this page
2. It takes too much space.
3. There is no explanation of what it is for. I can only guess.

If it's for watching tags, I do not understand why it's so big. I guess people know which tags they are watching without showing them this huge icon.
For usability, tags filters would be a better option.
On my page almost all questions have this tag, I don't think that people who follow tags with big amount of questions need to see this label.
[image]

Comment: Isn’t this basically the same as [this other report](/a/375508/289905)?

Comment: Similar, but my thoughts on this label are different.

Comment: Suggestion: why not highlight the tags themselves instead of adding an additional tag?

Comment: Yea, why aren't the watched tags yellow. I saw this on mobile view this morning and it was horrid. it takes up so much space and is shouty without giving any useful message. I liked the yellow highlight on the entire row better than this useless in your face label. I'm just hiding it for now `.s-post-summary--stats-item.is-watched {display:none !important;}`

Comment: Highlighting just the individual tag would also quickly remind you which tag you're watching for this question

Comment: I assumed it meant I either bookmarked or followed a question. It doesn’t seem clear at all.

Comment: Marking as duplicate of [this resolved post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/375508/395497).

Comment: @BenKelly How about deceze’s idea to highlight the individual tags that are being watched?

Comment: You've made a big improvement after fixing issues related to `Watched` label. How it's color should still be revised. It's too distinctive.

Comment: @BenKelly I agree with vitaliis. The thing that’s supposed to stand out to catch the eye of the reader is still the background colour of the question, not the tag label. The latter only provides an explanation and additional information. Please, (1) get rid of the distracting eye icons, and (2) make the colour of the watched tags less obnoxious; it should have a similar level of saturation as the light blue of non-watched tags.

Answer (score 74):

[discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion)

This change is bad, you need to step back and examine the purpose of the pages and elements you changed here. There are fundamental problems here, the new frontpage is much less usable than the old one.

The new layout for the votes/answers/views is inherently problematic. This is information that must be easily scannable when quickly looking through a list of questions, and not all numbers here are equally important. The old homepage view is really optimized for fast scanning of this table, with the three separate columns for the numbers.

The old questions view has a somewhat similar layout in that the numbers are also vertically stacked, but the huge difference is that the numbers are larger than the text and that the view count is much smaller. This makes an enormous difference, the different shapes provides a lot of help when scanning for these numbers. It's not an ideal design, the score and answers are a bit too similar when there are zero answers as there is no difference in color, but it still works pretty well.

Another huge difference is that in both old designs, I can see the score in my peripheral vision even while reading the title. I suspect this might even be the biggest factor that makes the new design so terrible for me in actual use. I don't need to stop reading the title to read the score. In the new design the score is too small and too similar to the other numbers for this, I need to stop reading the title and focus on the score to read it.

Comment: To add to this answer, when a question has more than 1k views, [the text colour of the view count changes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vbdh8.png). That makes it look like the most important to look at. It's not. It makes it harder to see the vote and answer counts.

Comment: There's a definite trend here - users keep saying "votes are important, views are not important" while the design is based on the opposite assumption. The design is produced by people whose primary incentive is to drive traffic to the site; the users have a primary incentive of sorting content by quality. The disconnect is *completely* to be expected and *not* coincidental.

Comment: @Dan The view count color changed in the old design too. The difficulty in seeing answer count and score now is because the font-size is much smaller (and the same size for value and label). Previously the font-size for the value of score and answer count were like 28px and the label was like 12px.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel When people like me genuinely *can't* find good content with the new UI, then quality will be driven way down and traffic will suffer. It's not even a boycott on principle; I just honestly cannot pick out good questions to answer like I could a few weeks ago. I'm not here to answer "null pointer exception means you have a null pointer in a place you shouldn't" a hundred times a day. Maybe they're hoping the site UI will force me to look at those questions rather than filtering them out, but it really just makes me not come to the site as much (excepting this Meta post, of course)

Answer (score 71):

[discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion)

The new layout allows users on desktops to see fewer questions per screen  on the hompage (due to the two sidebars on the page), which is undesirable.

While the new design may be more performant when switching smoothly to a mobile layout (which I support), it breaks what was a good layout in terms of information density on the desktop.

The lower information density (questions per screen in particular), makes my primary way of interacting with the network a *much worse* experience.

I should point out, that "screen" in this answer refers to what is visible and displayed on on my computer monitor, without having to scroll, as opposed to the word used in the question, which refers to different site *views* as screens.

As you can see from the below screenshots:

- In the new view, without those tags, I can see 10 questions at once
- In the old view I can see 12 questions at once

Compared to the original new view, without those tags, the old view enabled me to see 20% more questions.

Furthermore, not only is it easier to line up who posted, but also compare statistics between questions in the old view than the current view. If I try to scan down the list of recent posters, my eyes have to move *all over the screen* to find the information per question.

New view (original presentation):
[image: new view]

Old view (captured using the waybackmachine):
[image: old view (captured using the way back machine)]

---

#### Post 2022-01-27 update

I've moved the comments around the watched/ignored tags down here, so as not to conflate them with the actual issue that this post of raising, which is far too much whitespace in the design as a whole.

As you can see from the below screenshot:

- In the new view, with the watched and ignored tags, I can see 9 questions

So, compared to the current new view, with the watched & ignored tags, the old view enabled me to see 33% more questions per computer monitor screen.

New View (post- addition of watched & ignored tags):
[image: New view post watched/ignored tags]

Comment: I haven't noticed any significant change to the number of questions per screen. Can you provide a screenshot of the old view for comparison?

Comment: @NicolBolas I've captured an equivalent screenshot using the wayback machine on the same monitor. The only difference is I'm not logged in in the "old" screenshot (obviously), but I took pains to ensure that they are in fact the same size. I see 20% more questions per screen on the old view.

Comment: Ah, I see what it is now: question titles. In the old layout, question titles that fit in one line take up less space, while the new layout is tall enough that they take up the same space whether the title fits in one line or two. The new layout *could* do that too; it just doesn't, for some reason.

Comment: @NicolBolas also the new layout has additional unnecessary padding at the bottom of questions for no particular reason

Comment: 10 questions ? I got 7 to 8 on my home page. [Look at all that wasted space!](https://i.imgur.com/qBUTpfG.png) And I have the zoom level at 90% on StackExchange websites!

Comment: @Seblor I took that screenshot before the *delightful* watched and ignored tags were added to the question list to "fix" the highlighting removal. I get less questions per screen now, but I'm not on my computer until tomorrow to get a new screenshot.

Comment: No worries, it's gonna get worse once they start embedding random articles in the questions list, pushing another 1-2 questions out of view...

Comment: (Note for future readers: the "Watched" and "Ignored" text labels have been removed for now, as noted in Ben's comments below other answers bringing those up.)

Comment: @V2Blast I've edited the answer to allow for the changes since the post was originally written

Comment: @illustro: Thanks... Though now it looks like a new visual marker for watched (and ignored?) questions has been implemented that I quite like. At least for watched questions, I see that watched tags are highlighted with a gold-color fill, and an eye icon next to it. Sorry to make you edit so much :P

Comment: @V2Blast That's not a problem. The new individual tag highlighting for watched and ignored is better certainly, but slightly orthogonal to this (as they no longer detract from the information density points I'm making with the answer). I'll maybe look to update the screenshot with them in it, so it remains relevant, later, but it's not as pressing for the moment I think :)

Answer (score 59):

[discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion)

### Why was such a major change to the interface of the main page of both Stack Overflow and the Stack Exchange network rolled out so quickly and with so little feedback gathered?

There is a *reason* why sites on the internet contemplating sweeping changes to their *primary view* offer users:

- Several months (or years in some cases) to transition between the two and gather feedback
- They do this by using a modal box on the page informing users that a change is going to happen, and would they like to preview it.

This sweeping change was buried in a post, that doesn't have an especially informative title, nor is it clear that it was referring to such a sweeping change (I missed it and I'm active on the SE network daily).

What's more it was only tested by ~170 users, on a page no-one uses (in comparative terms given the userbase of the site) over a very short period of time. I would have expected such a large change to the user experience to need much more data to be gathered from as wide a range of users as possible, with users beng able to compare both the new and old interfaces *side-by-side* (by changing a cookie setting set by the aformentioned model popup method that most sites use).

For a site with the userbase of Stack Overflow, let alone the Stack Exchange network as a whole, this approach to rolling out primary user interface design changes seems ill-conceived and irresponsible at best.

Comment: As an example of a site handling primary UI changes well, I’ve been getting periodic messages to try “new Reddit” for *years* now, and they still let me use old Reddit.

Comment: @ThomasMarkov they compensate for that by new Reddit being outright terrible and broken. And there are plenty of dark patterns there to try and get people to use new Reddit.

Comment: Testing with such a small fraction of the user base and on a page many people don't even know exists, let alone use, introduces massive selection bias into the results - only people who first know that page exits and second find it serves a use case they value will be giving feedback, and such limited feedback is likely to break the use cases other, far more numerous, users find value in.

Comment: Maybe they rolled it out with so little feedback because the intention wasn't to ask for feedback in the first place, and just roll these terrible changes out, regardless of what everybody thinks. But they asked feedback so they can say "we took your feedback" while actually ignoring everything.

Answer (score 50):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)[accessibility](/questions/tagged/accessibility)[status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review)

### For questions without accepted answers, the "[X] answers" text is too hard to read, as the contrast ratio is too low

The text as to how many answers there are on a question is too light and difficult for me to read:

[image: "13 answers"]

A quick check with a contrast ratio checker shows that it's only 2.97:1. It should be at least 4.5:1 to comply with the Level AA standards for normal text, and preferably higher as the text is now smaller than normal.

[This prior answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/375472/377214) only talks about text size and not text colors.

Comment: The darker we make this text, the more difficult it become to distinguish it from black, so we'll need to consider a trade off between the information conveyed from color saturation vs. color contrast. I think we should tend towards higher contrast in this case. I can't guarantee that we'll achieve 4.5:1 here, but I think we can do better.

Comment: @DanCormier Yeah, black would be great. Can you make it pure black #000000? The green hue isn't that useful there.

Comment: @Dharman the color provides information by making different stats quickly differentiable, so I wouldn't want remove the color altogether.

Comment: @DanCormier Why is there less visual contrast between views and score (views is mostly high for old posts; score tells you what the community thinks of a question) than for whether one of the answers was accepted or not (which tells almost nothing about the content except that the original poster decided to accept an answer; they may have accepted a terrible answer, or a question with an excellent answer may have nothing accepted)? There's definitely a mismatch in contrast in *usefulness* of the information and visual contrast.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow @BryanKrause. Are you referring to the relative contrast _between_ distinct stats?

Comment: @DanCormier Yes. There is no contrast between votes and views unless there are lots of views. Outside of SO, those thresholds are only occasionally reached, and never on new questions. I'm responding to "the color provides information by making different stats quickly differentiable" and arguing that no, the color choices made right now do not make different stats quickly differentiable. The color choices right now only emphasizes the number of answers and whether there is an accepted answer. I argue this is the least interesting/important thing to have stand out.

Comment: @DanCormier You have problem with green color ever since this new shade was introduced (about 2years ago). It is too light. There are posts on the Meta asking for more  contrast even then. But it was just ignored, and the problem didn't go away. It is bad color and using it in more places will not make it better.

Comment: Note that WCAG advises that color should not be the sole method for conveying information. Perhaps also add a text shadow or a different border type to backup/supplant the color? I expect that people with certain types of color blindness do not get the information conveyed by that color choice.

Comment: @DanCormier Why not make the text black (or white on dark mode) and leave the green box border to keep your color as a distinguishing feature? That would give you the middle ground between keeping your colors and following accessibility standards. (Votes should ALSO have some distinguishing method, since answers and votes are the two most important stats for a question)

Answer (score 48):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review)

When going over the main pages, I find the amounts of votes, answers and views very important to quickly glean a lot of information about traffic, what questions might need more attention, &c. These amounts used to be very visible because these numbers were rendered in much larger font sizes.
Currently, the words as well as the numbers are even smaller than the text on both of the sidebars:

[image]

This is a strange change in the visual hierarchy and visually less appealing (to me).

Can the font-size of the 'post summary stats', i.e. Answers/Score/Views block (div class "s-post-summary--stats", currently at `12px`) be changed to at least the default font size (of `13px`)?

Answer (score 45):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [mathjax](/questions/tagged/mathjax) [status-planned](/questions/tagged/status-planned)

I'm seeing a strange Mathjax layout problem on Stats.SE:

[image]

This display weirdness is not caused by the user's Mathjax input, as you can see from the post itself: [PDF of $x_1^2+x_2^2-x_3^2-x_4^2$ with $x_i \sim N(\mu_i,1)$](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/561701/pdf-of-x-12x-22-x-32-x-42-with-x-i-sim-n-mu-i-1)

I'm using Chrome 97.0.4692.71 for ARM on MacOS 12.1 (Monterey).

---

It appears that this issue is more frequent on Math.SE. Some examples:

- [Multiline MathJax on title](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34508/multiline-mathjax-on-title)
- [Displays on main question page](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34510/displays-on-main-question-page?noredirect=1&lq=1)

---

**Update 2021-01-28**: SE CMs have added the "status completed" tag, but there are some pages where this bug still persists. Here's an example from the "All actions" tab of a user profile. For this reason, I've removed the "status completed" tag.

[image]

I've created a separate question to report the bug in other pages. [MathJax layout problems persist in "All actions" tab and review queues](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/375745/mathjax-layout-problems-persist-in-all-actions-tab-and-review-queues?noredirect=1#comment1252184_375745)

Comment: WOW, that's an odd one. I'll see if I can't reproduce this in my local environment and get a fix out for it. Thanks for the report!

Comment: @BenKelly FYI, this is very similar, and may be related, to what was reported on Dec. 7, 2021 in the answer [MathJax wraps awkwardly on the activity page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/372605/562482) (with this being marked [tag:status-review]) to [New responsive Activity page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/372049/562482). For what it's worth, I have seen this "strange Mathjax layout problem" many times over the past few months on Math SE.

Comment: Thank you for bringing this to their attention, its been around for some time on maths.se

Comment: This is probably due to a container that "shrink-wraps" the content, so MathJax gets the wrong width for the container, and tries to line break to that incorrect (and too small) width.

Comment: @BenKelly In case it needs saying: Davide is a dev on the Mathjax team. He also left some detail in [this comment](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34510/displays-on-main-question-page#comment160432_34510) on math.meta

Comment: [Here](https://imgur.com/a/pEk2ylE) are some more screen caps of recents posts. It's simply horrible. :/

Comment: Thanks for all the extra info folks, it's a big help. I'm looking to address this one today. Thank you for your patience. There is a _lot_ of feedback coming in and it is a lot of work to assess and address it all.

Comment: Its a tad hard to test this live, but I believe this has now been fixed. Thanks to @DavideCervone for the assist. We've set the display property of the title link to `block` as suggested.

Comment: @BenKelly Thank's, fFor my problem titles this is fixed now.

Comment: @BenKelly While it appears that the bug is fixed on each site's front page (thanks!), the same bug persists in other view. I've edited to document one example in the All Actions tab of the user page, but I've also seen it in the reopen queues and other pages.

Comment: @BenKelly, it looks like adding `width:100%` in addition to `display:block` may be necessary for the uses that appear in flex-box settings, like the "Comments" tab on a user's "Activity" page.

Answer (score 42):

(New answer, following the 2022-01-25 update)

> We're currently gathering together all the discussion and feature-request feedback items to decide how we want to alter the design.

Sure, but in the meantime, please revert the question list to the old design.

Answer (score 40):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

### Date and time shown on homepage is the date the question was originally asked, not the time of the last activity as before

Previously, the date and time shown on the homepage for each question was the time of the last activity (originally being asked, a new answer posted, an edit made, Community user bump, question getting reopened, etc.).

Now, however, the date and time shown is *always* the one when it was originally asked, and not that of the last activity:

[image]

The "Active" sort order still works, though.

Can this please be changed back to what it originally showed?

Comment: Related to: [Restore "Modified" link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/375467)

Comment: @zcoop98 Nope, that's a different issue: that has to do with the "asked", "answered", and "modified" texts that were removed.

Comment: Kind of... The way I see this, if the modified text lines return, then so will what you request; unless I'm misunderstanding something.

Comment: This has been fixed cross-network. The underlying mechanism that triggers this is the same as the one as the bug reported [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/375467/395497) (and linked by @zcoop98)

Comment: As I mentioned on another answer, I want to see both pieces of information if at all possible.

Comment: @BenKelly This is still broken on the Bookmarks page when sorting by activity: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dHaJd.png (the page still shows question's posted date, not its last activity date, and the link still goes to the page unqualified, not to the post on the page w/ most recent activity).

Comment: @BenKelly this is also broken for the user page. In a user (me, for example) page, see questions and order by "activity" --> https://stackoverflow.com/users/1983854/fedorqui?tab=questions&sort=activity What it shows is only the "asked <time>", instead of the last time there was some activity there.

Answer (score 39):

[discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion)[status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review)

#### Update 2 - Watched tags color

After update 2, the watched tags got a new color + icon.

Since the shade of orange is very bright, and not used anywhere else, the tag's instantly draws my attention.

The yellow background is, in my opinion, more than enough. I've pressed the 'watch tag' button myself, no need to remind me about that causing annoying side effects such as:

- Content jumping
- Disturbing bright colours

[image]

Comment: The icon alone, minus the color, would have probably been fine

Comment: Totally agree @KevinB.

Comment: +100 watched tag color is beyond horrible. Icon is more than enough. Actually, even icon is redundant. Reading tags was never the problem. It is something I selected, I don't need additional reminder in that place.

Comment: I've said this elsewhere but: I love the color!

Comment: The bright yellow watched button on 90% of all questions still is an eyesore and needs changing. If you keep the light background, then there's no need to color the tags, just add the eye icon, if you have to. If you want to drop the light background, that's the color intensenty that would be acceptable for the tag button.

Answer (score 38):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-deferred](/questions/tagged/status-deferred)

Not a new bug, but let me mention it here anyway for the record: the question summaries may get truncated at random places, including in the middle of MathJax expressions, resulting in broken markup:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: The new component is using the same body truncation function as the old code, so as you say, this is preexisting. Text truncation tends to be a much harder problem than it appears on the surface, so these types of issues are not uncommon. This issue is not something we plan to address as part of this work.

Comment: @BenKelly So is it [tag:status-deferred], or is it [we'll fix it in six-to-eight weeks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19514/1081494). Also, is there a Meta post already about it somewhere?

Comment: @cocomac From my point of view, this is a legitimate preexisting bug, but our team does not have the bandwidth to address it currently, so it is (for us) status-deferred. I don't know if there is an existing meta post already, but I'd imagine there must be.

Comment: @cocomac I don’t know of a bug report specifically concerning the “Greatest Hits” page (of whose very existence I wasn’t aware until this Meta post), but there are many reports about this truncation issue in other contexts (mainly in search results): https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/197817/, https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/217389/, https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/286456/, https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/291382/, https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/293488/, https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/304383/, https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/360956/.

Answer (score 37):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

It is unnecessary to know if people watch the questions - it should just be shown within the question, not on the homepage of the site's screen.

Why is it not helpful?

- This is unhelpful because most users are interested in the question itself - not whether someone watched it or not.
- It makes each question take up a lot of space, which makes it harder for visitors of the site to access more questions they may have missed.

  (See here:)

  [image: Watched]
- Most of the time, the quality of the question can be discerned based on the vote count -- not if someone watches it, and most people will only click on the questions that interest them anyway.

What purpose does stating the presence of watchers have?

I really have no idea, other than to take up space and add a yellow icon to the regular interface.

Can Stack Exchange please take out the watch icon -- or at least give an option to not see it? (As a whole, I am not a fan of the new update and format, but the watchers haven't been brought up yet (at least I didn't see an answer about them) and feel like they should be recognized for what they are: an icon that symbolizes next to nothing.)

Update 12/2022: Thank you for fixing this. The design looks much cleaner without the coloured backgrounds in my opinion.

Comment: The "watched" badge is for your watched tags, not if somebody is watching / following / bookmarked the question

Comment: I agree that the design is pure horror, especially on dark mode. It seems to be in response to [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/375479)

Comment: @Phil Thank you, I was confused as to what 'watcher' meant. However, it is still a terrible format and a waste of space -- I much prefer the old version.

Comment: Related: [this other report](/a/375512/289905).

Comment: Thanks for this post. It shows exactly my initial problem: I didn't understand that the "watched" icon was about **my watched tags** instead of some other random information. If users misunderstand the icon at first sight it might not be the best UI/UX decision. I really preferred the design where my watched tags questions where highlighted as a whole instead of having some icon.

Comment: The "watched" label is awful. I generally don't mind the new layout, but I think I would prefer it with highlighting the background rather than a badge-style thing. Plus, it often forces a lot of extra whitespace that is unnecessary. I think a small change to replace the badge with highlighting the background would go a long way here.

Comment: We have partially reverted the label approach back to using a colored background. We lose info that way, but it gives us an opportunity to revisit how the watched styles are being added to the page. I agree that the label may be a little confusing due to lack of context, but imo "yellow + watched" is much less confusing than just "yellow". We're revisiting this design to see if we can improve the context even further.

Comment: @BenKelly did you see the suggestion to highlight the actual tag(s) in some way? I thought that was pretty neat

Comment: @BenKelly No info is lost that way, and it seems the consensus on what is more clear runs opposite to your opinion (this may be because existing users are more familiar with the current format). Though stuffing information that I believe is best presented in other ways (here highlighting) into a list of tags is counterproductive UI design, it just takes up more and more vertical space and expands the item too much.

Comment: @Phil: Looks like that's what they went with. I quite like the new design, with the tag filled in with a gold color and an eye icon next to the tag name. :)

Comment: @V2Blast The colors are still an issue. Is it the same color on light and dark mode, because the contrast is too high on dark mode, the watched tag too bright. I think that's kind of true of a lot of the colors, they don't get muted at all for dark mode.

Answer (score 37):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)[status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review)

As of Update 2, watched tags are now by far the most eye catching thing on the homepage feed when in dark mode:

[image: Dark mode watched tags example]

Could we have a less vivid colour for these watched tags when using the dark theme?

Comment: How about simply adding the "eye" icon while keeping the existing colours maybe? See https://i.stack.imgur.com/j2oVX.png

Comment: I'm impartial about whether it needs a custom colour, I'd just like for any colour it does have to not be more eye catching than the title.

Comment: @sp00m that should be an answer. Also maybe consider a few different ways to highlight the eye? A different color, tag text bolded, an outline perhaps?

Comment: There seems to be a handful of colors they don't change between light and dark mode. I'd be all for just having the watched icon and keeping the color, but at the very least they should mute the colors on dark mode.

Comment: This seems to be completed and they went with your design, @sp00m. Congrats! I like it.

Answer (score 35):

[discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion)

I would like to make and argument for presenting the score, view count, and answer count as in the previous layout.

Previously these three numbers are tabulated and treated as primary information side by side with "content data" such as the title and tags. Now they are presented in a nested list, which groups them and subsumes this list to the stuff about the content of the post, creating a two-level structure of information, and thus forcing users to retrieve the information in two steps.

However this is not how these numerical data are used. They have been playing a much more primary role in a user's decision to view a question or not, allowing users to skim the question list as a table and make quick judgments,
which seems to be precisely the use case that [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/375478/939149) remarks upon. Thus I believe the score and answer count have an importance closer to the title than the tags or the most recent activity, and consequently deserve the more prominent position they had in the older design.

Comment: This information should be in a column. We visually scroll our eyes top to bottom and when we have to read whether the number corresponds to a score or views or answers, it makes reading that list much more cumbersome.

Comment: While you are at it, I would also make the post score larger so that it stands out more. You can make the title smaller instead

Comment: Looking at this from the perspective of two kinds of users, i can understand prioritizing the title answers and views over score from a i'm a user looking for answers perspective, but aren't these views mostly used by users looking for questions? Don't most users looking for solutions come from the outside?

Comment: @KevinB Yup. When I look for answers, I never see the question list. I see Google.

Comment: The weird thing is that they are still arranged in columns on mobile, it's just on desktop where they've been moved out of columns.

Answer (score 34):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

## My ignored tags are showing up now

I ignore the [dnd-5e] tag on Role-playing Games Stack Exchange. D&D 5th Edition is probably most of the site now. I want to be able to focus on questions that aren't about it, which the old view let me do. What's the point of ignored tags, otherwise?

Only one of the questions below would be plainly visible, and the rest faded out, in the previous view, the question tagged [pathfinder-1e].

[image: RPG questions feed with full view of ignored tags box]

Comment: Companion bug to [Watched tag highlight is broken](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/375479)

Comment: Thanks for the report! This bug is caused by the same issue as the one @zcoop98 linked. I have a fix going out for this soon.

Comment: Looks like this was now fixed by adding an extremely visible dark "Ignored" tag on questions you've ignored and reduces the contrast difference: https://i.imgur.com/JMivtpJ.jpg Should make it easy to find the things you want to ignore.

Comment: "Fixed" - isn't the point of ignoring a tag to *not see* it?

Comment: @BryanKrause Jesus. That is just unbelievably daft. Not only does ignoring a tag *not* hide them, that extra badge makes the post take up *more* vertical space than it would have if you didn't ignore it!

Comment: If you click on the “edit” button in the “Ignored Tags” sidebar section on the home page, there’s a radio button setting of “Hide questions in your ignored tags” vs. “Gray out questions in your ignored tags”. Isn’t it an option for you to simply hide these posts?

Comment: @SebastianSimon I do see interesting questions in the wastes once in a blue moon, so I would prefer them to exist, but faded out, like before.

Comment: @SebastianSimon While I might want to ignore the tags *most of the time*, occasionally there might be a title I find interesting enough to look into, or a situation where a new user might need some help with their question (new user plus downvoted score can indicate this)

Answer (score 32):

[support](/questions/tagged/support) [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

What's the difference between the "Watched" badge without an eye and the one with an eye?

Also (not shown in screenshots below), "Ignored" without an eye, and with an eye with a line through it.

[image: "Watched" badge]

[image: ":eye: Watched" badge]

Both screenshots were taken in the same page load at the same time, so scrolling down I could see both (indeed, I can see all four mentioned on the same page), which implies they're different.

For reference [here is a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pPRva.jpg) of all four on the page at once (screenshot from phone, set to show desktop version so I could fit them all).

Comment: I noticed that the eye showed up for me on all badges when I added a new tag to the watch list. Did you perhaps do the same thing right before you noticed the eye symbol? I think it's a bug.

Comment: I also just noticed the same thing happens when you remove a tag from the watch list. Also, when you add or remove a new tag from the Ignore list, a different eye symbol shows with a line going through the eye.

Comment: @CaveJohnson haven't touched my watch list in months, I'm fairly specific in the posts I watch. (In fact, I had to go and see how to even modify my watch list on mobile, apparently you have to spend 30s scrolling to the very bottom of the page, TIL)

Comment: looks like anything that causes a re-render on the question list causes the eye to show up. A link popped up saying "X new questions" and after I clicked it, the new question showed on top of the page and then the eye showed up on all the "watched" and "ignored" badges.

Comment: @CaveJohnson Even if I reload the page, I'm still in the same situation, eye on some, not on others. Whatever the cause is it certainly doesn't appear to be consistent. I also have posts with ignored without an eye, and with an eye and line through it (again, both are visible on the page at the same time).

Comment: This appears to be a bug. The eye icon is supposed to be shown everywhere; the SVG icon just fails to load for all of them except the last one of the same type. There’s an empty `<svg class="svg-skeleton-element-during-loading mr4"></svg>` in the labels where the eye icon isn’t shown.

Comment: This was a race condition bug. We have "fixed" this by partially reverting the label approach back to using a colored background. We lose info that way, but it gives us an opportunity to revisit how the watched styles are being added to the page.

Comment: Yes, thanks @BenKelly losing the label is the best option, and no info is lost that way!

Comment: Thanks for the update @BenKelly, could you throw into your discussion the contrast of the background colour? At least in "high contrast" dark mode, the difference (1 in screenshot) is barely perceptible without using the right hand margin (2 in screenshot) (where there isn't the line separators between posts): https://i.stack.imgur.com/B87qP.png

Comment: @BenKelly What info is lost? The bulk of the comments here about the watched tag was it takes up too much space and is ambiguous/unclear information. The highlight provides exactly the same information as far as I can tell, marking a question differently if it contains watched tags, so what info is lost by the changes?

Comment: @BenKelly is it possible to get any other color than Yellow for the dark theme... it's extremely jarring and draws focus from question to yellow thing.

Answer (score 32):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)[status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review)

Yellow tag buttons clutter my view with information with non important screams of attention.

I'd rather prefer the font being bold with the same background as other tags, with a slight color background on the row, to know which tag is affected.

There is already so much information, don't draw my eyes unnecessarily hard towards relevant but unimportant info.

Current styling

[image: current]

Better styling

```css
.tags .post-tag.s-tag__watched {
    font-weight: 600;
    padding-left: 0.5em;
    color: var(--theme-tag-color);
    background-color: var(--theme-tag-background-color);
}
.tags .post-tag.s-tag__watched:before {
    content:revert;
    display:none;
}
```

[image: Better]

```css
.subcommunity-avatar.s-avatar {
   filter: grayscale(1);
}
.subcommunity-google-cloud.s-avatar,
.subcommunity-go.s-avatar {
    filter: invert(1) grayscale(1);
}
body {
    --theme-link-color: #ddd !important;
    --theme-link-color-hover: #ccc !important;
    --theme-link-color-visited: #bbb !important;
}
.s-post-summary--stats-item.is-watched {
    display:none !important;
}
.s-post-summary__watched {
    background-color: var(--black-025);
}
.s-post-summary--stats {
  display: grid !important;
  width: unset !important;
  grid-template-areas:
    "score answers views"
    ". bounty ."
    !important;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr)!important; /* change to 3 for views */
  column-gap: var(--s-post-summary-stats-gap)!important;
  row-gap: var(--s-post-summary-stats-gap)!important;
  align-content: start!important;
  align-items: center!important;
}

.s-post-summary--stats .s-post-summary--stats-item,
.s-post-summary--stats .s-post-summary--stats-item.has-answers {
  white-space: normal!important;
  text-align: center!important;
  margin: 0!important;
  padding: 4px!important;
  width: 60px!important;
  word-spacing: 60px!important;
}

.s-post-summary--stats-item[title$="views"] {
  grid-area: views!important;
}

.s-post-summary--stats-item.has-bounty {
  grid-area: bounty!important;
}

/** Hide unwanted elements **/
.s-post-summary--stats .s-post-summary--stats-item[title$="views"],
.s-post-summary--stats .s-post-summary--stats-item.is-watched,
.s-post-summary--stats .s-post-summary--stats-item.is-ignored,
.s-post-summary--stats .s-post-summary--stats-item.has-accepted-answer .iconCheckmarkSm {
  display: none!important;
}

.tags .post-tag.s-tag__watched {
    font-weight:600;
    padding-left: 0.5em;
    color: var(--theme-tag-color);
    background-color: var(--theme-tag-background-color);
}
.tags .post-tag.s-tag__watched:before {
    content:revert;
    display:none;
}
```

Ideal styling(in my opinion)

[image: ideal styling]

Comment: I prefer the eye-icon-only version from [sp00m](/questions/375081/new-post-summary-designs-on-site-home-pages-and-greatest-hits-now-everywhere-el/375639#comment1251643_375637)’s comment (here’s the [mockup](//i.stack.imgur.com/j2oVX.png) again).

Comment: Styling is easy to change - (would be even easier if SE team decided to end with mixing semantic (`--theme-link-color`) and shade-based (`--blue-600`) variables. I also prefer my screen to be a bit dimmed, here is my current style: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JFbRC.png For me, the biggest pain point is the layout.

Comment: From what I understand [bold reduces legibility](https://ux.stackexchange.com/q/52971) so reading the text inside the tag would actually be made more difficult. Putting away with color and reducing legibility seems like an inferior choice.

Answer (score 31):

[discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion)

As also [said in this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/375482/139866) the format of the author is a mess.

What I see when I read it is:

- The author
- **Reputation!** (in bold)
- and some more small print

[image]

You could (should) format it more like this instead

[image]

Furthermore, I don't see why the reputation is the only bold text there -- it would be just as readable without being bold (and its being bold at the moment is in my opinion [chartjunk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chartjunk)).

Answer (score 31):

[discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion)

#### Not Tested Properly

> Where we are currently using this design
>
> Despite my claims above that this is a “new” design, we’ve been using it in a number of places across the site for quite some time. A (non-inclusive) list of places that are already using the post-summary design:
>
> ```
> Many various places in Teams and Collectives
> Review queue tasks
> New user activity screens, such as bookmarks and questions
> ```

This is the core of the problem. It was tested in the *wrong* places:

- Teams - The people who use Teams are the people who **have to** use Teams. They are not the bulk of the users. I have no statistics, but I am pretty confident of that.
- Collectives - Too new, too small, irrelevant to the vast majority of users.
- Review Queues - Those are a different animal altogether. Most users, *even those who have the reputation to do so*, don't bother with review queues, and if they do then they are concentrating on a specific task (reviewing) and not scanning a list of questions.
- New user activity screens - Again, not relevant to most of the users, most of the time.

The way to test a change like this is to identify a select group of users (e.g., random selection of users above a certain level of reputation and/or activity, ping them via Inbox messages), get voluntary agreement to test for a reasonable amount of time and then get real-world feedback. This is too dramatic a change to test via random any-page-could-be-old-or-new A/B testing, and it is also too dramatic to just drop on everyone without proper testing.

Answer (score 30):

[support](/questions/tagged/support) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

What's the threshold for showing the  symbol before the number of views? From the screenshots, I guess it's 100k – is that a global constant or will it differ per site? On many smaller sites, it's [rather hard](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1541333/questions-with-the-most-views-top-1-per-site) to reach that amount of views.

Comment: Yup, 100k views to reach "supernova" is correct. The thresholds for warm (1k), hot (10k) and supernova (100k) are preexisting and unfortunately hard coded, which means they can't be customized per site.

Comment: I’m not a fan of these symbols.  Older eye’s and small screens lead to me trying to figure out what that symbol says only to zoom in enough to realize it’s not something to be read, and then not clear why it is there at all.

Comment: @PatS Agreed. We'll just have to add another user script to surpress it, I guess.

Comment: User script count is getting really out of hand. Every site "improvement" results in 5 more scripts...

Comment: We wouldn't need all of these userscripts if they just gave us a profile setting to enable or disable all of the new "improvements"

Comment: @BenKelly hardcoded into what exactly? If it's an external library that SE is making use of (something I doubt) then you may have a point, but anything hard coded into SE's own code isn't a valid reason for saying it can't be changed, and honestly it would be a far better improvement than half of the changes in this update to do so. (This update is pretty regressive in terms of differing usage needs and workflows in an attempt to unify what shouldn't be)

Comment: luckily `.iconFireSm{display:none;}` is enough to get rid of it. Works in Stylish.

Answer (score 30):

[discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion)

## Custom Styles

I'm using the [Stylus browser extension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stylus_(browser_extension)) to customise CSS rules for URLs matching `https://(.+\.)?stackoverflow.com/(questions)?(\?tab=.*)?`

Also uploaded to [Userstyles.org](https://userstyles.org/styles/227421/stack-overflow-front-page-grid-stats) and [Stack Apps](https://stackapps.com/q/9296/5862).

[image: light mode]

[image: dark mode]

Features:

- Hides the user avatar
- Hides the view count (personal choice, I never found it useful)
- Hides the checkmark in the accepted answer box. This was throwing out alignment and is not needed due to the box's solid background colour
- Arranges the score and answer count into a grid to look more like it did before this change.
- Reverts watched tags back to how they looked previously

```css
/** Container **/

.s-post-summary {
  padding-left: 8px;
}

/** Stats grid **/

.s-post-summary .s-post-summary--stats {
  display: grid;
  width: unset;
  grid-template-areas:
    "score answers views"
    ". bounty ."
    ;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr); /* change to 3 for views */
  column-gap: var(--s-post-summary-stats-gap);
  row-gap: var(--s-post-summary-stats-gap);
  align-content: start;
  align-items: center;
}

.s-post-summary--stats .s-post-summary--stats-item,
.s-post-summary--stats .s-post-summary--stats-item.has-answers {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 4px;
  width: 60px;
}

/** State grid items **/

.s-post-summary--stats .s-post-summary--stats-item .s-post-summary--stats-item-number {
  font-size: larger;
  margin-right: 0 !important;
}

.s-post-summary--stats .s-post-summary--stats-item:nth-child(1) {
  grid-area: score;
}

.s-post-summary--stats .s-post-summary--stats-item:nth-child(2) {
  grid-area: answers;
}

.s-post-summary--stats .s-post-summary--stats-item:nth-child(3) {
  grid-area: views;
  display: none; /* remove for views */
}

.s-post-summary--stats-item.has-bounty {
  grid-area: bounty;
}

.s-post-summary--stats .s-post-summary--stats-item.s-post-summary--stats-item__emphasized {
  color: var(--fc-light);
}

/** Tags **/

.post-tag.s-tag__watched {
  padding-left: 0.5em;
}

.post-tag.s-tag__watched:before {
  content: none;
}

/** Hide unwanted elements **/
.s-post-summary--stats .s-post-summary--stats-item.has-accepted-answer .iconCheckmarkSm,
.s-post-summary--meta .s-avatar {
  display: none;
}
```

TODO:

- Handle bounty badge (though, to be honest, it doesn't look too bad)
- Align user and timestamp (again, I think this looks OK)

Comment: _“Hide ‘Ignored’ badge, do something with the question itself (hide?)”_ — This is already an option. If you click on the “edit” button in the “Ignored Tags” sidebar section on the home page, there’s a radio button setting of “Hide questions in your ignored tags” vs. “Gray out questions in your ignored tags”.

Comment: @SebastianSimon thanks man, I had them hidden so couldn't see them to create a rule. Turns out the fade-out for ignored question titles is still active in the new design, just had to hide the badge

Comment: Can you move this to a separate question thread so it doesn't get lost under a mountain of other answers?

Comment: @SurpriseDog you mean like a new question on [Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/)? I don't think that will fly since a) it's not a question, and b) it would just be a duplicate of this answer

Comment: Post it to https://stackapps.com/ . And you should probably upload this to github, this will cause the script to be auto-updated for the users when you change it.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat it's already on https://Userstyles.org

Comment: Oh. That works then. But I still suggest posting a link to stackapps.com.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat done ~ https://stackapps.com/questions/9296/userstyles-to-semi-revert-the-new-top-questions-design

Comment: It didn't work for me in dark mode. it was all wonky.

Comment: @Tschallacka don't know what to say, it works for me. The browser needs CSS grid support

Comment: @Phil https://i.imgur.com/S3kym0D.png that is what it looks like. If I hit f5 it renders ok. it seems to only not function when I come from a seperate site. Might have to do with that the user style applies before the css file of stack overflow is loaded. By adding !important behind everything it works properly for me in chrome all the time.

Answer (score 28):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review)

#### Mobile: multiline titles have a *larger* font size.

[image]

Comment: No repro on Firefox Nightly 98.0a1.

Comment: This is probably unrelated to this change; I have a screen shot from a couple of weeks back from my phone because I meant to ask about this apparent bug, before this change rolled out.

Answer (score 27):

[discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign)

The removal of the badge count information next to a user's avatar and reputation was [intentional](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/375081/new-post-summary-designs-on-greatest-hits-now-everywhere-else-eventually?noredirect=1#comment1249707_375081). While that information was not of critical importance by any means, I did find it informative and interesting.

Can you speak to the reasoning behind removing it, since it doesn't seem to be a matter of needing that space for layout purposes (overflowing the width parameter there bumps that whole line down to a new line anyway)?

Comment: The reasoning here is basically "less info > more space > less wrapping".  In the majority of cases (for "normal" usage), the user cards as-is do not wrap to a new line, but adding the badges back would cause them to do so. From testing, the things that cause the line wrapping the most often are 1) many, long tags 2) adding Staff+Mod badges 3) long community wiki text. Using the MSE greatest hits page as our benchmark is a little misleading because all three of those things are very abundant here! Check out the Stack Overflow greatest hits page for more a more typical example.

Comment: A very informal study: MSE greatest hits first page, ~50% wrap. SO greatest hits first page exactly 2 posts wrap. If I get some time later, I'll write up a quick (local) script to add badges to those pages and see how many more wrap.

Comment: yet, you found plenty of space to emphasize collective leaderboard badges, even though gold badges are applicable network-wide.

Comment: "The reasoning here is basically "less info > more space > less wrapping". In the majority of cases (for "normal" usage), the user cards as-is do not wrap to a new line, but adding the badges back would cause them to do so." **So what?**. The question title normally fits on one line. Even if you fit the tags, user info and question date into one line, the entire question *will take up three lines anyway* for answers, votes and views (four, with the current "watched" badges). So there is room for the old-style user card *anyway*, and also room to wrap a long set of tags to two lines.

Answer (score 27):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

Keyboard navigation doesn't work. Pressing <kbd>j</kbd>/<kbd>k</kbd> should move down/up in the list of posts, and Enter should click through to the post. This worked in the old style views, but doesn't work on the redesigned views.

Comment: Seems like `U` is also missing, at least they updated the `?` menu to reflect the missing shortcuts.

Comment: This has now been fixed (for `j/k/u`, which is all of the shortcuts). Something interesting to note is that the existing code explicitly disallows `ENTER` for "clicking through" to the post _on the home page specifically_. This doesn't make much sense to me, but I'm leaving it in place until I get a chance to dig in and find out why. Just mentioning this so it isn't reported as a followup bug.

Comment: @BenKelly Weird. I'm pretty sure I've used j/j/…/enter on the home page and not just on /questions. Maybe j/k used to focus the link to the question and the browser's default Enter binding applied?

Comment: @BenKelly The Enter key is still not working, and now I can't use `/questions` anymore to have a decent view and keyboard navigation.

Comment: @BenKelly Some time later, this is still not working.  Any update on this?

Comment: Sorry for the wait folks - but this(Enter key) should now be fixed. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/416033/cannot-open-a-question-using-the-keyboard-interface-and-the-enter-key/420813#420813

Comment: Thanks for the fix @CollinChoy, congrats on your first contribution to MSE, that many more bugs may be fixed by you in the future!

Answer (score 27):

[discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion)

This is a response specifically to update 2. You mention as a major issue that votes are too hard to see and write that as a response you bumped the size there. From this I get the impression that there is still a huge disconnect between what some of us are considering a critical fault in the new design and what SE is perceiving as our complaint.

The problem isn't just that the score is a point or two too small in font size. I reduced the font size for the numbers in the current /questions view to the size of the new design, and this still was much more readable than the new design. The size isn't the main issue, the layout is. The old layout clearly separates the number from the description and it's very easy to quickly scan the values. The new design puts the number as part of the text with its description.

I don't think you can fix the fundamental issue while keeping the new design of the statistics area.

Answer (score 24):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review)

### Word-breaks in titles make it difficult to read quickly

Some words in the titles of questions on the Home page and Questions page are now broken across two lines with a hyphen. This is what I’m seeing on [Academia SE](https://academia.stackexchange.com/)’s Home page on mobile (in the responsive design):

[image: Screenshot of Home page of Academia SE showing titles broken using hyphens.]

The titles in the above image appear as follows:

- > is there a way to include an updated paper cita-
  > tion link in excel
- > Should professors use the f*** word during lec-
  > tures? [closed]
- > Should I upload unfinished work to arxiv or oth-
  > er similar platforms?
- > Can an academic paper use a fictional world
  > (such as the show WestWorld) as a case study
  > for AI, software engineering, and system imple-
  > mentation?

In my experience, this does not improve readability, and in fact it slows me down. My feeling is that this is happening because the titles are anyway not fully justified (such as in the last question in the above screenshot), so having some words broken like this using hyphens—while others are fully moved to the next line—makes it confusing to follow.

Can this aspect of the UI please be improved?

---

Possibly related report in this same thread by [Rafael Tavares](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/818993/rafael-tavares): [A title with a long word is not wrapped correctly](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/375579/986753).

Comment: Previously reported here: [Hyphenation in titles makes it difficult to read quickly](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/376198/986753).

Comment: @BenKelly I don't think this is a feature request, I think this is a sort of bug (although not the "it's broke" kind, but rather a "we didn't think about that for our style guide" bug). Titles should not use hyphens to handle overflow. Even excessively long words with no reasonable place to break them should just be wrapped without a hyphen in a title.

Comment: Hyphenation is particularly problematic in german.SE: https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1694/automatische-silbentrennung-im-titel-von-fragen In the scope of this site, hyphenation is problematic, as question migth come in English, German language or even mixed languages (titles of English questions with German words or clauses in the title make up the biggest part). Hence, hyphenation of titles in german.SE is broken. Easiest fix would be to not hyphenate the titles at all.

Comment: If you're going to hyphenate, at least do it correctly.  This seems to be fixed now, but in the tex.stackexchange thread earlier today, i saw "\loggin-gall",  Of course, TeX commands shouldn't be hyphenated at all, but that is just execrable!

Comment: @barbarabeeton And I expect the well known “the-rapists” and “wee-knights”… ;-)

Comment: @barbarabeeton Today I say `nan-otubes`

Comment: @egreg Aye the old days, nan-otubes and her dear old mam gran-nan-otubes, all of us workin the tuber fields, but then the famine came. We left them for a new life in the new world--you-tubers, vide-ogames & pati-ofurniture.

Comment: None of those hyphenations should even be there because they do not shorten the number of lines the title would take. There is a fundamental confusion/misunderstanding about why/when hyphenation should happen.

Answer (score 22):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign)

On this page -- https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/?tab=active -- I'm seeing the number of answers above the number of votes.

> [image]

This is not what I expect (given what's quoted in the "question" at the top of this meta-topic), and not what I want.

---

Edit to add -- at least for now it's currently appearing as follows (which I think is better):

[image]

Because, depending on your interest, you can now easily scan either the number of answers (because it's highlighted), or the number of votes (because it's the top-most of the three statistics).

Comment: The order of the statistics on the left side have been tweaked since I took the original screenshots. `answers` has been moved to the top, as you're seeing now.

Comment: @BenKelly But *why*... The number of answers might be relevant if I'm searching for a post looking for an existing answer, but not when browsing recently active questions. I want to find things the community decided were great or terrible (or new!), not questions that are most answered (which on the sites I used mostly means the question is an older/recently-bumped posts, because answers accumulate slowly). I especially don't want my view to be dominated by which questions have an *accepted* answer, which usually says more about the asker (did they bother to come back) than the content.

Comment: @BenKelly By design or not, I think it's a defect. Why did you change the order of statistics? You already visually highlight the number of answers, by giving it a border -- so I think you can afford to position the number of votes above that, for users and moderators who are mostly interested in a score.

Answer (score 22):

[discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion)

I'm not sure if it’s *all* intentional, but

1. The 25/01/2022 update (maybe 24! Time zones!) de-emphasises the score of a post significantly. I am not sure how I feel about that.
2. The left information panel seems inconsistent - based on the state of the question - watch/followed/bountied. I guess there are advantages to seeing this all in one place, but I think there's a certain value to not having different sets of visible things based on the state of the question. It's also really crammed... which makes the fact that SE's webpage has lots of whitespace elsewhere more obvious.

   [image]

   Hardly anyone can see a deleted post, and being greyed out seems.. enough, rather than a bright red deleted sign right on top?

   I'm not a UX person, but my gut feeling feels like having the three basic items (answer count, score and views) feels like a reasonable compromise.
3. It seems more 'valuable' to show whether a post is followed (or bookmarked) to a user. There's less value to showing *some* tag *somewhere* on the question is watched where it is. Maybe highlight the specific tag(s) - which makes more sense with multiple tags.
4. The title is what everyone is interested in - and the space for it gets narrower. You have *all* the horizontal space in the world on a desktop. Just give it whatever you took away for the new style metadata, and make it consistent across all content, and it would be a better use of space. I know SE's allergic to excessively wide content, but at the moment, at *best* you're using a 1/5th of my screen.
5. The front page is a list. It’s jarring to have lists with variable sized items and metadata with no particular standard view. I also am not sure why view counts are on top, over score, since aside from the title, it seems that the score is what someone would *want* to look at.
6. Space is wasted. Consider the below, rather quick and dirty image

   [image]

   By dropping the tick mark (or I guess moving it to the left, and left justifying this - basically all your metadata is lined up (well, it would be if my skills at everything were better). You can use the saved space to have more space for the title, and everything would 'line up' more naturally. You wouldn't have a jagged line of metadata along the left/margins of the home page either.

Comment: Re "de-emphasises the score": [view counts are more important now](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/375180/226398) because we all know that popular == good, right? /facepalm

Comment: @l4mpi not even popular, just older most of the time.

Answer (score 22):

[discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion)

### Please actually make use of space that will be taken up anyway, and line-wrap sensibly

For reference, here is what the old `/questions` interface and new `/` interface look like for me (i.e., the two versions of the interface I get to see live at the moment), when the tags on a question are long enough to cause interference:

[image: old interface, "very long" tags]
[image: old interface, even longer tags]
[image: new interface, "very long" tags]
[image: new interface, even longer tags]

The old way often wastes tons of vertical space. However, the new way still wastes space when the tags are "incredibly long", and we sacrifice user card information for no benefit. The small card jumps down to the next line and looks weird and misaligned; and with the "incredibly long" tags, empty space above cannot be used. Meanwhile, when the tags are shortened and the user card moves back to the same line, **it barely even conserves vertical space**:

[image: short tags in new version]

For me, it goes from 103 pixels between the vertical lines to... 101. Less than a 2% savings. Because of the information on the left-hand side (even without a "watched" badge, which seems like it might get changed anyway), almost all of that vertical space where the user card got displaced before, is still in use.

As I see it, the fundamental problem is that *even though the tags and user card are intended to appear side by side, the tags don't account for this when wrapping*.

My proposal is that the div containing the tags should be designed not to take up the whole width, but instead reserve space for the user card beside them. Along with a rearrangement to prioritize vote numbers (which seems in line with what others are suggesting), we could have something like:

[image: proposal ("very long" tags)]
[image: proposal (even longer tags)]

To me, that looks **much** better already, even before giving any thought to the alignment of the elements in on the left side. This way ensures that vertical space is conserved (supposedly a motivating factor in the new design) even when the tags get longer; keeps things neatly organized regardless; and shows us the original, more informative user card.

---

Addendum: there was some confusion here because I am comparing apples to oranges in that the `/` page has always had a slightly different layout from the `/questions` page. At the risk of veering off topic:

My argument here, essentially, is that the oranges **should be** apples. It is jarring to move from one version of the layout to another as soon as I want to filter (not sort) questions in *any* way; and it is *not at all* obvious to me that a "home page" view distinct from a questions view makes any sense for Stack Exchange websites.

Just to make sure we're on the same page here: *Questions are the reason Stack Exchange exists*. Questions are the content being used for the "home page". The differences, apparently, are a) the layout (*different*, even though the OP spends paragraphs talking about the desire to have everything work the same way); b) the sorting and filtering functionality (*inexplicably and arbitrarily limited*); and c) some default filtering (not very discoverable, can't be interacted with, and can't be leveraged elsewhere).

For a site that tries to cater to an audience of the most sophisticated computer users out there, all of these choices strike me as *absolutely bizarre*. As a site user, I am defaulted to a mostly inferior version of the interface I want to use, get visually shocked every time I switch to the full version (which happens automatically if I do so much as click a tag), and can't properly capitalize on its few advantages.

Comment: How did you make these screenshots?

Comment: The ones for the existing UI are done with heavy use of Firefox's "Inspector" view, from right-click -> Inspect. (Any modern browser should have an equivalent feature.) I just screenshot normally after editing the DOM. My proposal is mocked up in Paint.

Comment: As a small note, your first example is not what the homepage looked like prior to this change. It's what the /questions page looks like. The homepage has never had any text of the question, as far as I'm aware. Here's a screenshot of what it looked like - https://i.stack.imgur.com/d2L1I.png

Comment: The *intent* is for the /questions page to change, eventually, so that it looks like the new homepage but with question text (and a differently filtered list of questions), right? I  *already* didn't like that the votes/answers/views information was laid out differently between / and /questions. Right now, they are *very* different. I assume that later, they will be less different than now. I would like them to be as similar as possible. I would also like the / page to be more functional and personalizable, per my other comment.

Comment: I added to the post to explain this in detail.

Comment: +1. I've actually *almost* gotten used to the change, but the user and history data being on the same line I still find jarring -- I think your mock-up would fix this.

Answer (score 22):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

### Content jumping

The new ['watched' label](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/415540/i-hate-these-new-yellow-watch-labels?cb=1) causes [content jumping](https://css-tricks.com/content-jumping-avoid/), so much that the lower questions are shifted down by 2 rows.

On page load, I start reading questions that get my attention. Half a second later, that questions jumps down by 1/2. Very annoying and unpleasant to the eye.

[image: example image]

[image: example gif]

Comment: This has been fixed by partially reverting the label approach back to using a colored background. We lose info that way, but it gives us an opportunity to revisit how the watched styles are being added to the page.

Comment: Already reported by [CodeCaster](/a/375539/289905).

Answer (score 19):

[discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) [duplicate](/questions/tagged/duplicate)

In the "interesting" view which I use by default, all I see is "watched" questions:
[image]

Which begs the question, what's the point in this badge here? Especially being as it's colour and location gives it a really high prominence.

Comment: The first question on the screenshot isn't watched. That page has always shown a small number of non-watched posts. But the new "watched" tag design is atrocious, and causes a lot of empty space.

Comment: The current “Watched” badge is certainly way too prominent. I see the same as you: virtually every item I have in my Top Questions is “Watched”. And that’s fine, but it’s not necessary for every item to YELL this at me in yellow.

Comment: @interjay I think you found yet another problem with the tag: it can possibly be misattributed to the previous post at a glance. Says a lot about the visual clarity.

Comment: OMG. This is sooooooo bad. I'm looking for interesting questions. All I can see is an avalanche of "Watched Watched Watched Watched Watched Watched Watched Watched Watched Watched Watched Watched Watched Watched Watched Watched Watched Watched Watched Watched" tags.

Comment: Unfortunately based on the post they are trying to unify the layout and content across the multiple different layouts - each layout which before had served a different workflow or use case...

Comment: Marking as duplicate of [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/375508/395497) resolved post.

Answer (score 18):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign)

Capitalization for "C/community wiki" is now inconsistent between list view and within the question:

[image: first "C" is uppercase for list view]

[image: first "c" is lowercase for flair within a question]

The old view was consistent with lowercase-"c" used in both list and within a question. Is this change intended? Is there some reasoning for upper- or lower-case to be preferred here?

For what it's worth, another capitalization inconsistency is still present: "asked" is lowercase in list view and uppercase within the question.

Comment: Nice catch! This is the intended behavior and will roll out everywhere as we get each different area migrated. Behind the scenes, we have a highly reusable PostSummary component that will unify all our different implementations. A sub-component of that is a UserCard component, which will also be used when e.g. showing a question. The goal is a single unified implementation used everywhere. [Obligatory XKCD](https://xkcd.com/927/)

Comment: Oops, forgot the second question - Uppercase `C` is preferred here as it is being treated as a proper noun. "Community wiki" is the post owner / author / whatever in this case. As for the lowercase `asked`, I don't see where that one is uppercase. In that case, it is read like a sentence / sentence fragment depending on layout, so lowercase is the way to go.

Comment: @BenKelly "Asked" is uppercase on the question page itself (like just below the question title and above the voting arrows on *this* page here).

Comment: @Randal'Thor Ahhh, I see it now. Not in the user card, but elsewhere. I hadn't considered that. I'll put this on the list of things to consider when we finally remove the mobile views for the question view.

Answer (score 17):

[discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion)

This is a response to [this statement by SE that they will continue rolling out the new design](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/375808/151385).

> We're going to continue to roll out this design to the screens it already most resembles. This includes /questions, tagged questions and search results. The largest unresolved issue (see above) does not apply to these screens, as they have always had their stats laid out vertically like in the new design.

This is a fundamental misunderstanding of our complaints, the unresolved issues certainly do apply to these pages as well and by continuing to roll out the new design in its current state SE will make those pages hard to use. The old design on those pages was vertical as well, that is true. But it was also still very easily scannable as the important numbers were larger and the labels were below the numbers and produced easily recognizable shapes for the stats area.

I use almost only the /questions pages for looking at a site, all my previous complaints about the new design apply fully to those pages as well. And using the mobile view as you suggested is not a real solution either, that one is also inferior to the old design.

You're trying to make this widget more generic than it can be. You want to be able to display any new kind of content you can come up with. But not all information is equal here, and by putting everything into a uniform list you're buying that flexibility for a high price, making the new design worse overall.

The problem with the very limited amount of horizontal space in a vertical list of this kind is pretty much unavoidable. You can't just keeping putting more stuff in there without drawbacks. So you should also carefully consider which new features or concepts really need to be visible there or not. Or also old ones, e.g. whether it is really that important to show the number of views there.

Answer (score 16):

[discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) [status-deferred](/questions/tagged/status-deferred)

I mainly visit Stack Overflow on a mobile device and my main entrypoints are the "newest tag questions" of various tags. I then read through the question titles, filter out the ones I do not know anything about and open the rest in a separate tab. In the old mobile view I can see 5 questions at a time, whereas in the current responsive tag view I can only see 2 at a time. In the responsive "home" I can see 4 questions and on the new "greatest hits" I see 3. So rolling the new post summary to the tag view would *improve* the information density for me, whereas rolling it out to home would decrease it. Also it's still worse than the good old mobile UI.

Now the main difference between the new UI and the current responsive "home" seems to be the question's body excerpt, which I won't read anyway as either the title catches my attention and I visit the question or I do not. Would it be possible to omit it somehow from the new tags view in favor of having more questions in view?

Comment: It is definitely possible to remove the post excerpt - we'll be doing this on views that previously already did so (such as the home page). In the spirit of maintaining data compatibility, we are not currently planning on removing excerpts from screens that currently have them (and vice versa). This is always subject to change, but that's the current plan.

Comment: In regards to data density, I just did an informal test locally. All tests were done on MSE, in the Chrome web tools, with the device viewport set to iPhone SE, with the view scrolled so the top of the first question is at the top of the page. On the old mobile views, I get ~6 posts on home and `/questions/tagged/foo`. On the responsive versions I get 4.5 and 2.75 posts respectively. On greatest hits I get 3 posts with excerpt and 4 posts without. The biggest vertical space takers are (in order) - Post excerpt, wrapping titles, wrapping badges, stats moved to the top (vs left), user info.

Comment: @BenKelly The UI already adapts to narrower widths -- when the viewport is 980px it decides to put the statistics above instead of to the left of the answer. You could consider using a similar technique: to hide the post excerpt only on a small (i.e. mobile-like) viewport where the density is at a premium.

Answer (score 16):

[discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion)

The justification for these changes **do not make any improvements for the user**.

> 1. We generally assume 3 items of metadata: score, answers, and views. If we want to add new entries for e.g. bookmarks or revisions, it can
>    be difficult to create a consistent layout in a list of questions.

Is it necessary to provide this additional information, if so why?

> 2. Inconsistencies in implementation have led to several different layouts across the site. When gathering requirements for a unified
>    post summary component, we found at least *5 (five!) different
>    layouts*.

Why not pick one of the five, or at least incorporate the best features of each?

> 3. Scaling the design is tricky, both in window size and adding features and functionality. We need to support all sorts of metadata
>    on all sorts of devices.

Again, how much meta information is necessary for the users to make quick decisions and navigate the site easily?

> 4. Our post summaries were only designed to support questions (and answers, kinda). We need to be able to display various content types
>    in single lists. For example, in a list of notifications, we may want
>    to present an article next to a question.
> 5. We have no unified place to put an action menu.

I don't understand either of these justifications.

Comment: The first sentence is partly incomprehensible. E.g, is a word missing? Can you [fix](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/375564/edit) it? And what do you mean by it? Can you elaborate?

Comment: I'm sorry I can't see what you mean. If I had to clarify the statement I would say that none of the reasons given under 'Why we’re making these changes' specifically address an issue that effect the _user experience_. I emphasise user experience because in the end, the changes that have been made have had an overlay negative effect on how real people use the site, that should always be the primary motivation.

Answer (score 15):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-planned](/questions/tagged/status-planned)

The display of the author information for community wiki posts is not always on one line. Browser: Firefox 95.0.1 on Ubuntu, 100% zoom. For the first CW question the author line does not go below the tags (which is different from the screenshot in the announcement, where it does go below the tags). For some CW posts the line does go under the tags however.

For the posts with a normal author it seems to work fine.

[image]

I tested also in Chrome and there the bug is not reproduced.

Another one where there is clearly enough space next to the tags where Firefox wraps the line (and in Chrome it is a single line next to the tags):

[image]

Comment: Yup, that one is a known issue. The markup for that link(s) is generated elsewhere and reused, so we opted for a suboptimal layout for now. This is next on our list of items to fix. The markup is the same across browsers, but FF isn't buying into our uh... "inventive" css we're using to collapse the rendered `<br />` tag.

Comment: @BenKelly It should break before the 'user percentage' so that it's consistent throughout. Currently: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YkNHK.png - Should be: Community wiki 16 revs, 7 users<br />37%
Sonic the Anonymous Hedgehog --- So the 37 is under the 16.

Comment: @Rob We were trying to go the other way with it - not breaking at all, but FF was having none of our nonsense. We're planning on changing the (fairly confusing) text here to something much easier to read anyways, so this is just a stopgap fix/bug.

Answer (score 15):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [localization](/questions/tagged/localization) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

There is [no string to translate](https://ru.traducir.win/filters?sourceRegex=Watched) for "Watched" label:

> [image: Watched]

Comment: This really proves that the _"feature"_ was rushed out in response to [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/375479)

Comment: @Phil Not specifically. Staff forgetting to make translation strings available has been a recurring problem for years.

Answer (score 15):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [duplicate](/questions/tagged/duplicate)

The `watched` badge gets added after page load, increasing prior non-badged posts' height.

I understand the "watched" functionality is client-side, because of performance reasons.

However, when it gets added like half a second after page load, a pixel or two get added to the post line's height on the homepage if the post had no badges (or answers) on page load. This is distracting.

The badge also jumps into view while you're reading, which is also distracting. The yellow background was more subtle in its appearing.

Comment: Marking as duplicate of [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/375556/395497) resolved post.

Answer (score 15):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)[status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review)

#### Watching/Ignoring overrides the red coloring of moderator-only tags.

Moderator-only tags are usually red, but watching and ignoring them overrides this:

[image]

[image]

I think instead it should look something like this when you have a moderator tag watched or ignored, preserving the red color but adding the appropriate eye symbol:

[image]

(Image created courtesy of [this bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/375644/674198).)

Comment: It's worth mentioning that it also overrides the "required-tag" (bug, feature-request etc.) style.

Comment: Maybe for ignoring it is not so bad, because if you ignore the tag then you may also not be interested in whether it is a moderator-only tag - if it was red then you could complain "the red color attracts attention to ignored questions" similar to the [problem with the ignored label](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/375506/). But for watched tags it should indeed be red.

Comment: @Marijn Looks like that's the design they went with. Watched stays red, ignored greys out.

Comment: @BenKelly is this [status-complete] now? Seems fixed.

Answer (score 14):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

Currently of the 4 meta data fields in the post summary only views has a tooltip.

[image: screenshot of tooltips in post summary]

Comment: Some of our many post summary designs do not have consistent tooltips, including the design this unified component based on (the most frequently used version, which is currently still live on `/questions`). The QuestionMini view that preexisted had some low quality tooltips that exactly matched the text. I've readded (not yet live) these tooltips to the component used here.

Answer (score 14):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)[status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review)

**Align tags and author to bottom of panel**

I was trying to work out why the homepage looks "empty". As [pointed out in response to another answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/375475/237313), the homepage has never had text excerpts, but it felt less obvious somehow.

I think the problem is that without a text summary, most of the content is floated at the *top* of the panel, with whitespace *below* it caused by the stack of labels on the left.

Compare these two questions:

[image: annotated screenshot of current homepage showing the whitespace in question]

In the first, the three labels on the left extend below the two lines needed for the title and tags, so almost an entire line of whitespace is left at the bottom. In the second, the long title is enough to bump the tags and author to *below* the stack of labels on the left, so the whitespace is just a thin strip on the left, and the gap at the end of the title's second line.

If the tags and author were aligned to the *bottom* of the panel, rather than to the top below the title, the first example would look more like this:

[image: quick mockup of alternative spacing]

Since the whitespace is now *inside* the panel, it looks more deliberate, and less like something's missing.

Answer (score 14):

[discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion)[duplicate](/questions/tagged/duplicate)

With the new main page design, I'm finding watched tag badges to be quite overwhelming in the design. At least at GraphicDesign.se.

They essentially "scream" at the viewer in my opinion.

[image: screenshot of vanilla question list]

**Is there a local setting I can adjust to reduce their prominence?**

---

I have used a custom style:

```css
.post-tag.flex--item.mt0.s-tag__watched {
    background-color: var(--yellow-300);
}
```

Which, to me, appears much more inviting:

[image: screenshot of custom style question list]

Or better still... yellow-500 border and color.

[image]

But, to be honest, I'd rather *not* have to employ custom styling.

Comment: As a heavy daily user I feel they were fine before with just the question highlighted and all tags having same default color. The rainbow displays are hard to visually scan

Comment: I sort of agree @charlietfl The background is sufficient. But I imagine there is some *reasoning* as to why the tags need visual variation.. possibly when there's no background on mobile?? But, well, there's the icon there too. So??

Comment: My guess is the only reason is they are experimenting - with no user tests at all. They originally forgot to do any watched tag highlighting at all and now they've gone overboard

Comment: @charlietfl it's also pretty obvious nobody tests the designs / colours in dark mode

Comment: The more I look at this new layout... the more I dislike it and miss the old one.

Answer (score 14):

In response to update 3:

> Responsiveness - This was the primary catalyst for the change. The old layout was unusable on mobile and could not be feasibly scaled to work.

I miss being able to see the vote, answer, and view counts aligned as separate columns on the homepage so I'd like to emphasize why I believe the approach stated above is incorrect.

I understand that this is a difficult problem: it's either hard or impossible to make a single interface that scales well for the extremely different screen dimensions here. It's inevitable that you will need to make some sacrifices.

**I believe sacrifices should be made by prioritizing.** A vast majority of people who use all SE sites by browsing through a list of questions are using desktops/laptops. People contributing answers (particularly for programming and STEM sites which include math and code, which cannot be easily typed on a mobile) are almost certainly looking for questions to respond to while on computers. The number of mobile users looking at the question list and trying to parse information is small. It is their cosmetic experience that should be compromised on.

The present approach sounds like "If mobile viewers cannot experience the column-based layout, then nobody can." I'd prefer "A column-based layout for question lists is extremely important to the people who use that screen the most. Unfortunately, this means that mobile users won't have the best experience they can be given when using that screen, but that's just how it goes." It's utilitarianism.

Answer (score 13):

[discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion)[watched-tags](/questions/tagged/watched-tags)

Update 2022-01-29: It looks that the gold/yellow color of the watched tags was removed: thank you very much.

---

As I mentioned in [a comment to the question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/289691/rub%c3%a9n), I really dislike how the watched tags looks now (update 2).

Now I'm wondering, have you considered the use cases ? ...

- where the user is following a popular tag so the homepage frequently has several questions with watched tags
- where the popular tags have a high activity (above the 50% of the questions have one)
- where multiple tags are watched and is common having questions with two or more of these tags? i.e. google-sheets and google-apps-script in Web Apps and SO.

Several of the recent answers show screenshots having multiple questions with watched tags:

- https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/375638/289691
- https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/375639/289691
- https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/375641/289691

Also, have you considered the users that visits the homepage multiple times every day?

Comment: Yes, I know, I spend too much time on Stack Exchange but that used to be nice, better than ... you name it.

Comment: I think the question highlighting AND tag highlighting is a bit much -- should just be one. The tag highlighting makes more sense to me. Question highlighting creates problems for dark mode and custom site designs down the road.

Comment: I don't want to contradict you Ruben but personally I think the color on the watched tags looks great, speaking for myself I like it. I do give my watched tags lots of attention and now it's easier to distinguish if it's the question's primary tag I'm watching (which can be broad) or a rarely used minor tag. It works a lot better this way drawing my attention from the listing to questions that are about rare topics.

Comment: @bad_coder Opinions are welcome (that is the purpose of [tag:discussion], don't you think?). By the way, my first contact to the "update 2" tag highlighting was on a moment that the Web Apps homepage had a lot of questions having watched tags... if the homepage had only one, perhaps I didn't dislike it so much (at least not no soon). I agree that that this tag highlighting could be perceived differently on another page, including the homepage of other site, where the watched tags appears rarely.

Comment: My take on it: on any page, you want to read what actually matters: _content_. But with every single item, you’re (potentially) greeted with a barrage of brightly colored labels which don’t matter to the user all that much _in this list_. On an _individual list item basis_, these labels may make sense as they tell a user _which knows nothing about Stack Exchange_, what a given list item _is_ or _has_: is closed, contains watched tags, has a bounty, what have you. This only makes sense _in isolation_, not in the _actual use case_. This is what needs to be (re-)considered in the design process.

Comment: The colored tags force you to read the tags on every question due to their brightness and high contrast, especially on dark mode. When you are greeted with a page that has a multitude of yellow, attention-grabbing rectangles on almost every line, it disrupts your focus on reading the titles. Maybe make it optional?

Comment: "It looks that the gold/yellow color of the watched tags was removed" - I'm pretty sure they will apply this change again soon, since they keep doing changes without ever updating anyone or asking anyone. So better wait with the thanks.

Answer (score 12):

[discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review)

It might be worth mentioning in the context that above a certain resolution the title *"1,000 questions"* and the message below it are moved from the bottom of the page to the sidebar.

When that happens it squeezes the post summaries into narrowness leaving only an empty gutter below the message. I wonder if there could be a better solution for this and what it would be?

**A larger resolution:**

[image: screenshot greatest hits larger]

**A smaller resolution:**

[image: screenshot greatest hits smaller]

Comment: Maybe put the stuff that's already in the right sidebar for other pages (i.e. filters, tag watching widgets, hot network questions)?

Comment: When transitioning the post list to the new design, I did a few light touch changes to this page to give it a similar layout to the other pages under `/questions` (it already kinda did, but was broken). @CaveJohnson is on the right track, in that the other pages have more "stuff", so the gap isn't as apparent. I'll see how big a lift it is to add the rest of the sidebar to this page as well, but no promises if that would be a whole project in itself.

Answer (score 12):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)

Add classes to the individual elements so custom user styling can be used with CSS without the need for JavaScript and string parsing for contents.

Current

```html
<div class="s-post-summary--stats js-post-summary-stats">
   <div class="s-post-summary--stats-item js-added-stat-entry is-watched"> 
      <svg class="svg-skeleton-element-during-loading mr4"> 
      </svg>
      Watched
   </div>
   <div class="s-post-summary--stats-item has-answers">
       1 answer
   </div>
   <div class="s-post-summary--stats-item">
       0 votes
   </div>
   <div class="s-post-summary--stats-item " title="15 views">
      15 views        
   </div>        
</div>
```

Proposed

```html
<div class="s-post-summary--stats js-post-summary-stats">
   <div class="s-post-summary--stats-item watch-stat js-added-stat-entry is-watched"> 
      <svg class="svg-skeleton-element-during-loading mr4"> 
      </svg>
      Watched
   </div>
   <div class="s-post-summary--stats-item answers-stat has-answers">
       1 answer
   </div>
   <div class="s-post-summary--stats-item votes-stat">
       0 votes
   </div>
   <div class="s-post-summary--stats-item views-stat" title="15 views">
      15 views        
   </div>        
</div>
```

Comment: OMG yes please. This is the one thing preventing my userstyle from re-arranging the stats column order

Answer (score 11):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)[status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review)

#### Unexpected behavior when removing tags from watched and ignored.

I was able to create this interesting situation:

[image]

1. Add a tag to your watch list.
2. Add that tag directly to your ignore list
3. Remove that tag from your ignore list.

The result will be a tag with the watched color, the ignored eye symbol, and no tags on your watched and ignored list.

Alternatively, just removing a tag from your watch list removes the background shading of the question card, but the tag remains yellow:

[image]

Similarly, adding and removing a tag from ignore leaves the eye symbol in the tag:

[image]

Refreshing the page corrects the coloring to your settings.

(I've reproduced this bug on Win10 Chrome and iOS Safari.)

Comment: Related: [Questions with ignored tags are hidden even if the "gray out" option is selected](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/415642/4642212).

Answer (score 10):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)

Please take a look at this screenshot here from the Home page, bountied tab, and compare it with the bountied tab on the Questions page.

**Home page:**

[image]

**Questions page**

[image]

I made sure to make both screenshots exactly 700px high as for a fair comparison.
The questions page is certainly far more information dense (hence preferable) then the Home page.

This basically has the following causes (which should be addressed IMHO):

1. **Superfluous labels in the Home page**

   There really is no need for the watched and ignored labels, the current implementation those have is perfectly fine as they are on the Questions page. I suggest you remove the labels (which frees up ton's of vertical space, as was already asked for in the answer by [John Montgomery](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/375501/361484). Also the watched label is called superfluous in the answer by [vitaliis](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/375512/361484).
2. **The bounty label**

   I understand the reasoning behind moving the bounty label to the left, and to group all "meta"data together. The implementation however is just done poorly.
   The post summary stats container has a width of 96px, and the bounty label at a value of +500 (is the plus sign really needed btw?), which is the value with the greatest width has a width of 40.1166 px. (Removing the + sign reduces the width to 32.55 px) This makes this badge small enough to be displayed on the same row as the views counter in most cases, saving tons of vertical space.

As it currently stands the amount of extra information I get from viewing the questions tab is just astonishingly. I get the first 2 rows of each question practically for free. You guys (and girls) really should do a better job at this. And concluding that the original design was good enough can also be a conclusion!

p.s. Don't even get me started on the mobile implementation of this, where meta data is crammed up in between titles, that just horribly in itself.

Answer (score 10):

[discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion)

##### User avatars/profile pictures on question list add to visual noise

I couldn't find anyone else mentioning this - on such a cluttered view as the home-page it's really important to avoid making unimportant information very high contrast or colourful, where it fights for attention with what you're trying to read. In particular, I don't think there's much value in user profile pictures appearing *in the top questions view, where they didn't previously appear* and it definitely adds a piece of shiny clutter to the view, especially as the location of the profile picture bounces around so much from line to line. I find this combines with the "watched" tags and the higher contrast in the modified date to make the page feel a fair bit more grating than before.

I don't intend this to take a stance one way or another about other places that the new view is shown. Maybe in some of them the identity of the author is much more salient. This is about its use to show "top questions" in the home page.

Here are old and new examples from the "Top Questions: Interesting" view.

[image: Single item from old "Top Questions" view. On the left are columns for votes, answer and view counts. In the bottom right in grey text is "modified 19 mins ago", a username, then a reputation score.]

[image: Three programming questions from the new "top questions" view. All of the questions are taller with more whitespace. Every question has a bright yellow "watched" badge now. There's just one column on the left, containing the watched badges, answer, vote and view counts, stacked for each question. Question author names now have a small avatar next to them. Their reputation and the time the question was asked is in brighter text.]

Comment: User profile pictures were there before (as 32x32 icons, just like on the actual question pages), and personally I quite like them. But at the new 16x16 size, they're pointless. You have to squint to make them out, and they don't accomplish the visual goal of making the user card seem like a *card* - a coherent entity that's part of the layout. Now it's just, like, a line of information that happens to have a small blob of pixels in front of it for some inscrutable reason.

Comment: Some of the places this view is used didn't have user pictures before. Specifically the home / recent questions view. I'll clarify in the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the visual. Personally I would like for the view on `/` to resemble the view on `/questions` as much as possible. I'm not even sold that they should be separate things, aside from some default filter settings. Stack Exchange websites **are** the questions. Everything else is ancillary.

Comment: I hadn't honestly realised they were different before now. The current view with the big icons on the questions pages benefits from having them in the same horizontal position all down the column. It feels less distracting than this. Definitely agreed that that `/` and `/questions` are doing the same kind of thing and deserve one good layout between them.

Comment: "The current view with the big icons on the questions pages benefits from having them in the same horizontal position all down the column." Yes; that's another reason I like the old user card, and advocated for it in my answer.

Answer (score 10):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)

There are aspects of this change that I like, but being unable to quickly see the score and the massive amount of extra space this design puts in is problematic.

What I'd suggest is:

1. Get rid of the threshold for vertical layout vs horizontal and only use horizontal
2. Re-implement the Score box on the left, removing score and views from the top (this should still be collapsible to the top left, giving the full width title space for mobile)
3. Add views somewhere else, such as bottom right, or bottom left, it doesn't belong in the top. It isn't as important as score and therefore doesn't need the big callout.
4. Add "Closed" as an additional status box that is shown along the top, similar to Watched/Answered etc. Even better, have it include the short close reason (Duplicate, Off Topic, Unclear, Not Focused) rather than saying "Closed" so that you can quickly see the close reason when looking at a list of closed questions.

The idea would be to make use of the available space while still accomplishing your goals of having an expandable stat list and a scalable design, *and* preserving the information that we users need to use the UI effectively.

Comment: Thank you for putting some of my thoughts into a *"What I'd suggest is:"*

Comment: _“Add ‘Closed’ as an additional status box”_ — Apparently this is [already planned](//stackoverflow.design/product/components/post-summary/#states), unless I misunderstood your suggestion.

Comment: That's half of it, but it's not implemented. That also seems quite... bright, to the point of potentially drawing too much attention.

Answer (score 10):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)[status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review)

**Highlight/shade whole deleted item rather than use the delete label in the stats column**

[image]

Update 2 from 2022-01-27 removed the "Watched" label but not the "Deleted" one.

What was wrong with the old system of shading the item background in red?

---

**This also needs implementation in some of the profile activity lists!** You removed that highlighting when the new design was implemented there as well

Comment: tbh, as someone who sees a lot of deleted posts, this is the implimentation I prefer. Especially since *most* users won't see it

Comment: @JourneymanGeek So you would prefer to lose the extra height needed for the label? Not ideal in my mind. The previous red highlighting approach allows maintaining same height. Not sure what rules are in the profile activity lists when you follow or bookmark items if you need high rep or not to see the deleted ones there

Comment: I'd rather have the heights of each item consistant, and not change with different states

Answer (score 9):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)[status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review)

A title with a long word is not wrapped correctly ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70854453/error-spawn-c-users-administrator-appdata-local-programs-myprogram-resources)):

[image: A question with a long title that is cutted off; it's also not possible to read the text "asked X mins ago".]

When searching for it, it looks like this (ellipsis are added):

[image: A question with a long title but with ellipsis.]

Comment: Another report, perhaps related: [Word-breaks in titles make it difficult to read quickly](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/376201/986753).

Answer (score 9):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review)

Tag(s) and answer(s) misalignment *really* bothers me...

[image]

Zoomed for clarity...

[image]

It may not seem like much, but it is constantly noticed here. It's unsettling and lacks balance.

To be frank, the more I see the new layout, the less I like it.

Answer (score 8):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)[live-refresh](/questions/tagged/live-refresh)[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

### [This answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/375467/377214) was not implemented for the live refresh feature

That answer, which was about linking to the last activity, showing the last active user and timestamp, and showing the correct action was not implemented for questions loaded in when clicking "[x] question(s) with new activity". Such questions loaded in when clicking that still show the prior buggy view. Only after a page refresh is the fixed behavior visible.

Can that please be fixed for the live refresh?

Comment: I think I know where the issue lies with this one. I'll take a look and see if we can't get a quick fix in.

Answer (score 8):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)

Can we please get a setting that lets us choose between "Top Questions" and "All Questions" as the default view when we navigate to root?  That for me at least would solve all of the problems.

If that's not feasible, at least a one-click option from root to show the questions view - not hidden behind a menu.

To be clear, it would help even if the /questions page is converted to a version of the new view - as long as it still has post summaries, anyway.

Comment: They're planning to use this design in /questions as well, so trying to hide there won't help you for long.

Comment: @interjay Understood (and that's unfortunate), but as long as they keep the post summaries it will be more palatable at least.  I've always preferred that layout- this just pushes me more that direction...

Comment: There were never post summaries on the homepage. :( The current design is just mimicking the old design that didn't have them.

Comment: @Catija Yes, understood, not re-litigating that :) This would allow us to choose a different view (vis-a-vis auto-loading the Questions page) which *does* have post summaries (that's not going away, right?).

Comment: Couldn't we just have a widget on the page to toggle visibility of post summaries? Ideally remembering the user's previous setting?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Apparently, this existed at some point: [Why does clicking twice on Show/Hide excerpts refreshes "Hot Network Questions" on the right side panel](/q/261319/289905).

Answer (score 8):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) [duplicate](/questions/tagged/duplicate)

I can understand the general motivation for all these changes. In fact I might even agree that they are the right decisions.

That being said, the amount of added white-space seems egregious. For example:

[image]

Even a simple change like this (quickly mocked up with dev tools in my browser) would bring a welcome improvement:

[image]

- Decreased bottom margin of each of the 3 rows of information on the left hand side
- Decreased column width of information section on the left hand side
- Increase bottom padding of post title to align the tags with the bottom of "views"
- Increased post title font size slightly to increase readability
- Flipped background of "answer" box to highlight this more

Comment: the background of the "answer" line is meaningful. No background means n answers exist, but none are accepted. This distinction is important because some people only want to see one or the other, depending on their needs.

Comment: Marking as duplicate of [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/375501/395497) very similar post

Comment: @KevinB I think the new design has a checkmark for those questions which have an accepted answer now.

Answer (score 8):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

**Latest Activity Link in private SO instances are missing the private part**
.. and are therfore pointing to a completely different question on public SO

[image: Private SO Question]

(1) Links to [https://stackoverflow.com/c/{private-so}/questions/1234](https://stackoverflow.com/c/%7Bprivate-so%7D/questions/1234)
(2) Links to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1234/question-title?lastactivity

Comment: Thank you for the report! This has been fixed. There were a number of preexisting bugs in these "mixed content" views. I believe that this bug was actually preexisting, but unnoticed.

Answer (score 8):

Even after the third update, the site doesn't looks as good as it used to look.

You have said this: "*increased size of stats as a whole*".

Take a look at this:

[image]

The bounty label is huge compared to the other important stats like votes.

Better increase the stats size more and decrease the size of the bounty label.

Comment: Also, the bounty is in blue, it already captures your attention.

Answer (score 8):

[discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion)

When the community members gave feedback about [Changes to answer sorting menu: moving menu, "Newest" sort option, renaming sort options](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/375749), the company went back to the drawing board and came up with this [Revisiting changes to answer sorting menu: better use of space, moving menu into a dropdown, ascending/descending sort options, clearer descriptions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/376062). That's nice, right?

Why cannot something similar be done for the post summary design too?

Please do not be inconsiderate. I would like to [quote](https://meta.askubuntu.com/a/18387) [Zanna](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/322419/zanna):

> The reasons people have for maintaining and contributing to a commons are quite simple; they derive some important benefit from it, and realise that without the participation of people like them, it will not exist. I believe this is a strong motivation, both emotional and rational. Not everyone will feel the need or have the skills/time/means to contribute, but if enough do, the commons will survive and thrive

I would like to emphasise about ***time***. Our time is valuable and without us spending time with the communities, the communities will perish. Feature changes like this anger users, make them want to use the site less and less as they have to spend more *time* to get used to the changes (which they don't like) being forced upon them.

Please value our time. Please value the communities.

Answer (score 7):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)

If we can't revert, is there a way to make this change optional much like the color palette and other layout settings?

I'm not a fond of this change to be honest, but I can understand if someone likes it, otherwise I'm guessing you wouldn't have built it in the first place.

Comment: I doubt it, because the "Why we’re making these changes" section of the OP suggests they're doing it partly to simplify the current implementation, and it wouldn't be simpler if they made the new implementation optional and kept the old implementation also.

Comment: This is a common request on design changes everywhere, and the answer is always that _supporting multiple versions is a lot more difficult than it sounds_. Having a _temporary_ switch, while you work out the kinks, is pretty easy; it's probably already there for the roll-out. Supporting it _permanently_ means that _every time a new feature or change is built_, you have to design it for both views, implement it for both views, test it for both views, fix bugs on both views... Then you want to re-design again, and are pressured to support _three_ views... It's very rarely a practical solution.

Comment: @IMSoP generally I would have agreed with you. It sure is much more difficult, but considering the fact there are more users against this change than those favoring it, I believe it is a special consideration worth exploring if SE wishes this change to stay.

Comment: @Bharel People are always far more vocal at expressing what they don't like than what they do like, or are indifferent to. They (or should I say, we) are also notoriously averse to change. This kind of feedback happens basically every time any website or software changes its design. Realistically, there are two paths: withdrawing the design (meaning, wasted effort, and failure to meet original project goals), or rolling out, hopefully after acting on any _constructive_ feedback which can be filtered from the background noise of general dissatisfaction.

Comment: @IMSoP I thought you'd say that. It's a little more philosophical, but what percentage of the userbase needs to disagree with a change before we realize it's not a background noise but the actual customers being dissatisfied? I fully respect the effort the developers have put into this proposal, but for me at least it makes it much harder to contribute to the site, and there are plenty more like me.
You're completely right, if this change was positive I wouldn't have posted anything, but we should compare it to the history of design change posts at meta and see the user's downvote percentage.

Comment: @IMSoP besides, a proper beta for such a significant change is warranted. I'd gladly join one and share feedback, but then turn off the feature and continue contributing like I love. I'm all ups for experiments and betas, and the extra few days work of hosting 2 versions with a temporary switch would have probably been worth it.

Answer (score 7):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)[status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review)

Looking at [the states of the post summary design](https://stackoverflow.design/product/components/post-summary/#states) although this hasn't rolled out I noticed some of the icons aren't center aligned in the labels (for example for Deleted, Closed, Archived). Might as well mention it now before it roles out or just in case it's a mistake in the Stacks page.

[image: screenshot of icons inside labels]

### Edit:

The deleted label is already visible in the [migrated returned tabs](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tools/posts/migrated/returned) of the 10k tools.

Comment: On Firefox Nighly 98.0a1, I get [all texts aligned correctly](//i.stack.imgur.com/YXPVX.png). The effective font face is Liberation Sans. The “Archived” label appears to be missing one pixel in height, even though all labels have a height of 21.7 px, but these are tiny rendering glitches which I wouldn’t worry about too much.

Answer (score 7):

[discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion)[duplicate](/questions/tagged/duplicate)

1. It's very inconvenient to use this horizontal scrollbar on phone. I am not sure if it was there before.

   Android, Samsung Galaxy S7
   Resolution: FHD, 1920*1080
2. `Watched` label is much more convenient now and takes less space, but I think it's still too bright.

[image]

Comment: The scrollbar of the top bar is unrelated to post summaries. Its appearance has been reported before: [What's this weird black line on the topbar of a site I moderate?](/q/369773/289905). The _watched_ label being too bright has already been mentioned in the three answers before yours.

Comment: @SebastianSimon OK, thanks for clarification

Answer (score 7):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)

Can we remove "views"?

With old design there was no problem in not noticing "views", as they were either smaller, or in a separate column.

Now they are distracting from the important information: the votes.

If you are not going to make votes stand out again, maybe as another solution, views removal can be done?

Comment: For me, and I'm not saying it's the same for everyone else, there's one noticeable advantage keeping the view count, it's the only way I can tell the difference between a new question from a much older one on the home page. Disregarding Qs that have hit the HNQ, a high view count often means the post has been around a while.

Answer (score 6):

[discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion)

Longer question titles that wrap onto a second line push the tags and author information down. Similarly, the position of the author name and image moves around a lot depending on the length of the date. This makes it harder to glance over the page and see the relevant information, as the position of the information varies a lot:

[image: front-page]

Please consider the revising the layout to fix this.

Possible solutions might include some combination of:

- Clamping the tags and author line to the bottom of the question block.
- Splitting the author and date onto separate lines.
- Putting the author image to the right of the author name.
- Putting the author and date into a separate third column.

Comment: Yes there's room to put the author on one line with their avatar and reputation, and the past participle with the date on another line -- as it was before (except that before it was three lines, now it could be two).

Comment: It's unlikely to be adopted, because it seems everyone but me seems to think they're great, but one way to solve the variable width of dates would be getting rid of the relative labels like "yesterday" and just always showing a date and time.

Answer (score 5):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)

I think the new listings are useful for the reasons Ben Kelly explained in the question. But I must say having larger green boxes on the accepted answers was just more attractive visually (even more so on Dark Theme). Is there any chance there can be more surface to the accepted answer? If not can the explanation be pinpointed why that was a problem (because I'm having a hard time following)?

[image: screenshot of active tab on top questions]

I have to add: **I just find the front page less enjoyable now.** We just lost color and the empty space doesn't seem like a good trade-off.

[image: screenshot of post on front page]

Comment: And what happened to the watched tags highlighting?

Comment: @charlietfl well spotted, I think you should post that as a separate answer.

Comment: My understanding is this change is in regards to: "1. An arbitrary, scalable number of stats" meaning, they can add or remove stats from this section to accommodate content types that don't have one of the three or may have a 4th. (articles don't have answers.) I personally find this de-emphasizes rather important information and makes it difficult to parse quickly.

Comment: @KevinB good points, but I'm getting the impression it's less *eye candy* and if folks are like me they'll find the front page less enjoyable now...

Comment: We actually gained color, in that every username now has their avatar (does that mean the page has to load more graphics per load, for a page that previously showed no user avatars?)

Comment: @KevinB avatar has a much smaller surface than the accepted answer icon used to have...

Comment: @Kevin small peices of colour everywhere is bad...

Comment: @VScode_fanboy 100% agree, which is why i've suggested in a few places removing them. Going back to the original card would be fine as well

Answer (score 5):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-norepro](/questions/tagged/status-norepro)

I only use custom filters to follow tags (I don't use the watch dialogue below it) and usually questions with tags that are in my custom filters had a yellow background in the listings but the highlight isn't showing now (and neither is the watch label which I imagine would be the replacement for it).

This is not the same as [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/375479) because it's specific to using custom filters and not just watched tags (I'm also not getting the watched labels).

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce the issue. From what I can see, custom filters do not apply to the home page, just `/questions` (which has not changed). Can you give additional steps to reproduce the issue? Maybe we're referring to different things?

Comment: @BenKelly I just checked and it's working for me now. It wasn't working between when I wrote this and earlier today.The watched icons are also on the tags now, when I posted it was a separate label as shown in the other screenshot, but it didn't work for the costum filters at the time I posted...

Comment: No worries, I may have fixed this issue along with one of the other bugs. I'll mark this as norepro and consider it done.

Answer (score 5):

[discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion)

Unread questions blend into the tags:

[image]

The (unvisited) link color is a visual match to the background of the tags; the height of the title text similarly matches the height of the tags themselves. Combined with the vertically cramped layout, the two elements blend into one indistinct mass that fails to stand out as an unread question.

Comment: What network site is this on? We didn't make any changes to the  colors of tags / titles, so this is likely a preexisting issue. You can check against `/questions` (which has not yet been migrated) to compare.

Comment: This is originally a very old issue: [Visited links should be more visible](/q/52942/289905). With this layout it becomes even more of a problem.

Answer (score 5):

[support](/questions/tagged/support) [tag-watching](/questions/tagged/tag-watching) [duplicate](/questions/tagged/duplicate)

---

What is the difference between these "Watched" tags? The "eye" icon in the "Watched" tag refers to what?

**Screenshot for reference:**

[image: Watched tag]

Comment: Duplicate: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/375509/395497

Answer (score 5):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)[status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review)

Attempting to highlight the page with my mouse oddly skips various pieces of text. See image.

I'm using `macOS 12.1 Monterey` and `Safari 15.2`, both the latest.

I started this drag-highlight somewhere above the first title. Titles below that are not highlighted. Usernames are sometimes not highlighted.

Please make this work normally and as expected.

[image: highlighting items on list]

Comment: Works perfectly fine on Firefox.

Comment: Seems to work fine for me (Chrome 97.0.4692.99, macOS Monterey 12.1) as well. I'm guessing this might be something specific to Safari?

Answer (score 5):

[discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)

This hasn't been mentioned yet and I only noticed it today.

On smaller sites I actually know the other users and when I'm scanning the question list I find myself more focused on the username on the right side of the listing than any other element. (This is rarely the case on Stack Overflow where the chance of coming across a user I've seen before is minute.)

So I noticed the username causes more eye strain than the other elements because altough it has 12px font size like the tags, the left side meta data and the timestamp, it does however vary frequently (maybe with each post) while the other elements have fixed text and only rarely do I need to focus on them. (On larger sites the main indicator might be reputation because it tends to have a strong correlation with the possible quality of a question/answer but it's easier to see because it's in bold - and on smaller sites that focus is shifted to the username.)

I'm aware of [the wrapping issue (explained under TylerH's post)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/375153) that having a longer right-side element can cause, however I think a slightly larger font size for the username might have advantages without the drawback of causing a lot of wrapping.

Lastly, I suppose this might be especially relevant for Teams assuming most communities there are small to medium sized and users will tend to know each other by name like on the smaller SE sites.

(I'm linking Karl Knechtel's [excellent post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/375547) here because it helps put this into perspective visually.)

[image: screenshot of question listing with usernames higlighted]

Comment: Well generically, I'd rather see everything 'left' justified, over right justified

Answer (score 4):

[discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review)

Possible off-topic here, but this wording could do with some copy-editing:

> Questions that have a large amount of views or a large amount of feedback.

Suggest: **Questions with a lot of views or feedback.**

Comment: I'll consider this on topic-ish since it is about greatest hits and I _did_ change that wording as part of this change ;). I wrote the copy there and I agree that it could probably use a lookover from a copy editor. That sentence made sense to my developer brain since the check is boolean (large views OR large feedback). Believe it or not, the description now is better than what it used to be, which was most certainly written by a developer... I'll leave it at that.

Comment: Btw my main gripe (such as it is), is about the ungainly phrasing "large amount of", usually better written as "much" or "many" etc. (In this case, because it's being applied to both a countable and an uncountable noun, that doesn't really work though...)

Comment: Yes. Large *number* of views [countable]; large *amount* of feedback [uncountable].

Comment: @BenKelly I could suggest "Questions with many views or a lot of feedback" -- it's grammatical and uses fewer words than your version and so is more readable. Also, what is "a lot of feedback" -- do you mean "many answers"? Also, you wrote, "Questions with less views than the median (225) are excluded" -- but that should say "fewer", not "less".

Answer (score 4):

[discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion)

The alignment is bugging me: elements don't align.

Currently it's like this:

[image]

This would be better:

[image]

Top-aligning the two would make the title text more readable, instead of the statistics over-dominating -- if you make them equal, balanced, then the eye can read either.

To implement this (moving that left column down a bit), I reckon you'll also want to remove what's currently 6px of margin-bottom from the views.

Comment: You could ask the folks in https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/ ...

Comment: I would rather that the baselines of the two pieces of text are aligned.

Answer (score 4):

## The mobile view is irritating

The new post summary design on questions page just arrived to my most-used site, Code Golf and Coding Challenges.

[image]

Although my use is primarily from the computer, I occasionally check from my phone. I don't have access to my phone at the moment, but using the Device Emulation feature of the developer console shows the above view for a typical-sized phone. Indeed, this is the view that I was shown this morning when I checked Code Golf and Coding Challenges from my phone.

However, the mobile view that appeared prior to this change was a lot more pleasurable to use. Although the view above is great (comparably) on computers, it certainly is not on mobile, because it looks as though Stack Exchange has tried to cram as much information as possible into a small space. The old mobile view was a lot more simplistic and I found it intuitive.

Therefore, my request is to at least revert the mobile view. If you're not willing to remove the current desktop view (which I'm not fond of either), at least revert the mobile view.

Comment: Viewing tagged questions on S.O. is similarly unpleasant. By the time you add in the "tag" description,  the header/options eats up 3/4 of the mobile screen. Leaving only the bottom 1/4 for the actual content! Ugh.

Comment: The mobile view is being depreceated, so no chance on that getting back.

Answer (score 3):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign)

#### Inconsistent capitalisation post summary tooltip

The post summary tooltip ([in which some are missing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/375524/844268)) have inconsistent capitalisation.

I'd expect every tooltip to start with a capital letter, as for example, [the navigation menu already does](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eXiob.png).

---

Some tooltips regarding the UX change do not start with a capital letter:

##### Bounty

[image: example image bounty]

---

##### User reputation

[image: example image user reputaion]

Comment: These titles match what exists currently (see unmigrated `/questions` view as an example). Marking as bydesign for now, this is something that can be revisited later if there is demand for it.

Comment: For reference, I think these should eventually be changed to have sentence case capitalization; I'm guessing the original tooltips were created before [Stacks made the design philosophy consistent in that regard](https://stackoverflow.design/content/guidelines/grammar-and-mechanics/#use-sentence-casing).

Answer (score 3):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign)

On iOS 14 Safari spaces separating user icons, names, reputation and last action suddenly disappeared and now everything looks glued together:

[image: screenshot]

This seems like a regression considering that on Feb 7 (4 days ago) spaces were present: [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zgG8G.jpg).

Comment: We’ve switched to the `gap` property from `margin` for the `flex` layout which gives us a lot more control over layout, regardless of what info or which order we put it in. Safari's support for the `gap` property was first supported in Safari 14.1 on October 20, 2020. While our official [browser support](https://browsers.stackoverflow.design) doesn’t have us supporting Safari 14 _at all_, we waited to adopt `gap` until we were well into iOS 15 release cycle. Given the aggressive upgrade numbers in the Apple ecosystem, we made the call to move ahead on `gap`.

Comment: @AaronShekey your browser support only spans less than *six months?* What... well OK then I guess you can mark this as `[status-bydesign]`.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli: As noted on the page Aaron linked: "Stacks supports the last two stable versions of each major browser. If your browser doesn’t appear in this list, it still may work, but with a degraded experience."

Comment: @V2Blast yeah, that's crystal clear. I'm just baffled that the browser support is so short-lived. As I said, feel free to retag as `[status-bydesign]`.

Answer (score 2):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

Not a bug with visible consequences, but the reputation score `<span>` element doesn't have a proper class:

```
<span class="todo-no-class-here" title="reputation score " dir="ltr">2,783</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

[discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion)

For those who are more interested in content but Meta: [Tampermonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/tampermonkey/) is your friend.

```js
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Stackoverflow: Clean Start Page
// @namespace    http://ceving/
// @version      0.1
// @description  Remove useless stuff.
// @author       ceving
// @match        https://stackoverflow.com/
// @grant        GM_addStyle
// ==/UserScript==

(function() {
    'use strict';
    GM_addStyle('.s-post-summary--stats { display: none; }');
    GM_addStyle('.s-post-summary { display: list-item; margin-left: 1.5em; padding: 0; border: none; }');
    GM_addStyle('.s-user-card.s-user-card__minimal { display: none; }');
    GM_addStyle('.s-post-summary--meta { display: none; }');
    GM_addStyle('.s-post-summary--content .s-post-summary--content-title { display: inline; margin-bottom: 0; padding-right: 0; }');
})();
```

Comment: This resolves which specific issue?

Comment: I payed for every single pixel on my display. I have no idea, why I must not use them all for something useful but empty space or useless stuff.

Comment: I have no idea in which way the name of an avatar helps to answer a question.

Comment: Re *"Remove useless stuff"*: Can you be more specific? Can you [provide](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/375562/edit) an explanation and/or a screenshot (with a frame and [freehand circles](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/19775#19775)) of what this is supposed to do?

Comment: @This_is_NOT_a_forum I have answered your question but my comment was once again censored without notice.

Answer (score 1):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review)

This time I'm not the only one seeing this because in screenshots from other users it's also visible. The icon isn't perfectly centered inside the tag, although the misalignment is subtle it's noticeable using normal resolution (for me it works as the saying goes:*"once you notice it you can't take your eyes of it."*)

(I have to wonder if this can actually be fixed, somehow, or if it's some kind of technological limitation... It happens with some icons but not with others, dunno...)

[image: screenshot of watched icon inside tag]

Comment: Seems to be bottom aligned. It may not be your preference but it's not like it's a random alignment

Comment: @charlietfl I said it was inconsistent with the alignment of other icons which are usually perfectly centered inside the tags/labels. It doesn't make much sense having different alignments, or slight offsets in some cases does it?

Comment: _“This time I'm not the only one seeing this because in screenshots from other users it's also visible.”_ — Of course you’re not the only one. Is this [Segoe, which has a lower baseline](/questions/372049/new-responsive-activity-page/372673#comment1244747_372673)? (The dev tools will tell you.) For me, again, the text [looks just fine](//i.stack.imgur.com/2cRjo.png), using Liberation Sans. The icon isn’t centered, just like for you, but it’s off by only one pixel, which is acceptable.

Comment: @SebastianSimon in this post I focused only on the icon! Imagine that instead of programmers we were table waiters, would we be discussing if 1 fly in the soup is acceptable? This 1px issue reminds me of [the unsymmetrical diamond](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/367942) it's worth mentioning because it catches the eye and hopefully staff will be able to fix it eventually (or someone will offer a detailed in depth explanation of the causes)... In the meanwhile, thank you for taking notice and confirming the 1px :)

Comment: @bad_coder Oh, sorry, you didn’t actually mention the text; based on the other comments here, I assumed you referred to it, too.

Comment: @SebastianSimon no problem, it made your comment even better because it was more complete!

Answer (score 1):

Other than the obvious "disapproval" of the new design, there seems to be an alignment issue as well.

Point **1** shows how the `tags` and `username` are aligned in one single line, but point **2** shows how that's being distorted if either of the text overflows the margin.

Might be a simple issue but definitely hurts the eye.

[image]

Comment: What do you suggest instead?

Answer (score 0):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review)

User profile icons are among the most colorful and varied elements on the homepage.

They draw attention to themselves but don't add value or readability.

I suggest showing user names without an icon.

Comment: The personalized avatars on the new page are tiny, just itty bitty dots of color. What evidence do you have that their owners/authors have an unfair advantage? Next, someone will be suggesting that we eliminate usernames and individuals be identified as a series of random numbers. If someone wants to be totally anonymous on Stack Exchange that's fine, they are free to be so but don't impose that on everyone.

Answer (score -6):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [pluralization](/questions/tagged/pluralization) [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign)

Posts with negative scores have a pluralization bug in *votes* see the screenshot and compare with the post that has a positive score.

[image]

Comment: Which screen is this on?

Comment: @Phil it was taken on the main page of Stack Overflow using a standard 1920x1080 but the browser window wasn't full screen so you're seeing the responsive design in action.

Comment: This should be [replaced by “score”](/a/375181/289905) anyway.

Comment: This isn't a pluralisation bug.

Comment: @Nick it's the usual definition of pluralization bug, why do you say it isn't?

Comment: Because "negative one votes" is correct. English is silly, but it's still not a bug.

Comment: @Nick no because the "positive one votes" has been discussed and it isn't correct. But find a reference on MSE to back up your claim.

Comment: Related: [Is negative one plural?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/165244/684990)

Comment: @Nick the linked thread on English.SE has mixed opinions but the overall most voted answers (with references) disagree with your claim.

Comment: @bad_coder That doesn't change the consensus on meta.SE

Comment: @Zoethe1337Princess the +15 on that post isn't a consensus, it's 15 users who didn't downvote :P

Comment: Just as the downvotes you're getting here don't mean you're wrong, it's just people that didn't upvote. The linked questions have a pretty clear conclusion indicating the plural version to be correct...

Comment: @Cerbrus exactly, needs moar upvotes!

Comment: I actually think -1 [noun], noun should be singular for discretely countable nouns, such as 'vote'.  The answer on the English SE actually uses non-discrete examples for where a plural is appropriate.

Comment: @JeffUK glad I wasn't the only one to notice that...

Answer (score -8):

[discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion)

Today, Jan 26, 2022, noon UTC, the two most lamented new features appear to have been improved: The votes are now on top of the information on the left, and the orange icon used to highlight questions matching my tags have been removed, reverting back to the light-salmon-colored background color for the entire entry.

I can live well with the current state now.

As a suggestion, I'd highlight questions that have been positively received, for example by using bold font for the vote count. That would make it easier to identify questions worth my time.

Comment: Tolerable and fully functional are not synonymous and we should not be expected to accept a regression in the UI which seems to be the recent standard

Comment: @charlietfl Given that people (me included) typically resent any change I'm willing to give them some leeway without starting to whine. I'll probably have forgotten about it in a month. It is fully functional for me.