# Can I ask for a recent feature change to be reverted in whole, and what are the chances of such a request succeeding?

Tags: discussion, support, meta, feature-request-process

(This is a general question and isn't specifically asking about one particular change.)

In the current times, quite a few radical changes are being made to the Stack Exchange engine, such as the [question list changes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/375081/new-post-summary-designs-on-greatest-hits-now-everywhere-else-eventually) and [user profile changes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/372049/new-responsive-activity-page).

Recently, there was one such UI change made which I strongly dislike, as it either:

- breaks my workflow
- is hard for me to use and understand
- de-implements some feature that I use quite frequently
- is bad for [other reason X]

I (or other users) have filed feature requests asking for changes to be made to better suit my workflow, but these changes have either been:

- declined or marked as by design
- not responded to in a long time
- given a staff response agreeing with the request (e.g. a marking as planned or deferred), but no action has been taken on them in a long while

I've also made repeated attempts to get used to the new UI, but after a *long* time, I'm still unhappy with the new UI and would strongly prefer the old UI.

I understand that it's important that SE update these pages so that they fit into the ultimate goal of having a completely responsive design. However, I dislike the current implementations of those updates and would prefer to go back to the old UI while I wait for these issues to be resolved and hopefully implemented.

How can I make a request for the team to either:

- revert back to the old design, temporarily or indefinitely, or
- provide a way to switch back to the old design temporarily (as was done with the 2018 site design changes)?

Also, what are the chances that such a request will actually succeed?

---

I've noticed that many of these recent changes are quite negatively received, with extremely low vote scores: several of the bottom 20 scored questions here on this site are announcements for recent feature changes. This question, once answered, is intended as a resource to help users make stronger arguments for making such a change, so they'll be more likely to be actioned by the team or at least result in some adaptation.

Comment: I'm pretty sure once the current set of changes are solidified or maybe before, someone's going to throw togetjer a userscript to revert all the changes

Comment: @JourneymanGeek see [Legqcy Questions](https://stackapps.com/q/9293/34061)

Answer (score 20):

> Can I ask for a recent feature change to be reverted in whole

You certainly *can*... but let me rephrase your question:

> **Should** I ask for a recent feature change to be reverted wholly?

Well, if:

- You were not notified about it before it happened, or
- You were notified, but were not afforded enough of an opportunity to voice your objection, or
- You objected, but your objection got no serious rebuttal

then - you most definitely should.

> and what are the chances of such a request succeeding?

I would guess they are low. That does not mean it is not important to voice your objection.

---

Also:

> I understand that it's important that SE update these pages so that they fit into the ultimate goal of having a completely responsive design.

Please dis-understand this. I'm not sure what a "completely responsive design" is, but if getting there means making parts of the site annoying to use, then maybe we can tweak that ultimate goal a little.

Comment: In this context, "responsive" = "works on mobile without needing two different UIs."

Comment: I don't think getting there *necessarily* means making the UI worse; in fact, it could make it better, and the goal itself is quite reasonable (but of course any change *can* make things worse, as seen in a couple of recent examples).

Comment: @tim: I did say _if_. As for the goal being reasonable - goals which include terms like "complete", "total", "without exception", "every single" - are suspicious/scary to me. I'm not necessarily against them, but I would need a lot of clarity before I support that kind of rhetoric.

Comment: @Kevin In that case if it messes up desktop use then responsive is a very bad thing. Desktop and mobile are different so why not have two different UI - Attempts to combine them by people with more resources than SX have failed e.g. Microsoft

Comment: @mmmmmm: Because developer-hours are expensive and the cost (in dollars) to SE, Inc of maintaining two UIs greatly exceeds the cost (also in dollars) that they incur as a result of users being unhappy with said UI on desktop. That's capitalism. *shrug*