# Please revert the new question list style change

Tags: feature-request, bug, design, question-lists

For many years, the question list view was such that you could easily move your eyes up and down along a column of numbers with the same meaning. Now the numbers are not aligned, the text is small and it feels jumbled...

I believe this was a change for the worse and ask that it be reverted - at least for desktop browsers.

**Notes:**

- The updates over the past couple of weeks (up to 2022-02-05) have not resolved the problem nor even significantly ameliorated it.
- It seems the new design also decreases the number of elements per unit of vertical length; and that it has contrast issues - gray text on white background. Those are also problems but they could theoretically be addressed without reverting the entire design.
- [@hkotsubo commented](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/375481/please-revert-the-new-question-list-style-change#comment1250758_375481) with links to [before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iLy9F.jpg) and [after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vb9v1.jpg) images for the mobile question list design, and it seems to also be a change for the worse, but I should not be one to judge since I don't use SE on a mobile device.
- This is not the the first time, unfortunately, when a core aspect of site design was degraded, and not fixed despite negative feedback: [Example](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/344874/196834), [another example](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/353525/please-revert-the-line-height-change). Maybe we should start a [please-revert-degradation](/questions/tagged/please-revert-degradation) tag or something.
- I should perhaps also explain why I am voicing my objection now rather than earlier, before the rollout. I was not aware it was coming. Even the "featured meta post" entitled "new post summary designs on greatest hits" does not suggest the question list design is going to be changed. And while I might have noticed this if I had spent time on meta, it wasn't "teased" in any way on regular site. The reason I'm not on meta is that... well, I spend my time asking and answering proper questions  and only come here where I know something needs my attention. So - I learned about the change when I just saw it put into effect.

Comment: I kind of figured this type of question would be asked, so I just asked [Can I ask for a recent feature change to be reverted in whole, and what are the chances of such a request succeeding?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/375477/can-i-ask-for-a-recent-feature-change-to-be-reverted-in-whole-and-what-are-the)

Comment: The related announcement: [New post summary designs on greatest hits now, everywhere else eventually](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/375081/335251)

Comment: In mobile it's also worse and I want it reverted.

Comment: @hkotsubo: 1. Fair enough, but can you link to before/after images?

Comment: [Before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iLy9F.jpg) - more organized, more questions visible at the same time. [After](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vb9v1.jpg) - I don't get SE's obsession for useless, excessive whitespace/padding/margins. I'm using Chrome in iOS 15.1

Comment: Regarding being "notified about the change" - the post about changing the format has been featured across the entire network for almost 2 weeks now. SE rarely "teases" design changes on single sites, and if they do, it's almost always here, on MSE. Frankly, I don't think you can justifiably complain about not being aware of the change - it takes 5 seconds to look at the 2 or 3 "important, network-wide impact" posts that are featured, no matter what site you're on

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing Knowing in advance is almost irrelevant to this abysmal rollout. When it was only visible on Greatest Hits the critical features weren't as obvious as they now are on lists everyone use daily

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing: I wasn't complaining, I was explaining why I am voicing my objection now rather than earlier. That is, I didn't just ignore something I knew was going on.

Comment: *I should perhaps also mention that I was not notified about this change* - indeed. What was announced in [this announcement meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/375081/new-post-summary-designs-on-greatest-hits-now-everywhere-else-eventually) is a DIFFERENT design (see "what we are shipping later" section).

Comment: @MarcoBonelli: And note that, reading the title of that meta post, I would absolutely not be able to guess that it's about changing the question list design.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli: It's the same design. It's right there in the Before/After section. And they clearly state that *all* lists are going to go this way. Indeed, the very next section states as clearly as possible that "/ (home / recent questions)" is next.

Comment: It's just as deceiving as ads you see in the subway at this point, I cannot comprehend what is going on in any part of the StackExchange network anymore. It's been a month-long headache, update after update.

Comment: @einpoklum: I would think that a question title that ends with "everywhere else eventually" would merit some investigation.

Comment: @NicolBolas right there? The [current design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w01mo.png) is nowhere to be seen in that post. The before/after shown there does not match the current design (FWIW, just to be clear, we are talking about the home page here, not /questions).

Comment: @SurpriseDog: 1. Don't knock the UI designer's work. It's quite possible they were tasked with designing something completely generic, not a question list replacement. 2. I have no problem with a UI designer making 6-figures, and neither should you; the problem is that other people make 5-figures for very decent work. 3. I'm not categorically against design improvements, but I'd say "if it ain't broke, think ten times before fixing it".

Comment: @NicolBolas: Even if it were "everywhere", it talks about the design of a "new post summary". I (think I) don't mind very much what happens with the design of "new post summaries".

Comment: @MarcoBonelli: The only difference is that it lacks the post description. In every other way, it's identical.

Comment: @NicolBolas so it's identical except it's not identical. Oh well. Hope you can see why I am calling it deceiving.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli: Not really. Every element being discussed here as a negative was part of what was shown. So as far as the discussion about whether this is good or bad, all of the "bad" parts were thing you were warned about coming to the home page. You weren't deceived just because the text blurb isn't part of the home page.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli: While the inconsistency is annoying, I believe Nicol is right in that it's hyperbole for you to call it a "deception". But regardless, I would rather the issue be discussed on the merits rather than on the technicality of whether or not we got "due notice".

Comment: @einpoklum well that's what it feels to me TBH. Anyway, that's right, we are here because we think this is clearly a regression, regardless of being notified about it or not.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli: I wonder if we could somehow get this post to be featured :-P

Comment: @einpoklum: "*The post you linked to does not contain answers to my post.*" [One of the answers there does say to revert the change](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/375478/164572). So this particular issue is being tracked.

Comment: @NicolBolas: That's not the criterion for question dupeness.

Comment: @einpoklum: 1) That's why I didn't vote to close it as such. 2) The response from the developers will be part of/associated with that answer.

Comment: @NicolBolas: 1. Well, I hope developers respond here, rather than in a comment to one of 10 or so answers to a question whose title isn't immediately relatable to the issue... 2. I won't be surprised if there's no response.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [New post summary designs on greatest hits now, everywhere else eventually](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/375478/282094) - 12 days ago. As a featured announcement it's expected that searching for duplicates before you file a new report will turn up the duplicate and that you would simply upvote the feedback (answer) that duplicates your complaint.

Comment: @Rob: 1. It's not a duplicate. 2. The title of the question does not suggest the question list design is to be changed. 3. You're the third person to suggest that as a dupe.

Comment: The issue of closing questions as duplicates of announcements if they've already been requested as answers there [has been discussed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/330811/377214).

Comment: I think so too. I have the feeling that I won't get used to it over time either.

Comment: @SonictheAnti-NewVariant-hog: IMO, This is (site-)political censorship, using considerations which are convenient to SE inc. to suppress public criticism.

Comment: Another reason for the feature request: It is now very difficult to see if a question has a negative score, especially when it is a small number like -11 rather than a big negative score like -349. This is especially difficult in the mobile view.

Comment: @SonictheAnti-NewVariant-hog: Your linked question is itself duped against another question, whose sole answer says the opposite.

Comment: @Kevin Yeah, I self-closed it, since (as the question body there says) I personally disagree with closing such questions as duplicates (and have not voted to close this one). I link to that question mainly because the answer to it was posted by someone who's now a moderator, so I figured that that was the policy being upheld.

Comment: I also figured that the downvotes on that question are a disagreement of the anti-closing opinion I express in that question, which means people think such questions *should* be closed as duplicates.

Comment: @SonictheAnti-NewVariant-hog: Actually, downvotes on meta sites are often rather difficult to interpret.