# Please revert New post summary designs

Tags: feature-request, bug, user-interface

The new UI is shockingly bad. I just noticed today, since it only today rolled out to sites I use. Why on earth does ignoring a tag make it more prominent? Why not highlight watched tags? Why make votes almost invisible? It's just totally incomprehensible.

I realize this is a duplicate, but I am posting it as a new question because I believe that this large of a regression in UI needs to be taken incredibly seriously since it significantly affects the usability of the site. Below is a screenshot of the new UI for any of you fortunate enough to not have seen it yet.

See also *[New post summary designs on site home pages and greatest hits now; everywhere else eventually](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/375081/new-post-summary-designs-on-greatest-hits-now-everywhere-else-eventually?cb=1)* and *[Please revert the new question list style change](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/375481/please-revert-the-new-question-list-style-change?noredirect=1&lq=1)* for evidence that this is not a niche opinion.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wZjuv.png]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Please revert the new question list style change](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/375481/please-revert-the-new-question-list-style-change) (I mean, I sort of have to - I see your point, but this is close-worthy)

Comment: While I understand that by the rules of Meta this should be closed, I would request that you don't vote to close it anyway. This is such a bad change, I believe it should need to be justified repeatedly.

Comment: Sorry, but posting an intentional duplicate is *never* a good way to get attention for another request. Yes, we know how much it's been detested, but this crosses the line.