# Is there an easy way for me to go back to the old layout of the information to the left of the question title?

Tags: support, design

I don't like the new layout of votes, answers, views on the left side of the page. How do I go back to how it looked previously?

[image: Screenshot indicating the new votes/answers/views layout to the left of a question title are the issue]

This question has been marked as a duplicate of [Please revert the new question list style change](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/375481/please-revert-the-new-question-list-style-change) but that doesn't seem to answer my question directly.

I just want a quick and easy way to make the site look like how it used to look. If that isn't possible or if it's really time consuming to do then so be it, I'll stick with the new changes.

Comment: StackApps: [LegacyQuestions - Bringing back the old questions design](https://stackapps.com/questions/9293/legacyquestions-bringing-back-the-old-questions-design)

Comment: Then upvote the existing posts under the announcement. Seriously, why is it okay to get 80 reputation points for free by just stating that you don’t like an unpopular change? This adds nothing new!

Comment: Also I don't feel like this question is a duplicate. But I'm not reading all of those super long duplicates to find out, as this isn't super important to me. I just want a quick and easy way to make the site look like how it used to look. If that isn't possible or if it's really time consuming then so be it, I'll stick with the new changes.

Comment: @AdamRubinson Your main concern (no liking the new design) was already answered in the "New post summary..." Q/A and technically strictly this post is a duplicate of that post but I think that having a 
"one Q catch all" is **not** a good practice, specially when the Q has several updates way beyond clarifying the original version and answering relevant comments/concerns as a FAQ.

Comment: Oh this is 100% a duplicate.  Even down to the point where you'd like to switch between layouts, that's covered in an answer in that other post.  It's...not really our problem if you don't want to read through all of the answers to see that your suggestion is already covered, but rest assured it is.  If you don't trust us, you could read the answers for yourself to see.

Comment: If my question has been answered in the "New post summary" question, can someone point out to me where exactly on that page it has been answered. Why do you want me to waste my time sifting through the entire thread, which is very long, rather than pointing out to me *where* my question was answered?

Comment: On MathOverflow Meta: [Bringing back the old front page with custom CSS: a guide](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/5248).

Comment: @AdamRubinson this [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/375511/361484)

Comment: @SebastianSimon This is a good duplicate. Generally searchable duplicates are a benefit for everyone - downvoting duplicates is generally disruptive from a perspective of content searching.