# What is the community feedback weight in deciding if a UI/UX is going to be "committed" or reverted?

Tags: discussion, design, feedback

I have recently noticed a change in the post list when a significant part of it became almost unreadable when compared to the previous version. I did not like it and I was pleased to find out that I am [far from being the only one not liking it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/375081/new-post-summary-designs-on-site-home-pages-and-greatest-hits-now-everywhere-el?cb=1).

This change (along with others in the past) received very little love from the community and I am wondering if this input is considered in the SO development team's decision to go on with the change or revert it.

I am specifically asking for in the context of this recent case because any user accessing the list is forced to live with it. This is opposed to the case when the layout changes impact is easier to check (e.g. user interaction with some links decreases and signals that something is wrong with the new layout).

What is the community feedback weight in deciding if a UI/UX is going to be "committed" or reverted? Is there any? Or only some metrics from A/B testing or similar matter in this type of decision?

Comment: This seems to be a pretty nearly exact duplicate of [Can I ask for a recent feature change to be reverted in whole, and what are the chances of such a request succeeding?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/375477/can-i-ask-for-a-recent-feature-change-to-be-reverted-in-whole-and-what-are-the)

Comment: @zcoop98 Yes, they are very similar. I am not happy with the answer there, especially because it is not coming from SO staff.

Comment: For sure, I agree it isn't satisfactory at the moment. Ideally the question will receive an answer from staff in due time!

Comment: "Is there any?" It's either 0.375812 or there isn't really a specific weight and the influence of community feedback on further changes on the UX/UI is very complex and cannot simply be combined into a single, simple expression. It's probably more a case-by-case decision. If however, changes happen, then probably because of the community feedback.

Comment: Basically take whatever they use as success metric (profit, site visits, ...) and then try to quantify the influence of downvotes on meta on that metric. That influence, as indirect as it may be, is the weight of the community feedback.

Comment: It is ranging from somewhere around absolute zero to "I guess the change is not worth pissing off half the network of free labor". They did revert the removal of custom 404 pages nearly instantly. At the same time it took a shitstorm to get at least some concessions on the matter of "toxic metrics". It really depends. If the change is driven by an agenda of a certain group in the company - good luck having *anything* to be backtracked. If there is any substantial dev time poured into - not happening either, but can be tweaked upon backlash (see: review queues, recent redesigns).

Comment: If the change was dictated by the "too hard to maintain" reasoning - also nope, we can scream all we want, it's not gonna happen (remember the non-sticky navbar option?). If it affects profitability - no chance. So, overall, if it is of little significance, then the feedback starts to matter, otherwise chances are basically zero. The company did improve communication via the significantly expanded CM team (who *are* doing a great job), but don't get yourself fooled, the relationship between the community and the company stayed strictly top-down (and not in favor of the former, obviously).

Comment: It's going to be kept.  There's some reason why they want it this way for Teams, and so it has to be that way for everything because they can't waste resources on anything that isn't Teams.