# Is vote count being less prominent an intended feature of the new design?

Tags: discussion, design

I don't want to judge the new design, although I think it desires a serious discussion on UX.stackexchange.

What is striking to me, how less prominent the vote count has become. It's hidden somewhere between the answer count, and the view count, and all of them are very small compared to big screaming 'watched' banner.

Was it a concept behind that new design, to make vote count less prominent, to remove the mental filtering of the downvoted answers from the question list? Was it a consideration, that seeing big minus creates a cognitive bias, giving first person to vote a disproportionate power? Was such cognitive bias considered a problem recently?

Comment: @Luuklag no, because it doesn't specify a reasoning behind that particular decision.

Comment: "_Q: What if I have constructive feedback, but it isn’t a bug?
A: We’d like to hear it! Add it as an answer on this post. As above, you can add a [tag:discussion] tag to the top of the post as well._" - quoted from [the official announcement](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/375081/818993)

Comment: @RafaelTavares to be honest, for me it sounds like 'pour out your complaints, we don't care anyway'...

Comment: Did it change for you? I'm on mobile and now the vote count is the first number in the row at least.

Comment: @Laurel I’m not the OP, but yes: I distinctly recall the vote count being the second item on the list earlier today, but it is showing up as the first item right now. (I am on mobile).

Comment: @DanubianSailor because for the most part that is what it sounds like :) I have to give them credit, though - the devs *are* responding to the requests/reports/discussions when they can - so please do post an answer there inviting the discussion about the reasons behind making vote count less prominent, I am sure at least *some* response will be given (not necessarily the one we want to hear, though...)

Comment: Speaking of feedback: https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/375081/revisions

Comment: If the score is hidden so much, what else should I go after to judge the quality of a question at a quick glance?