# Questions with ignored tags are displayed in grayscale instead of lower opacity

Tags: support, design, ignored-tags, accessibility

I just noticed that along with the [recent changes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/375081/348196) to questions lists, questions with ignored tags on the home page are now displayed in grayscale instead of showing them in lower opacity<sup>1</sup>.

This is how they're currently displayed:

[image]

And this is how they used to be (currently used on /questions links):

[image]

Dark mode:

[image]

**Was this change intentional?**

I don't really mind the use of grayscale but **I don't think the lower opacity should go**. It hurts the accessibility for people who are color blind (and even for those who aren't, I'd argue).

---

<sup>1</sup> <sub>Assuming you're not using the "*Hide* questions in your ignored tags" option.</sub>

Comment: It technically has both `filter: grayscale(100%);` and `opacity: .7;`. Should it have a lower opacity? The (slightly outdated) [design page](//stackoverflow.design/product/components/post-summary/#states) also uses grayscale. I don’t see why this change wouldn’t be intentional.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [New post summary designs on site home pages and greatest hits now; everywhere else eventually](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/375081/new-post-summary-designs-on-site-home-pages-and-greatest-hits-now-everywhere-el)

Comment: @SebastianSimon I hardly notice the change in opacity in the case of grayscale. It is, however, very noticeable on /questions (and used to be on the homepage too).

Comment: @RafaelTavares If you can find an answer in that post that mentions this issue, I'll close it as a duplicate (I checked before posting and couldn't find one). Otherwise, I think this should be discussed separately.

Comment: @41686d6564 I thought the dupe flag was a hint to discuss this under the main post instead by adding a new answer yourself.

Comment: I still disagree that this should be closed as a duplicate of [New post summary designs on site home pages and greatest hits now; everywhere else eventually](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/375081/348196) because that one is not specifically related to ignored tags or accessibility. However, we at least have a more appropriate (and more recent) dupe target: [My brain cannot ignore the ignored questions due to contrast change. Please change it back](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/382047/348196).