# Wrong z-index for tag popup when the question has an ignored tag

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, design, popups

After [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/382047/my-brain-cannot-ignore-the-ignored-questions-due-to-contrast-change-please-chan) was fixed, I tested it a bit, and noticed this behavior:

> [image: Tag popup is below other content]

When there is an ignored tag and the question is grayed out, the tag popup is below/behind the other page contents due to wrong z-index. (And also the popup itself shouldn't be grayed out.)

| Browser | OS |
| --- | --- |
| Chrome (latest) | Windows 10 |
| Chrome (latest) | mac OS 13.3 |
| Edge (latest) | mac OS 13.3 |
| Firefox (latest) | mac OS 13.3 |
| Opera (latest) | mac OS 13.3 |
| Safari (latest) | mac OS 13.3 |

Comment: repro'd on Android as well

Comment: You can add: Google Chrome 113, Microsoft Edge 113, Firefox 113, Opera 99, Safari 16.4; all on mac OS 13.3, to your li'l table.

Comment: @ElementsinSpace thanks, all of those are the latest? (Prefer latest over number, unless of course it's older version then it's also more relevant.)

Comment: Yes, they are the latest at time of posting. (Browsers are updating all the time these days, so just having "latest", might become inaccurate before long)

Comment: @ElementsinSpace well, IMO clear enough it means "latest when bug was reported", so issue not related to old version. I'll add now. :)

Comment: While the information that the browser version is the latest when posted is beneficial, not listing the actual browser version is counterproductive, given that browsers release new versions rapidly. In some months it's multiple times in a single month. Thus, without the version number, just saying "latest" is fairly useless to future readers. Saying the version number *and* that it's the latest is substantially more useful.

Comment: I'd note, however, that the nature of this issue makes it unlikely to be related to a particular browser or browser revision. It is useful to know that it's been replicated on multiple browsers and operating systems. But, again, this particular problem should be easy to replicate.

Comment: @Makyen well if the bug goes by itself at some point due to browser update, it should be noted in the report, or self answer. Developers won't go and install old version when going to fix a bug, so can't see the value in having it. (Unless not current, hence might be cause of the bug.)

Comment: "*Developers won't go and install old version when going to fix a bug,*" but if a developer is trying to test a bug, it ensures they would properly do it. Or they might test with a version *which is too old* because they haven't updated their browser yet for whatever reason.

Comment: @VLAZ my base assumption is that design bugs "stick", even if browser specific, they start at some version, but usually not going away by themselves, i.e. still happening in future versions.

Comment: We're on it. Nesting opacity issue from ignored fix is my guess (without looking)

Comment: @ShadowTheSpringWizard What you appear to be arguing for when not including the version number of the browsers tested is to give *less* information, which makes the report *less useful*. Just provide all the available information, including the browser version number and, since you know it's the latest, also indicate that it's the latest at the time the bug report was posted.

Answer (score 9):

> We're on it. Nesting opacity issue from ignored fix is my guess (without looking) –
> [Piper](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/355481/piper)

Correct!

In [a recent Stacks update](https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks/pull/1370), we applied a lower opacity to the children of `.s-post-summary` when ignored or deleted. This styling affected the container of the tags (and *everything* in it including [the tag popover](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hLvF2.png)). We've [shipped a fix Stacks](https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks/pull/1377/files) to apply the lower opacity more selectively which should resolve this issue. Please report any other issues if you find any and thanks for reporting @ShadowTheSpringWizard!

---

> […]due to wrong z-index.

Although we did not make changes to any element's z-index, giving an element an opacity less than 1 results in it gaining a new stacking context.

From [W3C](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-color-3/#transparency):

> Since an element with opacity less than 1 is composited from a single offscreen image, content outside of it cannot be layered in z-order between pieces of content inside of it. For the same reason, implementations must create a new stacking context for any element with opacity less than 1. If an element with opacity less than 1 is not positioned, then it is painted on the same layer, within its parent stacking context, as positioned elements with stack level 0.

Comment: When a tag is ignored (with the popup), it goes grey and gets a crossed-eye icon.  When unignoring the tag, the colours come back instantly, but the icon remains until the page is refreshed.  
Not a major problem, but a bug nevertheless.

Comment: Close, but still not a full cigar: https://i.stack.imgur.com/l05x1.png. Thanks! (to save a click, the user card still appears behind existing contents.)

Comment: @ElementsinSpace I noticed that as well in my testing. It's pretty low priority so it might be a while before we have capacity to address it. Nevertheless, I appreciate the report!

Comment: @ShadowTheSpringWizard Ah, good catch! I'll have a fix for that going out today or tomorrow