# Remove yellow badge around watched tags

Tags: discussion, design, tag-watching

I'm trying my best to see these changes with fresh eyes, and not simply be apprehensive about any changes. However, I can't find a justification for making watched tags yellow. To me, bright icons should be used sparingly and denote things of high importance. In this case:

- the information is redundant, as the question is already highlighted
- often, watched items become frequent, especially if you're interested in a popular topic. This has a tendency to fill the page with bright, distracting colors.

I propose removing the yellow from watched tags, and simply including the eye with a subtle hue change to the tag.

---

[image: yellow watched]

---

Comment: Does this answer your question? [New post summary designs on site home pages and greatest hits now; everywhere else eventually](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/375081/new-post-summary-designs-on-site-home-pages-and-greatest-hits-now-everywhere-el) (Relevant answers: [1](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/375638/1017231) [2](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/375081/new-post-summary-designs-on-site-home-pages-and-greatest-hits-now-everywhere-el/375512#375512) [3](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/375639/1017231))

Comment: Welcome to Meta SE. FYI, your question is at least very similar, if not a duplicate, of this [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/375653/562482) of the proposed duplicate question. Note, however, that answer was marked as [tag:duplicate] by the other answer's OP, but with no indication of which other answer it's a duplicate of.

Comment: seems like I'm not the only new Meta user to show up recently.