# Hyphenation in titles makes it difficult to read quickly

Tags: discussion, title, homepage

I couldn’t find any announcement about this, so I expect it’s a recent change (or a bug): some words in the titles of questions on the Home page are now broken into two lines with a hyphen. This is what I’m seeing on [Academia SE](https://academia.stackexchange.com/)’s Home page on mobile (in the responsive design):

[image: Screenshot of Home page of Academia SE showing titles broken using hyphens.]

The titles in the above image appear as follows:

- > Is there a way to include an updated paper cita-
  > tion link in Excel?
- > Should professors use the f*** word during lec-
  > tures? [closed]
- > Should I upload unfinished work to arxiv or oth-
  > er similar platforms?
- > Can an academic paper use a fictional world
  > (such as the show WestWorld) as a case study
  > for AI, software engineering, and system imple-
  > mentation?

In my experience, this does not improve readability, and actually slows me down. My feeling is that this is happening because the titles are anyway not fully justified (such as in the last question in the above screenshot), so having some words broken like this using hyphens, while others are fully moved to the next line, makes it confusing to follow.

Can this aspect of the UI please be improved?

Comment: I’ve added the report to the linked duplicate thread: [Word-breaks in titles make it difficult to read quickly](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/376201/986753).

Comment: Now imagine that you're reading questions about hyphenation, like this [ELU question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/74ZHj.png)