# Missing space between bounty amount and remaining duration in user bounties page

Tags: bug, design, profile-page, bounties

This was previously reported as an [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/375837/986753) to the announcement [New responsive Activity page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/372049/new-responsive-activity-page). However, the answer was posted **more than two months** after the announcement. The team only monitors announcements for answers for around 2-3 weeks (up to one month max), after which answers should instead be posted as new questions. As such, while that answer exists, it's unlikely to have been noticed by the team due to the length of time since the announcement, so I'm posting this question.

In my offered bounties page on Travel, it lists an active bounty of mine along with the amount and duration. However, it's missing a space:

[image: +100(ends in 4 days)]

If possible, I'd like it to return to the [previous styling](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/108460/377214) where the colored box would only show the amount, and the remaining duration would be shown separately afterwards. If that is not possible, at the very least, the missing space should be added.

(At first, I was confused as to why an active bounty was showing in the "Offered" tab, as I thought that was only for past bounties. However, from the earlier question, this appears to be by design.)

(Also, I've filed a [separate bug report](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/376616/pluralization-issue-in-number-of-bookmarks-on-list-of-bountied-questions-in-user) for the pluralization issue seen in the screenshot.)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [New responsive Activity page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/372049/new-responsive-activity-page). In particular, I had already reported this bug in an [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/375837/986753) there a few weeks ago.

Comment: @TheAmplitwist That answer was posted more than two months after the question was posted. The team only monitors announcements for answers within 3-4 weeks of them being asked, after which reports should be posted as new questions.

Comment: When I had made a [separate report](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/375831/986753) regarding this bug, I was [told](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/375831/missing-space-between-bounty-amount-and-opening-parenthesis-in-the-bounties-ta#comment1252528_375831) to post it as an answer to the announcement.

Comment: @TheAmplitwist Yeah, that was incorrect advice; it seems they weren't aware that the team ceases to monitor announcements after some time. If you look at prior announcements, you'll often see explicit directives saying "please post answers by [date]", and even in cases where they don't post that, it's still the same.

Comment: Another bug report of mine that I posted as an [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/376201/986753) to a different announcement (again, after first posting as a [separate question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/376198/986753)) received a status update from a staff member.

Comment: I’m just saying, it’s not particularly clear when we should break off new bug reports into their own posts. It might be better to get a definitive response from a staff member before duplicating these reports.

Comment: @TheAmplitwist A month hadn't yet passed since you posted that one. On the other hand, 2.5 months have passed since that answer.

Comment: @TheAmplitwist If staff did indeed see that prior answer, they can close this question as a duplicate themselves. In the meantime, it's best to leave this open so it's not off their radar in case they didn't.

Comment: Hmm, that’s true… I hadn’t noticed that. It certainly felt like longer :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At some point, it seems that some of the elements on the Activity page have been redesigned.

1. Active bounties are still shown in the Offered tab as well. However, the remaining duration indicator is *not* shown in either tab on the [*Bounties*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=bounties) page.

   [image]
   [image]

2. The remaining duration indicator is only shown in the [Summary](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=summary) tab on the profile page. This is shown in both the Active and Offered tabs.

   [image]
   [image]

3. The location of the bounty indicator on the **Bounties** page has been shifted to the right (as shown in the screenshots above).

---

Regarding your main question:

> **Missing space between bounty amount and remaining duration** in user bounties page

(In the Summary tab) The colored box now only shows the bounty amount, and the remaining duration indicator is shown separately (without any highlight, as shown in the screenshots above).

---

Regarding:

> (Also, I've filed a [separate bug report](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/376616/pluralization-issue-in-number-of-bookmarks-on-list-of-bountied-questions-in-user) for the pluralization issue seen in the screenshot.)

The "1 bookmarks" statistic has been removed / is no longer shown.

[I'm assuming you're referring to the pluralization bug regarding "1 bookmark**s**" (your post seems to have been deleted). I've posted a similar bug report: [Pluralization issue: "1 bookmarks" in the Following and Bookmarks tabs](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/378607/pluralization-issue-1-bookmarks-in-the-following-and-bookmarks-tabs).]

Comment: Yes, it's the same issue. The question was closed as a duplicate of the announcement post as someone else had posted an answer in time and it had a staff response. I edited that into a question asking when it will be fixed, but that resulted in heavy downvotes which is why I deleted it. I [attempted to have it reopened through a meta request](/questions/376636/), but that too was quite negatively received. (That discussion was closed as a duplicate of a target that wasn't applicable by binding vote from a moderator, and at the moment, I don't wish to re-litigate it, at least not yet.)

Comment: @Sonic: Thanks for clarifying. Well, the issue has been fixed (as stated in my answer). The statistic has been removed from all the pages (Bookmarks, Bounties, Following).

Comment: Yep, that's why I've decided not to re-litigate the closure there.