# Will extra statistics be included in the new post summary layouts, and when?

Tags: discussion, design, user-interface, user-experience

Since Stack Exchange introduced and implemented the [new post summary designs](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/375081/new-post-summary-designs-on-site-home-pages-and-greatest-hits-now-everywhere-el) in January 2022; hundreds of users have voiced their dissent. But no one, as far as I could tell, actually referenced one of the major reasons for updating the design layout.

> ### Why we’re making these changes
>
> 1. We generally assume 3 items of metadata: *score*, *answers*, and *views*. If we want to add new entries for e.g. *bookmarks* or *revisions*, it can be difficult to create a consistent layout in a list of questions.

As I understand it, this data will appear on the Homepage and on the Question page. Presumably, this addition will affect every site across the network.

1. Was the inclusion of extra data on the Homepage a common feature request by users? Judging by the furore the new layout has created, it seems that the majority of users are  satisfied with the three stats: *score*, *answer*, and *views* while some have even suggested [**removing the view count**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/376078/223820):

> With old design there was no problem in not noticing "views", as they were either smaller, or in a separate column.
>
> Now they are distracting from the important information: the votes.
>
> If you are not going to make votes stand out again, maybe as another solution, views removal can be done?

and [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/375829/223820)

> You can't just keeping putting more stuff in there without drawbacks. So you should also carefully consider which new features or concepts really need to be visible there or not. Or also old ones, e.g. whether it is really that important to show the number of views there.

2. What other stats apart from "revisions" and "bookmarks" might be included, and are they currently under discussion?
3. When will we see a mockup of the layout with the added stats?

Comment: This makes me wonder (as you mentioned in your comment under Mad Scientist's answer) what they have in mind, because surely they aren't considering the number of bookmarks or revisions to be useful information to display on the home page...

Answer (score 8):

The answer lies in another part of the announcement, specifically the explanation after the feedback and the first iterations and bug fixes:

> Extensibility - We want to be able to add new features to post summaries. In fact, many of these "new" features already exist in specific areas and can be (visually) supported everywhere if we are able to implement the backend processes. Existing features include: Collective post/user endorsements, Article types and read time in Teams/Collectives, Bookmark support in Activity, answers nested under questions in Activity (and Enterprise search results)

The requirement for additional flexibility in post summaries is driven by Teams and Collectives. So this is internally-driven demand, not based on specific requests by the commnunity.

The articles page on Teams already seems to use the new components, and it has the estimated read time in the stats section, and of course no number of answers there.

Comment: Which begs the question why mention "bookmarks" and "revisions" being added to the Homepage (as I understood) if it is only meant for Teams. I confess, not being an active member on Stack Overflow nor a developer, I have  a very rough idea what a summary page, teams  and articles are.

Comment: @Mari-LouA My reading of that part would be that those are only examples of information that might be useful to add in some contexts, not that they'll add it to the homepage. They're just examples of additional pieces of information