# Inconsistent alignment in the reputation summary

Tags: bug, reputation, design, profile-page, summary

There seems to be an inconsistent alignment in the reputation summary. For example, on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com), a user with **147** reputation has the following alignment:

[image]

However, another user with **172** reputation has the following alignment:

[image]

Here's another example from a (suspended) user's profile:

[image]

Note: This seems to be the case for users with less than 200 reputation because users with more than 200 rep are tracked in the reputation leagues (i.e., they have a special "top { }% this { }" attached to their rep summary which does not allow for this inconsistent alignment).

Do I sense a [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) here? Even if it's not a bug (i.e., [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign)), the alignment should still be consistent throughout.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [New post summary designs on site home pages and greatest hits now; everywhere else eventually](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/375081/new-post-summary-designs-on-site-home-pages-and-greatest-hits-now-everywhere-el)

Comment: I linked the wrong duplicate, these design elements where changed [in this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/372049/new-responsive-activity-page/375189#375189).