# New line for question title. Is it really needed?

Tags: feature-request, bug, design, title

Is starting a new line really necessary on some questions in that design?

> [image]

> [image]

> [image]

Can’t it be fit in the single line?

Comment: Seems like there's some extra padding on the right hand side of `.s-post-summary--content .s-post-summary--content-title` that does it. Not really sure what's the point of that.

Comment: Even beyond that, **WHY** are we breaking words like this at all... two characters is not a reasonable break spot for a word! Does it seem like maybe we're overdoing the hyphenations? - https://i.stack.imgur.com/XyPWL.png

Comment: @Catija It's been clear since hyphenation started that it wrongly hyphenates when 2 rows are needed hyphen or not. There's a bug report post. You don't need another image, if these sentences think there is not enough room, they shouldn't hyphenate, they should just use 2 lines without hyphenation.

Comment: @Catija Related: [Word-breaks in titles make it difficult to read quickly](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/376201/986753)

Comment: @Catija The reason why is because you've got the `hyphens` CSS property set to "auto" but you've also let the `hyphenate-limit-chars`  property default to "auto" as well. That's kind of nasty in most browser implementations, at least on English-language pages. It could be improved via something like `hyphenate-limit-chars: 10 3 4;` in the CSS as mentioned [here](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/h/hyphenate-limit-chars/). As far as hyphenation on the web goes, its current state of the **art remains artless** at best, even if this is less bad than it was ten or twenty years ago. Alas.