# Is StackExchange programmed to intentionally mis-hyphenate "Democrats" to characterize them as "rats"?

Tags: support, bug

I asked a question [Did US president Theodore Roosevelt call Democrats "prison vermin"?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/56352/did-us-president-theodore-roosevelt-call-democrats-prison-vermin) on Skeptics SE and noticed on the mobile version it displays as:

[image]

Is Stack Exchange programmed to mis-hyphenate the word this way? Or would it be my phone's software?

Comment: I suspect its a function of your phone's resolution and screensize rather than intentional political bias of any sort

Comment: It wasn't designed much at all - see [this past complaint](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/376201/377214) from the time it was rolled out. From the comments there, this [is causing issues on the German Language site](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1694/automatische-silbentrennung-im-titel-von-fragen), as in German the rules for hyphenation are more stringent.

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog but aren't all those examples correctly hyphenated? Hyphenation is supposed to be between symbols.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek but is it the phone deciding where to break the word (against proper English) or is it Stack Exchange deciding?

Comment: I suspect it's probably your browser. I tried resizing my browser window and I was unable to get the word "Democrats" to hyphenate - it'd just wrap to the next line.

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog thanks, my browser is Safari and there are many titles with hyphenated words, but only Democrats is incorrectly hyphenated.

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog FYI, I just tried the same thing with Microsoft Edge on Windows 10. The behavior is the same as what you reported, i.e., the word "Democrats" is always kept together as one word, either on the first or second lines depending on the width.

Comment: @DavePhD Perhaps Safari is programmed to mis-hyphenate "Democrats" in that way :-) ?

Comment: @JohnOmielan Apple [does a lot of weird, accidentally political things](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/341459/why-does-freedom-return-the-french-fries-emoji)...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some digging, I found it's done by pure CSS, adding `hyphens: auto;` to the CSS code.

This means it's up to the browser to render the text as it see fit, and it's 100% the browser's "fault" when words break in the middle in odd ways.

You can read more about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/hyphens).

Answer (score 2):

Viewing the page source, I see (edited for clarity)

```
<h3 class="s-post-summary--content-title">
 <a href="/questions/56352" class="s-link">
  Did US president Theodore Roosevelt call Democrats &quot;prison vermin&quot;?
 </a>
</h3>
```

Stack Exchange would have had to replace `Democrats` with `Democ&shy;rats` to intentionally result in the goofy hyphenation you saw. Note the `&shy;` -- short for "soft hyphen".  A viewer / browser will take the soft hyphen as having precedent over its own hyphenation rules if hyphenation is needed.

Note that while Stack Exchange did substitute your `"` with `&quot;`, it did not insert a `&shy;` in the middle of `Democrats`. It's your viewer / browser that created the goofy hyphenation.